# February 2019 Photo competition

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for our February competition will be:
**Water as (or being) influenced by humans.**

To inspire people, this includes bird baths, people active on rivers, water features in cities and much more. Use your creativity.

And this month entries by two people teams will be welcome, like husband and wife teams and travel companions but not restricted to them. This is going to be the norm for this competition.

Rules:

- 1 photo per answer.
- You may submit more than 1 answer per user.
- Try and keep it non offensive.
- All entries should include a line of text with the location and subject of the photo and the date the photo was taken.
- The photo has to be taken by the user* who posted it and taken in the time frame given in the description for that month's photo.
  (*Or one of a two people team, give credit to the actual person who took the photo.)
- Remember we are 'Travel' stack exchange. If you can give the photo or its description a travel connection, you should get more votes (and/or stand a better chance on getting the virtual prize.)

The next rules changes per month, the subject of the picture and its 'when it was taken'.

For the month of February I would like to set the rule:

- The photo is of water as influenced by mankind or of people on or in water.
- The photo can have been taken anytime.
- If your photo contains people who can be recognized, please make sure that they do not mind being in a published photo. It is up to the person posting the photo to make sure that it is up to the laws of the country where the picture was taken.
- No entries/photos should be posted before midnight, 1st of February 2019, voting will run till midnight the end of 28th of February 2019* and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself. 
  (*Or as soon after as your main judge can see the votes.)

I am looking forward to your photos.
The December and January entries are incredible and plentiful enough that I feel we can keep this competition running.

The highest voted photo is by mts, the rice paddies by the first rays of sun. Very deserving winner. The bragging rights are yours.
The photo that is most the image I was hoping for is the photo of the water over the wall, by WedaPashi.
He gets the virtual price, "A shower out of doors, in the (monsoon) rain, location of your choice but please keep dressed as the local rules require. No travel cost included."

Comment: This looks awesome Willeke! Thanks for allowing a companion to be the one who actually snapped the picture, and for not limiting the time frame! January's been great but I suspect we'll get even more in February! I hope everybody has fun!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

The first rays of sunrise are reflected on the flooded rice terraces of Yuanyang (元阳) in southern Yunnan, China. Photo taken on 11 Feb 2013 by me and modified for contrast, brightness and to reduce file size.

Comment: mts, the bragging rights are yours! Highest voted post and with a good margin, almost twice the votes of the number 2.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Campsite right down the bottom of Horseshoe Bend. 22 Sep 2012.

Comment: How did humans influence the water there?

Comment: Not as easy to see as the others, but next to the camp they've shaped the path of the river towards them.

Comment: I can't even make out the campsite :D could you say where it is?

Comment: @PaulPaulsen bottom middle, where you see the path change.  If you zoom in you can see walking tracks and a couple of structures.

Comment: That is such a minor detail (the human influence) that I wonder if this photo meets the rules.

Comment: @MarkMayo what camera setup are you using here? And is there any post-processing done?

Comment: @insidesin Nikon D80, old thing. I took 3 photos with different exposure, and blended them together to create an HDR.  Back when you couldn't do it in 1 click on your smartphone, haha

Comment: It's okay @MarkMayo most people still don't know how to work the "HDR" option. Ruins a lot of nice photography. :(

Answer (score 7):

[image: Water dancing over granite.]
A detail of the Diana, Princess of Wales Memorial Fountain ([link to the Wikipedia page with some photos.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diana,_Princess_of_Wales_Memorial_Fountain))
Photo taken 4th of May, 2013, Hyde Park London (UK) taken by Willeke.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

This is a man-made water cistern in a complex of caves that were carved more than a thousand years ago. 
Picture clicked back in 2009.
Place: India.
These are one of the more popular caves in state of Maharashtra, India. To know more about the place, look for 'Ankai-Tankai' caves in Maharashtra, India. These are roughly 150 miles from Mumbai.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

This a picture of a water cistern in a complex of caves. This was used as a primary source of water by people living in the complex. The main source of water was the natural water dripping through the rocks. And this cave was carved out of single rock structure.

It was built more than a thousand years ago.
Picture clicked back in 2009.

These are one of the more popular caves in state of Maharashtra, India. To know more about the place, look for 'Ankai-Tankai' caves in Maharashtra, India. These are roughly 150 miles from Mumbai.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Above the wall at Hoover Dam, Arizona side. 8 Sep 2012.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Subject: Man is trashing water.

(26 Jan 2019. Murree Hills, Pakistan)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Standing by a wall erected as a barrier to store the water. In monsoon the water flows over it :-)

This was clicked in July 2016.

Place: Western Ghats, in forest of Dhak-Rajmachi, Maharashtra, India.

Comment: This photo wins you the virtual price: "A shower out of doors, in the (monsoon)rain, location of your choice but please keep dressed as the local rules require. No travel cost included."

Comment: @Willeke: Yayyy, Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Stausee Mattmark (an artificial lake), Valais, Switzerland (https://goo.gl/maps/p9AhqQJJZqJ2) on a cloudy day, taken on August 6th 2018

[image: Stausee Mattmark]

Answer (score 4):

This is the view through the rear window from the *Spirit of the Wild* looking past the swell at the stern of the boat towards the harbour opening, called Hell's Gate, Macquarie Harbour, Tasmania Australia taken  4 January 2019.  A slight artefact of taking this through the window gives the illusion of a moon.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Recife, Brazil. November 2018.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: a bit of water on the top of a block of stone, with a water spout.]
A drinking fountain somewhere in Reykjavik, photo taken 28-9-2014, by Willeke.

Answer (score 4):

This is a mourning dove drinking from drops and rivulets of the glass roof of our sunroom while my husband was washing the room with a hose. The bird was hopping from place to place to get the most water at a time! (There were actually five birds enjoying the fresh moving water, but they were scattered around and I didn't get a good picture of the group!)

I took the picture myself looking up from inside the room. It was on March 10, 2015, in Holden, Massachusetts, USA.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a picture of the Rideau Canal locks in Ottawa (Canada). This is a series of locks operated by manpower. This picture is from 2011.
[image: Rideau Canal Locks]

Answer (score 4):

This is a picture of a small lighthouse in Nairn, Scotland (2012). 
[image: Nairn lighthouse]

Answer (score 4):

[image: a mushroom shaped of water coming up.]
This is the water inlet for the water cleaning system in the dunes near Heemskerk/Castricum, the Netherlands.
Photo taken today, 15 february 2019, by Willeke.

After the cleaning this is the water we get out of our taps.

Answer (score 3):

[image: möhnesee]

The dam of Möhnesee, Germany.
Photo taken on 30th of July 2016.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Aswan Dam, Egypt, looking downstream.

15 Jan 2008.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pic of the sunset at Pushkar lake, Pushkar, Rajasthan, India - Dec 2018.

The town of Pushkar is on the edge of the Thar desert. This lake is surrounded by temples and has a religious significance for the Hindus. The lake is a place that a lot of people take bath in and believe it to be sacred. Also a popular spot for photoshoots :D

[image: Puskhar lake, Pushkar, Rajasthan, India]

Comment: Lovely photo but what is the human influence on the water there? (And when was the photo taken, it is in the rules that the date and location should always be mentioned.)

Comment: Updated. The lake is a place where hundreds of people take a 'religious' dip every day.

Answer (score 3):

How human influence on water affects the travel of other species - A swan trapped on the wrong side of the perimeter fencing in Wanstead Flats, London. Photo taken Dec 2018.

Readers will be delighted to hear that the swan has gotten to the right side with the help of a long bread/seed trail (set up by someone else) that they have eventually followed.

[image: A swan trapped within the perimeter fencing]

Comment: Hi B.Liu! I'm one of those delighted readers! I haven't seen the area, so this is a total guess, but the barrier may have been built for a good reason, such as protection for the swan if she's raising young, but never taken down. Whatever the reason, the swan looked stuck and unhappy in that corner, and I'm grateful to the people who cared enough to set up a way to get it back to the general population! It benefits the entire ecosystem, including the animals on both sides, and humans, too.

Answer (score 3):

A panorama on Swansea Marina, Swansea, UK. Also featuring a napping swan in the middle. Photo taken May 2018.

[image: Swansea Marina, May 2018]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Roughly an year and a half ago, we were trekking on a route in Western Ghats of Maharashtra, India. Initially we had planned to walk by the river but an elderly person that we met on the way asked us to cross the river and walk the other bank as it has better trail than the one we haf planned. When we said we didn't want to swim, he dropped us on the other side of the river in his own boat. He didn't want money, he just wanted us to come and see his small farm he had created out of nothing. Gem of a person!
He resembled uncle Popeye. We call him the sailor man.. Beep Beep!

Date: September 2017.
Place: Post Sangavi. Nearby *Bhor*, About 150 miles from Mumbai.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Picture taken in November 2018 from the Myanmar side of the Moei River facing Thailand. The location is called *Mokkhla Cave, Huai Pla Kong*, but there's not much information on it on the internet. Google Maps has some more pictures of it, somewhat of an unknown gem, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Water feature at Kaydale Lodge in north west Tasmania, taken on the 28 December 2018.  The water is pumped to give a moist space to grow ferns.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: turtle on water pumping hose[1]]

The structure is part of a man-made system of hoses and pumps used to feed drinking water throughout dam-enclosed reservoirs in Massachusetts, USA. This is the Wachusett reservoir in the town of Princeton.

My husband took the photo on April 8, 2018. He had to step closer to the water to get a good view while I stayed on the trail a few feet up the hill.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>perhaps somewhat late to the February party, but here goes my contribution</sub> :
[image]
Now answering the bullets:

- The photo is of water as influenced by mankind or of people on or in water.

  - I hope I'm not bending the rules too much, but the photo was taken using an artificial and rather uncommon filter: the yellowish polarized sunglassses that I was wearing at the time, so the ocean's water colour in the picture is *influenced* by the mankind in this aspect (is this a valid enough excuse?)
- The photo can have been taken anytime.

  - This photo was taken during the Summer of 2011 (February or March, I'd guess), during a road trip I took through Uruguay's seashore. This photo was taken in [Colonia del Sacramento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonia_del_Sacramento) in the Historic quarter, [an UNESCO World Heritage Site](http://whc.unesco.org/en/list/747), which I highly recommend if you're heading or coming from Buenos Aires, which is 1-hour on a ferry away.
- If your photo contains people who can be recognized, please make sure that they do not mind being in a published photo. It is up to the person posting the photo to make sure that it is up to the laws of the country where the picture was taken.

  - No one in the photo
- No entries/photos should be posted before midnight, 1st of February 2019, voting will run till midnight 28th of February 2019* and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself. (*Or as soon after as your main judge can see the votes.)

  - Still 3 days before the end of February!

Comment: gmauch, your photo is welcome but it will not win, as I think the wording was clear enough. But with only three more days for voting I do not think you would have ran a risk of winning anyhow. Next month we have a different theme and you can post early.

Comment: @Willeke, yeah I thought I might have bent the rules way too much. Anyway, my idea was to contribute to the post, since I liked the Photo Competition theme. Kudos to you for that. I'll be searching through my travel photo-memoirs and see if any fits the criteria!

Comment: As I said, your photo is welcome. (And you have time to take a photo for March if you do not have one.)

Comment: Thank you Willeke and keep bringing up nice contests like this one, besides doing a very nice mod work!

Comment: Hi gmauch! I think that's a beautiful picture! I think upvoting it is fair because you and @Willeke have already discussed that it's welcome, even though it doesn't necessarily fully meet all the criteria!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Lake Zurich from Lindenhoff hill]

> Lake Zurich from Lindenhoff hill

This photo was taken March 12, 2018 when i visited Zurich,Switzerland as part of my Europe Trip :)

*note: Thanks for Google Photos for nice color effects*

Answer (score 1):

[image: Franfurt's Huge Sky scrapers seen across river Main]

> Franfurt's Huge Sky scrapers seen across river Main

This photo was taken from the Frankfurt's famous Eisener steg (Iron Bridge) on April 14, 2018.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Majestic White Swan from Palmengarten, Frankfurt]

> Majestic White Swan from Palmengarten, Frankfurt

I captured this white swan on my phone cam on my weekend trip to Frankfurt, Germany in Palmengarten.

**Date:** Apr 14, 2018