# Possible topics for the photo competition

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

In the past few months the photo competition has gained some popularity here on Travel Meta. You can find all previous editions back via [photo-competition](/questions/tagged/photo-competition).

Do you have suggestions for topics for the photo competition?
This can either be

- **[single photo, multiple entry](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5049/3886).** Each post has a single photo each (see e.g the [bus stop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4898/february-2019-photo-competition) episode) or
- **[multiple photo, single entry](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5051/3886)**. Every user can supply only one entry, but with multiple photos (see e.g. the  [road trip](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5022/april-2019-photo-competition-road-trip-read-rules-are-different) edition).

Please add your suggestions at the bottom of the correct list in the community wiki answers, with your name. (a link to your profile is preferred, but can be added by someone else if you do not know how to)

The next topic will be chosen by the person posting the competition question, often but not always after discussing the topic in the [You Are Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) chat.
If you want to make a suggestion for the next month, from the list or a new topic which still has to be added to the list, please come into the chat and mention it.

Answer (score 14):

**Single photo, multiple entries**

- Officials (police, customs officers, diplomats etc) by [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo?tab=profile)
- Ghost towns, by [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow)
- Kites, by [Bernhard](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3886/bernhard)
- Local markets, by [nightgaunt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/91855/nightgaunt)
- Natural water splashing off things like shoreline and boats, by [sue](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/57178/sue?tab=profile).
- Unusual modes of transportation, by [JJJ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11883/jjj)
- The countryside, by [JJJ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11883/jjj)
- Checkpoints (e.g. for entering parks / countries or just for passing through), by [JJJ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11883/jjj)
- Construction (any work in progress that's meant to enable / enhance travel), by [JJJ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11883/jjj)
- Most illegal-looking (but not actually illegal) photo, by [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo?tab=profile)
- Pets traveling, by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile)
- Places/buildings/scenes that no longer exist, by [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill)
- Civic buildings, by [gparyani](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11329/gparyani)
- Seen from the hotel room, by [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow)
- Places of worship, by [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow)
- Reflections, (on water, on shiny surfaces, on walls, ...) by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile)
- Art, craft or (traditional) workmanship, by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile)
- holiday photos, in which you can recognize people traveling for their (yearly?) break from work, by ?
- Doors, gates, or other portals, by [choster](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster)
- Remarkable weather (blizzards, lightning, signs of severe drought/storm surge/gales, unusual rainbows, etc.), by [choster](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster)
- Items you have made/repaired that you use while traveling, either your own inventions, variations on well known items or very useful repairs on travel items. (More related things possible.) By [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile)
- Cemetery, by [Bernhard](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3886/bernhard)
- Most beautiful (or curious) banknotes collected in travels, by [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Photos you got wrong. Like blurs, light seeped in, focus on the wrong part of the photo. Does not need to be a beautiful photo but people will still vote for what they like, by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile)
- Photos of lettering, by [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Inside Cave, by [Ankit Sharma](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26973/ankit-sharma)
- Panoramic photos, by [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)

**Selected topics**

- Staircases, by [Bernhard](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3886/bernhard) - [Photo competition May 2019](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5063/may-2019-photo-competition-staircases)
- Animals, by [gparyani](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11329/gparyani) - [Photo competition June 2019](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5105/june-2019-photo-competition-animals-interacting-with-humans)
- Bridges, by [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow) - [Photo competition July 2019](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5138/july-2019-photo-competition-bridges)
- Seen through a train window, by [mdewey](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/66146/mdewey) - [Photo competition August 2019](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5200/august-2019-photo-competition-seen-through-a-train-window)
- Towers, by [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow) - [Photo competition September 2019](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5266/september-2019-photo-competition-towers)
- Musical instruments, buskers and travel related  playing of music, by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Photo competition October 2019](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6341/october-2019-photo-competition-musical-instruments-buskers-and-travel-related)
- "How did that happen?", by [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo?tab=profile) - [Photo competition November 2019](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/november-2019-photo-competition-how-did-that-happen)
- Lighthouses, by [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill) - [Photo competition February 2020](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/february-2020-photo-competition-lighthouses)
- Waterfalls, by [nightgaunt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/91855/nightgaunt) - [Photo competition May 2020](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6566/may-2020-photo-competition-waterfalls)
- A combined theme written by [gparyani](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11329/gparyani) from the following themes - [Photo competition July 2020](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6645/july-2020-photo-competition-human-or-animal-powered-vehicles):

  - Human powered vehicles (including bicycles but not restricted to that,) by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile)
  - Animal powered vehicles, like carts drawn by horses, by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile)
- Mountains, by [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo?tab=profile) - [Photo competition August 2020](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6672)
- Something small, (from or for your travels.) By [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Photo competition September 2020](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/september-2020-photo-competition-something-small-from-or-for-your-travels)
- Impossible Travel. Locked gates, blocked roads, abandoned stations, wrecked boats, etc from my friend Mike, by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Photo competition October 2020](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/october-2020-photo-competition-impossible-travel)
- Wildlife, by [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo?tab=profile) - [Photo competition November 2020](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6766/november-2020-photo-competition-nature-wildlife)
- Decorated walls, (mosaics, painted, graffiti, pargetting, ....) by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Photo competition March 2021](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6910/march-2021-photo-competition-decorated-walls)
- Trees, by [Bernhard](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3886/bernhard) - [Photo competition April 2021](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6939/april-2021-photo-competition-trees)
- Architecture (modern / ancient), by [Xnero](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/105447/xnero) - [Photo competition May 2021](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6978/may-2021-photo-competition-architecture)
- Ten Year site anniversary by [gparyani](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11329/gparyani) - [Photo competition July 2021](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7031/july-2021-photo-competition-ten-year-anniversary)
- Beaches by [Tomerikoo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/120762/tomerikoo) - [Photo competition August 2021](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7058/august-2021-photo-competition-beaches)
- Foreign food, by [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo?tab=profile) - [Photo competition February 2022](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8230/february-2022-photo-competition-foreign-food)
- Country borders (obvious or not-so-obvious), by [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo) - [Photo competition December 2022](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/december-2022-photo-competition-borders)
- Waterfeatures (fountains and (animal) drinking basins,) by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Photo competition April 2023](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8484/april-2023-photo-competition-fountains)

Comment: @Willeke should "Photos you got wrong" be among the selected topics? :)

Comment: @MattAllegro, yes, I had not updated it yet and now have computer problems. But as this is a wiki you can do it.

Answer (score 10):

**Single entry, multiple photos**

- Something old and something new (and if you find them, also something borrowed and something blue.) Up to four related pictures which follow the old wedding rhyme. By [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)
- The same location in an old and a new photo, in which you can see it is the same location but you can also see it has differences. Two photos in each entry (or maybe more if you have an in between one as well.) By [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)

**Selected topics**

- *Road trip* by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) - [Photo competition April 2019](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5022/april-2019-photo-competition-road-trip-read-rules-are-different)
- *Countries* by [Bernhard](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3886/bernhard) - [Photo competition January 2020](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6434/january-2020-photo-competition-countries)
- *Castles* by [Dirty-flow](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow) - [Photo competition June 2021](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7000/june-2021-photo-competition-castles-and-similar-structures)