# May 2019 Photo competition, Staircases

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for May is Staircases, and in the words of the person who proposed it first, [Bernhard](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3886/bernhard?tab=profile):

> I would say we can keep the scope a bit wide, i.e., as long as it consists of steps and is used by people to climb up or down something.

Rules:

- 1 photo per answer.
- You may submit more than 1 answer per user. But keep it to no more than 3 posts.
- Try and keep it non offensive.
- **All entries should include a line of text with the location and subject of the photo and when the photo was taken, date for recent photos, month for 'a few years old' and year only of old ones.**
- The photo has to be taken by the user* who posted it and taken in the time frame given in the description for that month's photo. (*Or one of a two people team, give credit to the actual person who took the photo, nick names are acceptable.)
- Remember we are 'Travel' stack exchange. If you can give the photo or its description a travel connection, you should get more votes (and/or stand a better chance on getting the virtual prize.)

The next rules changes per month, the subject of the picture and its 'when it was taken'.

For the month of May I would like to set the rules:

- The photo can have been taken anytime.
- The subject of the photo is Staircases.
- The photo should not be of people, as such, but it is rather likely that one or more will be in the picture. If so, either in such a way you can not recognize them or you should have permission to post their photo online. It is up to the person posting the photo to make sure that it is up to the laws of the country where the picture was taken.
- No entries/photos should be posted before midnight, 1st of May 2019, voting will run till midnight, the last seconds of May 2019* and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself. (*Or as soon after as your main judge can see the votes.)

If you want to join in sharing themes for future competitions, please see [the suggested topics question.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/27650)
Just edit your suggestions into the community wiki answers there.
And to have a say in which one will be selected next month, do a suggestion, soon after a month started, in the [You Are Here chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)
Be ready to defend your choice for a while, as more people might post suggestions.

*Please do not delete posts if you do not get upvotes (or even get down votes.) It is what you entered, stand by it. You can post two more entries to change your luck.*

@Tor-Einar Jarnbjo you win the bragging rights, highest voted photo this month.
@gmauch, you win the virtual prize, for hiding the man sized steps the best of any of the photos in this competition.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]
*Umschreibung*, Olafur Eliasson, Munich, May 1st 2019

I am not sure if this can still be called a stair case, but it at least used to be. This piece of art is rapidly deteriorating and most steps have fallen off.

Comment: Yours are the bragging rights, you have won the May 2019 photo competition.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Szimpla Kert]

Szimpla Kert, claimed to be Budapest's first *romkocsma* (ruin bar), taken October 2018

Answer (score 14):

[image: Phare de Baleines]

This is the spiral staircase in the lighthouse Phare des Baleines on [Île de Ré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Ele_de_R%C3%A9), an island off the west coast of France. The "1854" on the bottom signifies the year the lighthouse was finished.

Picture was taken in August 2013.

Answer (score 12):

New vs. old stairs in the Otranto cathedral (Duomo di Otranto), Puglia, Italy. 
[image]

Taken by me on 27 Aug 2018 and modified for contrast and to reduce file size. The cathedral features fascinating medieval mosaics.

Comment: Hi mts! This is awesome! What a great way to modernize something (and probably make it safer) without losing the original!

Answer (score 10):

The Mayas were great at staircases. This is the back-side of the Chichen Itza. The contrast with the front that is often depicted is surprising. The picture dates back to January 2014.
[image: Chichen Itza]

Answer (score 9):

[Tiger Cave Mountain Temple in Krabi, Thailand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_Cave_Temple). Picture taken in August 2014. The steps are more of a pain (see linked Wikipedia page) but the view form the top (pictured) is much nicer:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

[Wat Ban Tham in Kanchanaburi, Thailand](https://www.tripadvisor.com.ph/Attraction_Review-g2237741-d6161636-Reviews-Wat_Ban_Tham-Tha_Muang_Kanchanaburi_Province.html). Picture taken in July 2014. The [view form the top (link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOdHZ.jpg) is nice but you don't see the stairs. In this case, the stairs are part of the attraction:
[image]

After reading some of the reviews on Tripadvisor, I recall that the steps leading to the dragonhead (pictured) are just the first flight of stairs. It all ends at the pagoda at the top (where the linked picture is taken).

Answer (score 9):

[image: Vernal Falls]

Vernall Falls, Yosemite National Park taken September 2011 on my honeymoon

Comment: Awesome! What a nice place.

Comment: @HankyPanky Thanks! Yosemite National Park is probably one of the most beautiful places I have visited. Some truly spectacular scenery.

Comment: I have a picture from the exact same spot!!

Answer (score 8):

These naturally formed, lichen-covered, stone steps lead downhill to the bay at Schoodic Peninsula, Acadia National Park, Maine, USA. There are some more at the bottom but the tide is coming in, covering them. It's part of a 20 step, steep path between a large rocky formation, with the road at the top.

[image: Steps leading to the bay at Schoodic Peninsula, Maine.]

My husband took this on October 9, 2015, during a trip from Massachusetts. I was standing a few steps higher.

Comment: I can't get my head about around the size / scale in that picture, how high above the water was your husband when the photo was taken?

Answer (score 8):

How about that for a staircase?

[image]

Go Ape, Battersea Park, London, UK

13 July, 2018.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Rakiura Track, Stewart Island, New Zealand, 2007.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Moss covered steps, Ballydehob, Co. Cork, Ireland, 2009.

Answer (score 7):

[image]
[Český Krumlov Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cesk%C3%BD_Krumlov_Castle), May 5th, 2019

Answer (score 7):

Themed Stairs. In Dubai even the stairs have to match the color scheme!

[image]

Dubai International Airport, 18 June 2018.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Santa Catalina Monastery, Arequipa, Peru, 2005.

Answer (score 6):

[image: A spiral of a staircase taken from below.]
This is a staircase in the Louvre, Paris. Taken from below, 10 April 2015.

Answer (score 5):

Somewhere at the start of a trail in [Doi Khon Than National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doi_Khun_Tan_National_Park), Thailand. I don't know what the board says exactly, the numbers refer to a year ([1917](http://dateconverter.net/thai/2460/?hl=en)) and a distance (900 metres) though. Picture taken in December 2018:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Victoria and Albert Museum Ceramic Staircase]
I took this photo of the Ceramic Staircase in the Victoria and Albert Museum during a trip to England over Christmas 2018/2019

Answer (score 5):

[image: Peter's Summer Palace]

This is a picture I took from a staircased fountain (hope it meets this month's contest criteria) in front of [Peter the Great Summer Palace](http://www.saint-petersburg.com/palaces/summer-palace-of-peter-the-great/), on the outskirts of Saint Petersburg, Russia.

Photo was taken on my trip to Russia on November 2015.

Comment: That is beautiful!

Comment: @HankyPanky спасиба! Russia was a very nice surprise to me, who was used to just visit more western-style countries. Beautiful palaces and museums everywhere!

Comment: @gmauch, you win the virtual prize, for hiding the man sized steps the best of any of the photos in this competition. Your prize is: Go up and down the escalators in your nearest fancy multi level department store, but not in the weekend, because then it will be too busy. Travel cost and purchases are not included.

Comment: @Willeke Wow! Now I cannot say 'I never won any contest!' anymore! Already stretching my legs to collect the prize!

Answer (score 5):

Hatshepsut Temple, Valley of the Kings, Luxor, Egypt
December, 2007

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: a pole with electricity wires and steps going up]
Weymouth, UK 12 May 2019.
Not your average stairs but the steps are for people to go up.

Comment: Very interesting. Do they still use those or are they from the era before [Health and Safety](https://www.hse.gov.uk/)? :O

Comment: I don't know, I was just a tourist there.

Comment: Well, it's interesting to [see people climb them](http://www.livingthai.org/thailand-power-poles.html). It's very dangerous though, you can fall and there can be dangerous wiring. In your image it seems the steps start pretty high, so at least kids won't be able to climb up for fun. ;p

Answer (score 3):

Taken by myself on 7 October 2016 in Western Australia.  I believe this shows the stairs in Jewel Cave in Deepdene Western Australia https://www.margaretriver.com/members/jewel-cave-augusta/

[image: Western Australian Cave staircase]

Answer (score 3):

Stairs winding down to the sinkhole at the Trowutta Arch, north West Tasmania, taken 30 December 2018.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: A metal staircase, seeing the front of the steps.]
A very plain staircase (Heemskerk, the Netherlands, 23 May 2019)
No need for a special staircase to be able to take a photo.
(Only this is not as special a photo as I had hoped for.)

Comment: Hi Willeke! I think this is special, and not that plain! I'm not sure but it looks like it's inside a warehouse or workplace. Either way, they're probably used every day, so people rely on them. There aren't any criteria for the contest other than staircase, and I like that you added something very different from others!