# June 2019 photo competition, Animals interacting with humans

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

In the words of the person who proposed it: [gparyani](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11329/gparyani?tab=profile)

> Theme: animals, interacting with humans or human-made objects, pets and zoo animals disallowed.

Animals should be alive and well and the interaction should be of their choice. Or normal working animal conditions

Rules:

- 1 photo per answer.
- You may submit more than 1 answer per user. But keep it to no more than 3 posts.
- Try and keep it non offensive.
- **All entries should include a line of text with the location and subject of the photo and when the photo was taken, date for recent photos, month for 'a few years old' and year only of old ones.**
- The photo has to be taken by the user* who posted it and taken in the time frame given in the description for that month's photo. (*Or one of a two people team, give credit to the actual person who took the photo, nick names are acceptable.)
- Remember we are 'Travel' stack exchange. If you can give the photo or its description a travel connection, you should get more votes (and/or stand a better chance on getting the virtual prize.)

The next rules changes per month, the subject of the picture and its 'when it was taken'.

For the month of June I would like to set the rules:

- The photo can have been taken anytime.
- The subject of the photo is animals, interacting with humans or human made objects, pets and zoo animals disallowed.
- The photo should not be of people, as such, but it is rather likely that one or more will be in the picture. If so, either in such a way you can not recognize them or you should have permission to post their photo online. It is up to the person posting the photo to make sure that it is up to the laws of the country where the picture was taken.
- No entries/photos should be posted before the 1st of June 2019, voting will run till midnight, the last seconds of June 2019* and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself. (*Or as soon after as your main judge can see the votes.)

If you want to join in sharing themes for future competitions, please see the [suggested topics question.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition)
Just edit your suggestions into the community wiki answers there.
And to have a say in which one will be selected next month, do a suggestion, soon after a month started, in the [You Are Here chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)
Be ready to defend your choice for a while, as more people might post suggestions.

**Please do not delete posts if you do not get upvotes (or even get down votes.) It is what you entered, stand by it. You can post two more entries to change your luck.**

Choster won the bragging rights this month, 9 upvotes.
JJJ gets the virtual prize, see his entry for the details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure whether this qualifies—I've never done one of these before.
[image: Photo of a sambar doe]

> Pardon me, ma'am. Which way to the front?

A grazing sambar doe inspects our Tata Nano shortly after it enters Horton Plains National Park, Sri Lanka in January 2013, en route to World's End.

Comment: I love it, I think it qualifies. Animal is really looking at/interacting with the car.

Comment: You win the competition, +9 votes, (downvotes do not count for this but even with them you are ahead of the others.)

Comment: @Willeke Woot! I'll chalk it up to beginner's, ah, sympatheticness. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 8):

Everybody queues up in London. There are no acceptable exceptions to the legendary British Queue!
[image]

Hyde Park, London, UK. 12 July 2018

Answer (score 8):

I must admit that choster inspired me on this one:

[image]

> Pardon me, may I have a taste of that juicy looking camera lens?

The picture was taken on a bicycle tour close to Gedern, Germany on June 16th, 2017.

Answer (score 7):

A monkey (not a gibbon) at the [Gibbon at Highland Farm in Mae Sot](https://www.gibbonathighlandfarm.org/en/), Thailand. Contrary to what one might gather from the metal fencing, the farm is not a zoo, but it's a sanctuary for abused animals (mostly gibbons that **used to be** held as pets).

The monkey is shown flea picking a human arm. Very friendly monkey, apparently he comes highly recommended. Picture taken in November of 2018.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
Hairy coo, and my wife

September 2018
Between Sconser and Luib, Isle of Skye, Scotland

Huawei Nexus 6P
ƒ/21/4074.67 mmISO60
```

Answer (score 5):

A nice exercise machine for me?
[image: squirrel on the top of a fence.]
Squirrel in Hydepark, London, UK, photos taken by Willeke, 4 May 2013, combined into one picture.
Photo is free to use.

Comment: It's actually quite an interesting story how squirrels came to parks — they are not naturally urban animals any more than, say, deer. The City Beatiful movement felt city residents would enjoy seeing them in parks, so there was a concerted effort to introduce and sustain them, in particular the North American grey squirrel. They are all over Japan, despite Japan having no natural squirrels, and have outcompeted the red squirrel almost to extinction in Britain.

Comment: They're basically just rats with nicer tails :)

Comment: Much like your flying rat (gull).

Answer (score 5):

Bambi, do you want to go out for a drink :)

Photo taken in October 2018, in the Summer Bar Bedouin near Sevlievo, Bulgaria.

[image: Me and Bambi]

Comment: Looks like Bambi didn't enjoy the drink you offered him!

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Camel scoffing down a Coke
3 Jan, 2008
Petra, Jordan

Comment: That's an efficient camel! I heard they drink [up to 200 liters of water](http://wtamu.edu/~cbaird/sq/2013/09/18/how-much-water-can-a-camel-store-in-its-hump/) at once and this one goes by with only 335ml!

Comment: A downvote on a picture, how bizarre.

Comment: Not mine! One of the funniest animal pictures I've ever seen!

Answer (score 4):

This is a picture of a seagull watching over downtown San Francisco from the Aquatic Park Pier. I made this picture May 2018.
[image: San Francisco]

Answer (score 3):

[image: statue with gull on top]
This is what those metal people are made for, somewhere to sit so you can drop what you do not want anymore.

Gull on the head of [Queen Victoria.](http://www.victorianweb.org/sculpture/marochetti/5.html)
Photo taken in Glasgow, 26 August 2015, free for all to use.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

We went to a bed and breakfast on a goat farm in Rhode Island, USA, a few hours from our home. One of our friends fed the goats carrots, apples, and other various treats, and ran out.

The goats didn't believe they were all gone, so our friend put up his hands to show they were empty!

My husband took the picture in August, 2018. I was sitting next to him with a young goat in my lap!

(Our friend didn't want us to show his face.)

Answer (score 2):

Person feeding monkeys at [Wat Thammikaram Worawihan](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Wat_Thammikaram,_Prachuap_Khiri_Khan) in Prachuap Khiri Khan, Thailand. The picture was taken in August of 2014. As you can see, the surroundings are very nice, this temple is situated on top of a hill and looks out over the Gulf of Thailand. I might edit the picture to make a compilation like Willeke's entry since there's a lot going on there ([and in the parking lot](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1438/8227)).

[image]

Comment: You win the virtual prize, an invisible animal friend. Nice company on your next travel. Of course we do not include food nor its outfitting, but cost are expected to be very low. Looking forward to the both of you showing off his tricks.