# July 2019 photo competition. Bridges

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

Theme for July 2019, bridges.

> Any bridge you can drive or walk over, or use whatever other method of
>   crossing. And that includes natural bridges which have no human access
>   and miniatures.
>
> The bridge needs to be recognizable as a bridge.

Rules:

- 1 photo per answer.
- You may submit more than 1 answer per user. But keep it to no more than 3 posts.
- Try and keep it non offensive.
- All entries should include a line of text with the location and subject of the photo and when the photo was taken, date for recent photos, month for 'a few years old' and year only of old ones.
- The photo has to be taken by the user* who posted it and taken in the time frame given in the description for that month's photo. (*Or one of a two people team, give credit to the actual person who took the photo, nick names are acceptable.)
- Remember we are 'Travel' stack exchange. If you can give the photo or its description a travel connection, you should get more votes (and/or stand a better chance on getting the virtual prize.)

The next rules changes per month, the subject of the picture and its 'when it was taken'.

For the month of July I would like to set the rules:

- The photo can have been taken anytime.
- The subject of the photo is bridges, all allowed as long as recognizable as bridge.
- The photo should not be of people, as such, but if one or more are be in the picture make sure you either have them in such a way you can not recognize them or you should have permission to post their photo online. It is up to the person posting the photo to make sure that it is up to the laws of the country where the picture was taken.
- No entries/photos should be posted before the 1st of July 2019, voting will run till midnight, the last seconds of July 2019* and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself. (*Or as soon after as your main judge can see the votes.)

If you want to join in sharing themes for future competitions, please see [the suggested topics question.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition?noredirect=1&lq=1)
Just edit your suggestions into the community wiki answers there.
And to have a say in which one will be selected next month, do a suggestion, soon after a month started, in the [You Are Here chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)
Be ready to defend your choice for a while, as more people might post suggestions.

**Please do not delete posts if you do not get upvotes (or even get down votes.) It is what you entered, stand by it. You can post two more entries to change your luck.**

**And do not downvote, (we can technically not stop you doing so but it is not nice to see downvotes on a photo which has done nothing wrong.) Only upvotes will be counted to hand out the prizes.**
(If you think a photo does not meet the rules, you can post a comment or ask about it in the chat.)

Helm wins the bragging rights, the most upvoted photo this month, (and the last vote that made the difference did come in July.)
JJJ wins the virtual prize. This month that is a walk through a puddle. Not included wellies to splash nor a cape to spread over the puddle. (And he may have to make his own puddle, depending on where he lives.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image: Pont du Gard]

Le [Pont du Gard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pont_du_Gard) is the highest Roman aqueduct ever built and nearly 2000 years old. Located near Nîmes (for which it used to serve water) and Avignon in the south of France. It's a UNESCO World Heritage Site. Picture was taken in 2010.

Comment: I see Roman architecture. I upvote. :)

Comment: Tallest [Grecoroman bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Roman_architectural_records), awesome!

Comment: My parents have a photo of this aquaduct when visitors were still allowed to walk on it, and it was not even that long ago. (Late 20th century, I guess.) Very impressive to look down it, even on just a photo.

Comment: It was a photo finish but you have won the bragging rights.

Comment: Hurray, thanks for the votes and all the other great entries!

Answer (score 15):

[image: Sydney Harbour Bridge, from Kirribilli, 2018]

Sydney Harbour Bridge, from Kirribilli, 2018

Answer (score 12):

A natural bridge, I think made out of two 'ice bergs' in [Jökulsárlón,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6kuls%C3%A1rl%C3%B3n) the glacier lagoon on Iceland.

[image: two hunks of ice in roughly animal shapes which seem to rest nose to nose]

Jökulsárlón 23 September 2014, a bridge from nowhere to nowhere useless to all but the odd bird.
The icebergs reminded me then and now of a cat and a dog nose to nose.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

The Kintai Bridge (錦帯橋 Kintai-kyō) is a historical wooden arch bridge, in the city of Iwakuni, in Yamaguchi Prefecture, Japan.

The bridge was built in 1673, spanning the Nishiki River in a series of five wooden arches. The bridge is located on the foot of Mt.Yokoyama, at the top of which lies Iwakuni Castle.

Taken in Iwakuni, Japan, on the 31st of July, 2014.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Bridge over an irrigation channel]

Bridge across an irrigation channel for access to the Pha Thao cave (though labeled "Mai Cave" here) near Ban Pha Thao, a Hmong village about 11km north of Vang Vieng, Laos. The water was quite low as we were into the dry season, which should have warned us that the underground pool we sought would be nothing but caked mud.

Yes, I admit to stopping in Vang Vieng. It was March 15, 2007, and I was young then.

Comment: Yes but did you go tubing? :)

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Railway bridge in Tauranga, New Zealand.  Photo taken by my wife on May 3, 2019.  While Tauranga is our hometown, we no longer live there and took this while on a trip back to visit family earlier this year.

[Google Maps link](https://goo.gl/maps/tyCv6Yuqhvrh9Rgb9)

Comment: Woo, +1 for Tauranga! My folks are in Papamoa Beach

Answer (score 10):

The Devil's Bridge (Rakotzbrücke) in Germany
4 April 2018
[image: The Devil's Bridge]

Comment: That is this one, isn't it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azalea_and_Rhododendron_Park_Kromlau

Comment: @Willeke exactly :)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Picture taken on on or about 4th of July 2016.

A bridge situated at about 4000 m (13000 feet) at a remote places called Batal, in from Lahaul valley of state of Himalchal Pradesh, India. 
The bridge crosses over a significant river Chandra, which flows into Pakistan after a confluence with another glacial river called Bhaga, later its popularly called 'Chenab' in the region downstream of the confluence.

Answer (score 9):

The Glenfinnan Viaduct, taken last summer while a friend and I were on a highland ride on Harley Davidsons.

Sadly we didn't see the stream train which was made so popular by Harry Potter.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The bridge to Cadiz, taken 8 July 2019 (by my wife, as I was driving)

[image: Cadiz bridge]

Answer (score 7):

Bridge on the River Kwai, [just like in the movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bridge_on_the_River_Kwai). Photo taken in July of 2014 in Kanchanaburi, Thailand.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

"Under the Bridge"

The Marvelous Bridges in Bulgaria
1 August 2017
[image: The Marvelous Bridges]

Comment: Is this a natural bridge?

Comment: @Willeke yes it is.

Answer (score 6):

Going in a different direction here. This picture is taken from the car at the Saraburi bypass of [Mittraphaap Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittraphap_Road), which connects Bangkok with Vientiane and further to China. I took this picture in July of 2017.

What we see is part of the construction of the [Pan-Asia railway Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunming%E2%80%93Singapore_railway#In_Thailand). The bridge part consists of the red apparatus on top of the railway which connects the already built parts with the next pillar.

[image]

Comment: I accidentally accepted (and then unaccepted) this post. Which did draw my attention to it. Not the most beautiful photo but it does have something. You win the virtual prize. This month that is a walk through a puddle. Not included wellies to splash nor a cape to spread over the puddle. (And you may have to make your own puddle, depending on where you live.)

Comment: @Willeke thanks. I just take all my photos with my mobile phone so it's not the best quality but you have it out faster and it's always near. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Taken in Venice in 2011, this is the Rialto Bridge. It also includes two workers unloading a barge to a hand cart. The water is a main utility way in Venice for sure.

[image: Rialto Bridge, Venice]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Coronado Bridge, San Diego, CA]

Under the Coronado Bridge, San Diego, CA.  Photo taken by me April 15, 2018 from one of the San Diego Harbor Tour boats.

[Google Maps link](https://goo.gl/maps/dkcAJTokHLn1zF9B6)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Footbridge to [Mizen Head, Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizen_Head). Taken March 2009.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Mathoor Aqueduct]

Photo of Mathoor Aqueduct located in Kanyakumari District, Tamil Nadu, India. Image was taken on 25 June 2007.

Attribution: This image is a self-made image by Infocaster [published](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mathur_Aqueduct.JPG) under Creative Commons license.

Answer (score 6):

The Kurushima strait bridge (southernmost bridge of the so-called Shimanami Kaido), as seen from Uma island. (Japan, 2014)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is a picture I took in Bratislava, July 2017. This bridge is also called the UFO bridge (because of the shape of the observation-deck and restaurant. I took this picture standing near the White Castle. 
[image: Bratislava]

Answer (score 5):

[Forth (railway) bridge, across the Firth of Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_Bridge)

Photo taken from a tour boat, 25 August 2015.

[image: Forth bridge from beneath.]

Other photos in the series do show it the usual red, it is the angle of the camera and the sun that makes it seem so dark in colour.

Answer (score 5):

Golden Gate, San Fransisco, Summer 2016, cloaked in the fog.

[image]

That chubby guy is me, stuffed with Hellenic Yogurts! :)

Note: Photograph taken by a friendly fellow tourist.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Sergeant John Baker Jr Memorial Bridge, crossing the Mississippi River from Iowa to Illinois.  Photo taken by my wife (or me if she was driving), June 30, 2018, on our road-trip from Tijuana, Mexico to Washington DC.

Had a number of other bridge photos on this trip (and numerous other sights), but I like this one mostly because it's the first time we ever crossed the Mississippi (other than by air).  Apologies for the dirty windscreen!

[Google Maps link](https://goo.gl/maps/VMY3FvPTC1RAhz6PA)

Answer (score 5):

The bridge near Fort Punta Christo in Pula, Croatia. April 2019. 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Sydney Harbour Bridge, during Vivid, taken from harbour on board a boat, May 2017]

Sydney Harbour Bridge, during Vivid, taken from harbour on board a boat, May 2017

Answer (score 4):

The Geierlay bridge in Germany
20 August 2017

[image: Geierlay]

Answer (score 4):

Tower Bridge doing its thing!

[image]

Tower Bridge, London, UK. July 2018

Answer (score 4):

[image]

KPK, Pakistan. March 2019

Answer (score 4):

A bridge in the wall around the marina, La Rochelle, France.
There does not seem to be a reason to have such a bridge there, as the rest of the wall does not lead anywhere and gives no access to the boats in the marina.
[image: Bridge with a forest of masts behind it.]

Photo taken by me, 5 March 2015. Free for all to use.

[Link to the google maps location of this bridge.](https://www.google.com/maps/place/La+Rochelle,+Frankrijk/@46.1540784,-1.1504265,1034a,35y,245.72h,44.62t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x48015383c9253d75:0x405d39260ee9640!8m2!3d46.160329!4d-1.151139)

Answer (score 4):

[image: Montopolis Bridge]

[Montopolis Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montopolis_Bridge), Austin, Texas. This historic steel truss bridge formerly carried a major north/south highway across the Colorado River, but has since been superseded by the newly-constructed roads seen on the left. As such, this bridge has since been converted into a pedestrian and bicycle path.

Shot June 30, 2019 by me using Ilford HP5 black-and-white film pushed to 800. There are also [more images where that came from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VASl4.jpg) (all available under CC BY-SA 3.0).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Bridge at the [Imperial Palace, Tokyo, Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Imperial_Palace). Taken April 2009.

Answer (score 3):

Bridge in Tbilisi, summer 2015

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Bridge in [Castellane, France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castellane). Taken June 2013. The cliff on the left side is the base of the Roc of Notre-Dame.

Answer (score 2):

[Floods in Prague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_European_floods#Vltava_river), 2013. Luckily didn't get as bad as [the floods in 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_European_floods).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Classic shot of the Golden Gate Bridge, March 2018

[image]