# August 2019 photo competition: 'Seen through a train window.'

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

Theme for August 2019 is 'Seen through a train window' by [mdewey](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/66146/mdewey?tab=profile).

As trains are not everywhere and at least some users are unable to use them, I want to widen the theme.
The photo has to be taken from a vehicle through the window, showing the frame and/or the glass. (Or in case of a windowless vehicle, you need to include a part of your transport to show you took it from that.)

The vehicle does not need to move while taking the photo, although that is allowed. Drivers are advised to stop the car (or whatever) before using the camera, as safety requires.

Photos from planes and other flying vehicles are allowed but remember that they need to have both quality and need to be 'good' in other ways, photos of 'just clouds' are mostly not. But photos of sight seeing flights or extremely lucky 'airline' shots are acceptable.

But you get a much higher chance on the virtual prize if you manage a good train window photo.

- As usual, one photo per post.
- You can post up to three posts.
- **Do not delete posts if you do not get votes, you posted it, stand by it.** (You have two more chances with your other photos.)
- All posts should have a line with when the photo was taken and what is in it and/or where it is.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named.)
- Keep it nice and non offensive.
- **All votes count as upvotes,** (to decide the winner.)
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo has to be taken through a window of a vehicle, showing the frame or glass, or if a window less vehicle is used, it needs to show that it was taken from the vehicle in the photo.
- The photo does not need to include people, but when it does, make sure they are either agreed with them being in and online or show them in such a way they can not be recognized. (Doctoring the photo to block out faces is allowed.)
- Photos can be posted in the whole month of August, we use UTC, just as the site. The winner will be announced if there is no tie at the end of the month, and the voting period may extend beyond the month, one day at a time.

Comment: There is a discussion about the 'all votes count as upvotes' rule here, https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/should-downvotes-count-as-upvotes-for-the-photo-contests/5227#5227

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[image: Forth rail bridge from the Forth road bridge, with a reflection showing the Queensferry bridge during its building.]
The Forth Bridge, the Forth Road Bridge and the Queensferry Crossing in one photo due to the reflections in the window, while crossing the Forth Road bridge.

Taken 29 August 2015, a just a minute after my other photo in almost the same location.
Again near Edinburgh, Scotland, UK.

Comment: Of the submissions so far, I think this one is truest to the idea of the competition. It isn't just a photo of something beautiful or striking taken through a window, but demonstrates how the window itself alters our perception of something, how it can both obscure and augment one's observations of the surrounding environment. I like Dirty-flow's contribution for similar reasons.

Comment: Was this from a train? What's in the bottom-right of the picture if it's not a car mirror? Should the title be taken more loosely than I imagine perhaps?

Comment: @Mast As I was crossing the Forth Road bridge, it is indeed from a road vehicle. In my other submission (so far) this month I mentioned that I was in a minibus, this was from the same bus. And yes, the header of the competition is not giving the whole of the rules. That is in the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. It's a beautiful picture.

Comment: The reflections make it for me. They look like spacecraft coming in to land

Comment: And as usual down voters do not bother to leave a comment why they downvoted.

Comment: This one has the highest number of upvotes, at 23 while the one above has only 22.

Answer (score 23):

The Akita Nairiku line, Winter Edition™. Japan, January 2016.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Photo taken in [Safari Park Open Zoo](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g297924-d1744252-Reviews-Safari_Park_Open_Zoo-Kanchanaburi_Kanchanaburi_Province.html), Kanchanaburi, dated July 2017.

**1: When there's free food:**

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Took the train from San Diego to Seattle in Feb 2018 (just for fun) - this photo taken [just past San Luis Obispo, CA](https://goo.gl/maps/TnNuLiGwK1UDjsLa6).  I tried to get a photo of the rest of the train every time there was a decent curve.

[image]

Photo taken by me on Feb 3, 2018

I had a lot of other photos I considered using this month from that journey, but most of them I had done my best to get a decent picture outside and they weren't obviously taken from the train.  Maybe I'll get to use them another month in another photo comp!

Comment: *Coast Starlight*?

Comment: @gparyani Yes - _Pacific Surfliner_ from San Diego to Los Angeles, then _Coast Starlight_ through to Seattle.  38 hours of train magic  

Comment: Trelfie? It's awesome!

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Taken from an abandonded train carriage at Yaniv Railway Station in the Chernobyl Exclusion Zone, today, August 10th, 2019.

Answer (score 13):

There is no frame and the glass is not very visible but I suppose it's obvious it was taken from a train. Akita Nairiku line, Japan, probably 2014.

[image]

Comment: The smudges on the glass are clearly visible, so this qualifies ;)

Answer (score 13):

I always considered gaffer tape as *the* universal repair tool and didn't consider sheets of paper in the same way. But obviously, if your train window is falling out, just jam in some paper.

For technical nerds: Outside the window is a dual gauge track with Hungarian standard gauge and Ukrainian 1520mm broad gauge.

[image: From a window]

Between Chop and Mukachevo, today, August 7th, 2019.

Answer (score 12):

Only seen snow a couple times in my life, so it was pretty cool to have snow for day two of our journey from San Diego to Seattle (Feb 2018).  This photo taken in [Deschutes National Forest between Crescent Lake and Odell Lake](https://goo.gl/maps/QSMeDSgAwEEQwtYE9)

[image]

Photo taken by me on Feb 4, 2018

Answer (score 12):

The following picture is taken on the typical one-way bridges that you find on the Southern Island in New Zealand. This particular picture is taken in January 2017, along Highway 6, on road to Wanaka. (I know this picture could also have been an entry in last months competition)
[image: Highway in New Zealand]

Comment: Is this one of those one lane bridges that is (in turn) used as a road bridge either direction and/or a rail bridge in either direction?

Comment: @Willeke Yes! And this was the longest one.

Comment: @Willeke There's a tunnel just like that in Whittier, Alaska.

Answer (score 12):

Approaching another tunnel, Bernina Express between Chur and Tirano, 2011.[image: Bernina Express]

Answer (score 11):

[image]

```
13 Jul 2011
Wed, 11:38
DSC_0510.JPG
10 MP3872 × 25923.8 MB
NIKON CORPORATION NIKON D80
ƒ/81/20020 mmISO100
```

Taken on the M41 highway in Tajikistan, between Dushanbe and Khorog. Tajikistan is on the left of the image, and across the river on the right is Afghanistan.

Answer (score 11):

The Hershey train from Havana to  Matanzas, Cuba, 2016 as we passed in the other direction. Sadly we broke down half way there. [image: Hershey Train]

Answer (score 10):

The first train ride of my son.

Photo taken somewhere between Berlin and Frankfurt, Germany.
2 Sept 2018

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Taken on a wildlife tour bus at Denali National Park, Alaska, on June 17, 2018.

We spotted some bears outside near the road the bus was driving on, and we had to slow down to avoid them chasing after us.

[image: Bears outside a bus]

Answer (score 10):

Photo taken by my wife in Croatia, on the road from Pula to Premantura, May 2016.

[image: Photo taken by my wife in Croatia, on the road from Pula to Premantura, May 2016.]

Answer (score 9):

[Taieri Gorge Railway, New Zealand](https://www.dunedinrailways.co.nz/our-journeys/taieri-gorge-railway). Taken December 2018.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
9 Aug 2011
Tue, 09:33
DSC_0285.JPG
10 MP3872 × 25923 MB
NIKON CORPORATION NIKON D80
ƒ/6.31/16020 mmISO100
```

Taken from inside a [UAZ-452](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UAZ-452) soviet van, on [Ольхо́н (Olkhon Island) in Lake Baikal](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Olkhon+Island/@53.2059957,106.7862384,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x5dac37fca674b5ff:0xf5ad2df1e424a77!8m2!3d53.1566678!4d107.383612), Siberia, Russia.

Answer (score 8):

Train to Denali, Alaska, from Anchorage:

[image: Train to Denali]

Answer (score 7):

Dog'sb first train ride. Late July 2019. Stuttgart, Germany. 
[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
14 Apr 2005
Thu, 21:13
DSC03421.JPG
7.1 MP3072 × 23042.7 MB
SONY DSC-V3
ƒ/81/4007 mmISO100
```

Giraffe, Kruger National Park, South Africa

Answer (score 7):

Mountain railway up to [Schynige Platte, Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schynige_Platte). The view out the window is of Interlaken. Taken July 2013.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Taken on the 15 June 2019 from a helicopter looking down at King's Canyon NT Australia.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Seen through the bus window between Luang Prabang and Vang Vieng, Laos, 2015. I know you can't see the glass although there is some reflection and dirty spots :)[image: Seen through the bus window between Luang Prabang and Vang Vieng, Laos, 2015.]

Answer (score 5):

A nice small road near Palling, Bavaria, Germany.

9 June 2018

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Photo taken at the [Kosamphi Forest Park](https://thailandtourismdirectory.go.th/en/info/attraction/detail/itemid/21558), Maha Sarakham, Thailand, dated July 2012.

**2: When they want you to give up the source of the free food:**

[image]

Note that there's a reflection of other monkeys in the top right corner. Not sure where they are though.

Edit: actually not sure what that is in the reflection, it doesn't really look like monkey. :?

Answer (score 4):

Taken some minutes bevore landing in Sofia, Bulgaria, and minutes after the end of the final game for the Bulgarian Football cup. Some friends of mine were in the stadium.

24 May 2017

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a picture taken in May 2018 in the Yosemite National park. It is taken on the road from Glacier Point back to Yosemite Village. One of the turns near the top offers this epic view.

[image: Glacier Point]

Answer (score 3):

[Sweeney Creek](https://goo.gl/maps/B5DP2TjM5PAjPp2X8), just as it comes into Lookout Point Lake near Lowell, OR.  From the train, traveling from San Diego to Seattle.

(I always thought creeks were small, to me this is a river)

[image]

Photo taken by me on Feb 4, 2018

Answer (score 3):

[image: Queensferry crossing during building]
This is the Queensferry crossing, taken from the north side, on our way to cross the Forth road bridge, (which was then very much still in use.)
Taken 25 august 2015. It does not show (much) but it was taken through the windscreen of a minibus. This is near Edinburgh, Scotland, UK.

Answer (score 2):

View out the window of the [TranzAlpine Railway, New Zealand](https://www.greatjourneysofnz.co.nz/tranzalpine/). My camera decided to focus on the raindrops, which accurately captured the weather outside. Taken June 2017.

[image]