# November 2019 photo competition: "How Did That Happen?"

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for November 2019 is: "How Did That Happen?" When asked for more information Mark Mayo gave these samples:

> a tank upside down next to the road, or a guy flying in the air above a bull (he got flipped up), ....
>   if you google it you'll see some great examples
>   like a boat in a house, or a truck that's gone through another one
>   a car tyre around a tree (seems simple until you realise it would need to have grown - the tyre can't be removed without cutting it

I'd say, use your imagination.

- As usual, one photo per post.
- You can post up to three posts.
- Do not delete posts if you do not get votes, you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more chances with your other photos.)
- All posts should have a line with when the photo was taken and what is in it and/or where it is.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named.)
- Keep it nice and non offensive.
- Do not downvote, if you do not agree with a photo do leave a comment to it or post in the chat.
- Only upvotes count.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo does not need to include people, but when it does, make sure they are either agreed with them being in and online or show them in such a way they can not be recognized. (Doctoring the photo to block out faces is allowed.) If in doubt, go by the laws in your country.
- Photos can be posted in the whole month of November, we use UTC, just as the site. The winner will be announced if there is no tie at the end of the month, and the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you want to have a say in the upcoming themes, add it to the [list here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition?noredirect=1&lq=1) and/or come to [the chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)

November 2019 is the last competition run by Willeke, (for a while at least) we are looking for someone to take over [more information here.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/photo-competition-series-needs-a-new-person-to-run-it?cb=1)

Mark Mayo has won the votes this month, with two photos on 14 votes.

Comment: Thank you for running these for so long! It's a great way to engage the Meta community.

Comment: Maybe the bar has been set too high for this month’s competition? I have no issues with the topic but with 0 answers in 5 days it might actually be counter productive and a little discouraging. Ordinary travellers like me rarely stumble upon something like that and have a picture of it taken by ourselves.

Comment: I agree, I had my doubts but it was the (only) topic proposed and no objections. Does anybody have suggestions?

Comment: I never took part on one of those contests. How do I participate? I just post the photo here? I may just have a thing.

Comment: @Willeke (Just a suggestion - if "How did that happen" is a bit too hard for travellers, maybe changing it to "No context" would relax the rules a bit while still allowing for very strange and fun photos.)

Comment: Yes, just post a photo and a few lines of text, with the date and location of the photo.

Comment: Apologies, been travelling for a few days and then got a puppy. I've got some photos I plan on adding

Comment: Mark, posting your photos does not solve the problem that very few people seem to have photos that fit the theme and it is not one you can go out for to take one.

Comment: I think more people do have ones.  It just requires thinking a bit about them.  Here's an article from the front page of today's main news site in NZ: https://www.stuff.co.nz/environment/climate-news/117224396/the-aral-sea-is-dying-putting-60-million-people-at-risk - that photo of the boats alone would work!

Comment: took a series of photos of #thatwanakatree this weekend - it's a tree growing in the middle of a large body of water. Looks so weird. Nearly submitted that too.

Comment: (scrolls through my photos) - some weird post earthquake ones of things in random places.  red sandstorm.  Me on top of a 737.  Blood stains across my bedroom wall (long story).  Train tracks that go nowhere (Valencia).  A raised motorway that suddenly ends in midair (Cape Town).  Photos of me in police cars in several countries (never arrested).

Comment: @Willeke Sorry for deleting my answers against the rules, I just don't feel like participating.

Comment: @HankyPanky Your choice but as we have so few entries this month, I feel your entries are even more important.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

Taken on the I95(?), Nov 5, 2010.

Might take a moment to realise the truck in front is pointed. At. Us.

Comment: Wow that's life threatening. I hope that driver went to Jail and nobody got hurt

Comment: @HankyPanky it was all good.  He was being towed.  But it was a little scary when we first saw it! ;)

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica, you have won this months competition with two photos both at 14 votes (next one has 8 votes.) I accepted this photo as I think it is closer to the theme as I understand it.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Camel drinking a Coke, Jan 3, 2008. Petra, Jordan.

Comment: This picture would be improved by closer cropping.

Comment: Indeed @Martha, as long as the quality remains the same. Best photograph in that contest, winner for me. :)

Answer (score 8):

[image: East Aligator river with 4x4 on it's roof further down the river, mostly out of the water]

Abandoned 4x4 in the East Aligator river alongside a ford bridge photographed by myself in June 2017 from a tour bus as we entered Arnheim land, NT Australia.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Upside down tank spotted on M41 highway between Dushanbe and Khorog, July 12, 2011.

Answer (score 5):

[image: A car sticking out of a wall]

Taken while on a bus tour through Toronto, Canada, 7 October 2014. 
I did not have more details but googling 'car sticking of a wall in Toronto' gave me [this link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/299_Queen_Street_West) Where one of the photos has this caption:

> CP24 Breaking News truck on the east wall of the building.

Comment: That's right, CP24 is a news channel (I believe it stands for City Pulse) and they have trucks they drive to the site of breaking news in the city. This isn't an accident though, but it is a deliberate pun (breaking news breaks through the wall) and a bit of a landmark on their building.

Comment: My coworker has PTSD from the time his neighbor drove through the front wall of his apartment. It was a matter of inches/minutes that neither he nor his dog were hurt. So pardon me while I fail to find this picture amusing.

Comment: The theme does not ask for amusing photos. Seeing a car sticking out of a wall high up is strange. And talking about cars in houses, when I still lived with my parents one of the others in the street had her foot stuck on the gas pedal and if going straight it would have entered our living room, she managed to do a 90 degree turn and get her car into her own house, (which was more brick and less glass than ours. Scary when we thought on what could have happened. If she had hit our house she would only have been stopped on the back wall, with us in the way.

Answer (score 4):

Where was that photograph taken from? Could it be from the tail of the airplane? :o

[image]

Of course not! :) I mean of course I was not standing on the tail of the airplane, but rather one of the cameras of the A380 superjumbo is located in its delta-shaped tail, allowing me to take that photograph with my camera from the screen in front of my sit.

Dawn in flight San Francisco - Paris, Sep 2016.

Answer (score 3):

This traffic sign raises more questions than answers, picture taken in December of 2018 along นน.4010, Phrae, Thailand. It seems more holes have been added since [the November 2013 image on Google Street View](https://www.google.com/maps/@18.1932249,100.4587345,3a,15y,29.83h,84.84t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sEyDNQDI_Z1ZrHd3mhE7dwA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656).

[image]

Comment: Hmm maybe small rocks getting flicked by vehicles?

Comment: @BobKerman nah, I think they're bullet holes. Just stopped there for a bit and saw the board. It's quite unusual, I think, haven't seen many things struck by bullets in Thailand.

Comment: It is just obscure that the holes are varying in size  Probably different bullets

Answer (score 2):

On the way to [Phu Thap Buek](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/phu+thap+buek), Phetchabun, Thailand in November of 2018, the road seems to have taken its own path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: A spinning jenny in very poor condition]

Taken on 20 September 2014, in the shop at Geysir Iceland, this is the sad remains of a spinning jenny, (a machine to spin several threads at once.)

It looked like it had been placed in the shop for some local tradition but had fallen in disrepair, quite badly 'broken'.