# April 2020 photo competition: "Hotels" (and other accommodations)

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

**The April 2020 photo competition is now over!**

---

The theme for the April photo competition is "Hotels". While the name of this competition specifically refers to *hotels*, this doesn't necessarily mean *hotels* per se: this means *any sort of* place where a traveler can spend time resting or sleeping, free or paid, while traveling. Examples would be an outdoor photo of an ornate resort, an indoor photo of a luxurious hotel suite, or even a set of airport cots. (Places that you stay long-term on a temporary basis do not count, e.g. a university dormitory doesn't count.)

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Only one photo per answer.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo was taken.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin April 1, 2020, 0:00 UTC, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/11329). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

## Results

mlc wins the bragging rights for the most voted photo this month, of the tents in Antarctica.

Mark Mayo wins the virtual prize for their long-exposure, tripod-less photo of the Burj Al Arab hotel in Dubai.

<sub>Rules adapted from [Willeke's previous photo competition](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6378/11329).</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Burj Al Arab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burj_Al_Arab) in Dubai, United Arab Emirates.
Photo: 6 July, 2007
Sony DSC-V3, f/7.1, 30 seconds, 7mm ISO100, no tripod.

[image: Burj Al Arab]

Comment: 30 seconds, no tripod. How steady are your hands?!

Comment: @JonathanReez used the beach sand, it's not perfect.  And rotated image later ;)

Comment: Good thing you didn't have to deal with reciprocity failure...

Comment: Congratulations! You win the virtual prize for this month's photo competition!

Answer (score 13):

[image]

There are no hotels in Antarctica, so if you want to stay on land overnight, tents are the way to do it. This is at Hanka Island in Leith Cove (64°52'S, 62°48'W), on February 24, 2019.

Comment: Congratulations! You've won the bragging rights as the highest-voted photo in this month's competition.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Långholmen Hotell]

This is the Långholmen Hotell, formerly a prison and now a place people stay voluntarily, in Stockholm, Sweden. Photo taken July 31, 2007.

Answer (score 8):

Salt Hotel, near Salar de Uyuni, Bolivia

July 26, 2010

Nikon D80

ƒ/5.61/12518 mmISO100

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is the [Sylvia Hotel](https://sylviahotel.com/) in Vancouver, BC, Canada.

Taken on October 5, 2019.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Spent two nights sleeping on a felucca (a small boat propelled by oars and/or lateen sails) on the Nile, Egypt.

27 Dec 2007
DSC-V3, f8, 1/250, 7mm ISO 100

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Photo competition entry]

Statue of 70s-era toys. This hotel is full of references to past decades stretching from the 1950s to the 1990s.

Disney's Pop Century Resort, Walt Disney World, Florida, USA.

Taken on Kodak Portra 160 film on July 5, 2019.

Answer (score 6):

The Hotel Del Coronado, in Coronado, CA (across the harbour from San Diego).  It is the second largest wooden structure in the USA, and apparently has had some very famous guests over the years and featured in a number of films including *Some Like It Hot*.

Photo taken by me on April 22, 2018.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Queimada dos Britos]

Queimada dos Britos, a tiny settlement in the middle of the Lençóis Maranhenses national park in Brazil.

It's a part of a small oasis where around 13 families live. You can sleep in the building on the right and even get some food (mostly tapioca, rice, beans and cashew nuts). One night costs R$30 (~6 USD), there are around 10 hammocks available.

Taken by me on July 6, 2018

Answer (score 5):

For sure not the most luxurious hotel in the world, but I really enjoyed it - big windwos, cold and snowy outside and warm inside.

It's the Maxi Velingrad Park Hotel & SPA in Bulgaria.

December 1, 2016

[image: Hotel in Bulgaria]

Answer (score 5):

Camping ground at [Phu Thap Boek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phu_Thap_Boek), Thailand:

[image]

I took the photo in December 2018.

Answer (score 3):

The "Carnival Sunrise", from the deck of the Norwegian Sky.  Photo taken in Freeport, Grand Bahama, on November 19th, 2019

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A hotel in Black Forest (Schwarzwald) in Germany

August 5, 2018

[image: Hotel in Black Forest]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The Tent in Munich. A couple hundred beds inside a huge tent. July 12, 2019.

Answer (score 2):

Trump International Hotel, Washington DC.  Photo taken on July 4th, 2018.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: 4 poster bed in room]
Photo taken 19 July 2019.
On arrival in the George hotel in Dorchester on Thames (UK) BF and I were given this ground floor room while my parents were given the other, not only up one set of stairs but down a few more steps, up some more and then at the other end of a long hall.
So we swapped rooms, sight unseen so the older couple did not have to climb stairs. If I had seen the room I might have been less fast to change. But it was much better for them, this room was not only ground floor but just outside the entry to the bar and dining area.
And the room was also quite big with a walk in shower in a roomy on-suite bathroom.

Answer (score 2):

The Pullman Hotel (left), the yellow Charoen Thani Hotel (right), and the Kosa Hotel (in front of the yellow hotel) in Khon Kaen, Thailand. Photo taken in July of 2012, from a room in Glacier Hotel. If I understand correctly, the unfinished tower was also supposed to be a hotel, the Kosa Complex Tower (according to Google Translate on [this page](https://www.skyscrapercity.com/threads/khon-kaen-city-skyline-of-the-north-eastern-thailand.202698/))
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Street face and garden of hotel]

O Jardim da Tessa, Lisbon, Portugal
Photos taken 2 January 2020, combined into one photo.

The hotel does not seem to have a garden when you see it on the street side. And the 'farmacia' on the ground floor did have a back exit with some space. But there was a charming garden, just a short bridge away from the building, with a lemon and orange tree, (which for us people from a lot farther north was a first.)