# September 2019 photo competition, Towers

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

Theme for September 2019 is *Towers*
In the [Travel Stack Exchange chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) we came to the following wording:

> Any natural or human-made structure that rises beyond 100 feet (30 meters) and should be taller than it is wide or a tower in the more traditional sense like a church tower, a part of a temple or castle or some such regardless of actual height.

- As usual, one photo per post.
- You can post up to three posts.
- Do not delete posts if you do not get votes, you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more chances with your other photos.)
- All posts should have a line with when the photo was taken and what is in it and/or where it is.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named.)
- Keep it nice and non offensive.
- **Do not downvote, if you do not agree with a photo do leave a comment to it or post in the chat.** Only upvotes count.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo does not need to include people, but when it does, make sure they are either agreed with them being in and online or show them in such a way they can not be recognized. (Doctoring the photo to block out faces is allowed.)
- Photos can be posted in the whole month of September, we use UTC, just as the site. The winner will be announced if there is no tie at the end of the month, and the voting period may extend beyond the month.
- If you want to have a say in the upcoming themes, add it to the [list here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition?noredirect=1&lq=1) and/or come to the chat which is mentioned above.

Kuba has won the bragging rights for the Azadi (Freedom) Tower in Tehran, Iran photo.

Tor-Einar Jarnbjo won the virtual prize for the photo of the Duga-1 receiver station near Chornobyl, Ukraine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: Freedom Tower]

Azadi (Freedom) Tower in Tehran, Iran. Sony Alpha a5100, April 2016

Comment: argh, naerly put my photos of this tower up! Your shot is way better.

Comment: You have the bragging rights, most upvoted photo during the competition month.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

A look up through the overgrown antenna tower of the [Duga-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duga_radar) receiver station near Chornobyl, Ukraine. August 9th, 2019.

Comment: My head wants this rotated, just because of the blue on the left and the green on the right.  I know it doesn't need to be, but I still find myself tilting my head ‍♂

Comment: @Midavalo Believe me, the image is the right way around and the structure is even more confusing when standing there.

Comment: You get the virtual prize. The right to make a map of this tower, it needs one. Of course, as usual, no travel money nor even drawing equipment provided. (Nor official permission if needed.)

Answer (score 13):

[image: Photo of a slender white tower seen over forest]

[Montjuïc Communications Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montju%C3%AFc_Communications_Tower), taken from a tour bus, 18 March 2013.
Barcelona, the tower is in the Olympic park.

Answer (score 12):

The towers and (towering) spires of Gdansk, Poland[image]

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Wat Arun Ratchavararam, Bangkok - Temple of Dawn.  April 2017, Nexus 6P.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Eiffel Tower, Paris, 03 Oct 2018. Nexus 6P.  I have this photo on my wall at home :D

Answer (score 9):

[image: shard]

A photo of the Shard from the bottom. 25th May, 2019. 306m, 310m to tip.

Comment: I love the camera angle!

Answer (score 8):

[image]
A lighthouse (not sure) by the Bodensee in Konstanz. You can see the Alps far in the distance. Taken in 21.04.2019.

Comment: It's a lighthose: https://www.lightphotos.net/photos/displayimage.php?album=18&pid=20818

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Minaret towers in Khiva, Uzbekistan. Nikon D40, July 2011.

Answer (score 8):

[image]
Medieval Torre dei Lamberti seen from Piazza dei Signori, also known as Piazza Dante, in Verona, Italy. Photo taken by my husband on 19th August 2019.

Answer (score 8):

Photo taken on the Klínovec Peak in Czech Republic

2 February 2019

[image: Klínovec]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

[Sudirman CBD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudirman_Central_Business_District) towers at dusk, Jakarta, Indonesia, 2019.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

How could we not include the Eiffel? :) Taken in 2006.

Answer (score 7):

The Tower at the end of the [Experience Treetop walk](https://www.bad-wildbad.eu/black-forest-where-to-stay/package-offers/experience-treetop-walk-spa-id_87938/) in Bad Wilbad, Germany

29 September 2018

[image: Tower in Black Forest]

Answer (score 6):

[image]
I'm not sure exactly what that tower is but I was standing in front of Christianborg in Kopenhagen when I took the picture. The date is 12.08.2019.

Comment: That’s the tower of St. Nikolaj’s church, at Nikolaj Plads. It’s no longer in use as a church. There’s an art gallery, but the reason I recognised it is that there is also a very nice restaurant in the building - where my wife and I held our post-wedding celebrations last month 

Comment: Thanks for the info, and congratulations on your wedding.

Answer (score 5):

[image: european central bank]

Seat of the European Central Bank, Frankfurt, Germany. 4th August 2017. 185m roof and 201m antenna.

Answer (score 5):

CN Tower, Toronto, June 2016

[image: CN Tower, Toronto]

Answer (score 5):

Leaning Tower of Pisa July, 2018.

[image: Leaning tower of Pisa]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

California Tower in Balboa Park, San Diego, CA

Photo taken March 1, 2018

Answer (score 4):

[image]
Tivoli Gardens, Kopenhagen. Taken in 14.08.2019.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Shwe Dagon Pagoda, Myanmar 2012]

Shwe Dagon Pagoda, Yangon, Myanmar 2012

Answer (score 4):

The Czech version of the Eiffel Tower - The Petřín Lookout Tower in Prague

3 September 2019

[image: Petřín Lookout Tower]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[Český Krumlov Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cesk%C3%BD_Krumlov_Castle), Czech Republic. May 5th, 2019.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Eiffel Tower, Las Vegas, NV. Photo taken by my wife as we drove through on June 28, 2018.

Answer (score 3):

Sintra Castle, Portugal, 2013[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Faro Tijuana, Playas de Tijuana, BC Mexico

Photo taken May 17, 2018.

OK so the tower is only 22m so not quite within the rules, but the focal point of the lighthouse is actually at 40m due to the land rising quickly from the beach.

On the right behind the lighthouse is the old Tijuana bullring, and behind me (not in the photo) is the border fence between Tijuana and San Diego.

Comment: It looks like a <s>duck</s> tower, it quacks like one, it waggles like one, it is a <s>duck</s> tower.

Answer (score 2):

[image: nelsons column]

Nelson's Column, Trafalgar Square, London. Taking during a light show. 20th January 2018. 52m.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Hallgrímskirkja]
This photo is taken of the tower of the [Hallgrímskirkja Reykjavic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallgr%C3%ADmskirkja) over the length of the church.

Photo taken 27 September 2014, one of many on that trip where my hotel could most easily be reached from many points in town passing the church.

Answer (score 2):

Picture taken from LX181 Bangkok to Zurich in December of 2018. In the centre you can see the traffic control tower at Suvarnabhumi Airport. At 132 metres, it's [the second tallest air traffic control tower in the world](https://www.klia2.info/klia2/facilities/tower-west/).

In the background you can see a lot of the high-rise of Bangkok.

[image]
(click and zoom for more detail)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Tower]

Communications tower, near St. Paul, Minnesota. Taken on a walk in William O'Brien State Park. Taken on September 28, 2019.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Church of our Savior in Copenhagen]

Church of our Savior in Copenhagen, taken in July 2016.

Comment: This competition already ended. Feel free to enter the new one: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6330/89966