# October 2019 Old Question Answerathon! Winner Willeke

Tags: discussion, fun, unanswered-questions, competitions

To give people time to enter, this will start on October 1st, UTC at midnight.

Rules: To stay in the competition, you must:

- answer an [unanswered question asked **ON OR BEFORE MARCH 31, 2019**](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) not asked by you AND receive an upvote for your answer.
- **once the upvote has occurred (and not earlier), edit the latest answer on this page for the date in question, and someone else can review and confirm.**  If not edited in before the 'day' is up, you're out.  Reviews can occur after the fact, but if the review fails, you're out.
- IF there are no [unanswered questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) at all (hah), then and only then can you answer a previously-answered question for your 'day'.
- IF the question you answer is marked as a duplicate on the same 'day', your answer is invalidated.

Each 'day' will last for 48 hours.  So October 1st-2nd inclusive is a day, October 3rd-4th is a day, and so on.

Miss a 'day' and you're out.

*However, please - if we finally hit a day where you can't answer something with a proper answer, i.e. with a citation or evidence or something useful to the author, don't post a weak answer on a question.*

I'll provide the sample answer template below for  October 1st. If you intend to enter, put your name there now.

Answer (score 1):

### October 1 -  3 entrants so far

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/147865/101 - Willeke
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) - [From JFK to Newark. Time & transportation alternatives](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126089/from-jfk-to-newark-time-transportation-alternatives/147841#147841) - Mark
3. [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) -  -

### October 3 -  2 entrants left

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - [Taking turmeric bulbs from Asia to Europe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134779/taking-turmeric-bulbs-from-asia-to-europe/147970#147970) - Willeke
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) - [BA: "anx9c1s6 type fares"?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125879/ba-anx9c1s6-type-fares/147959#147959) -Mark

### October 5 -  2 entrants left

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/148046/101 - Willeke
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) - [What effect could prior illegal work in the UK have on future visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126228/what-effect-could-prior-illegal-work-in-the-uk-have-on-future-visa-applications/148042#148042)  - Mark

### October 7 -  2 entrants left

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/148085/101 - was asked in august.

Edit: Mark: ARGH I linked the wrong one! Meant to be this: [Can a Swedish citizen on government benefits invite a person to stay with them?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124641/can-a-swedish-citizen-on-government-benefits-invite-a-person-to-stay-with-them/148084#148084)

2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) - [What can I do: UK transit visa not issued or passport returned: my flight is in two days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126553/what-can-i-do-uk-transit-visa-not-issued-or-passport-returned-my-flight-is-in/148124#148124) - Mark

Comment: I'd say you are out, @Mark

Comment: @Willeke, totally agree.