# October 2019 photo competition: "Musical instruments, buskers and travel related playing of music."

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the October 2019 photo competition is: "Musical instruments, buskers and travel related playing of music."

- In a line of text please add location, date and why this for you is a travel music photo.
- As usual, photos taken by you or by your travel companion (who must be named, nicknames accepted.)
- One post per photo, three posts max per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted, you posted it, you stand by it, you have two more options.
- The photo does not need to show the people by face but if it does, please make sure you have their permission to post the photo online or work the photo such that they can not be recognized from the photo, blocked out or blurred faces are acceptable, even when in the focus of the photo.
- Keep it nice and non offensive.
- **Do not downvote, if you do not agree with a photo do leave a comment to it or post in the chat.** Only upvotes count.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- Photos can be posted in the whole month of October, we use UTC, just as the site. The winner will be announced if there is no tie at the end of the month, and the voting period may extend beyond the month.
- If you want to have a say in the upcoming themes, add it to [this list](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition?noredirect=1&lq=1) and/or come to [the chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)

Comment: Perhaps a little late for this month's contest, but the question remains valid for future months anyway. I have a bunch of photos of a trip I took to watch a musical show. Some of the pictures show an iconic (IMHO) singer and band-leader who's been playing for a few decades. This specific show was recorded live and sold as a DVD (old times, I guess). Even in this specific situation, should I have this person's permission to post the photo as stated in one of the bullet points? Or could I assume he's Ok with that, given all the aforementioned circumstances?

Comment: @gmauch, the rules differ by country at the moment. I personally keep to ' if you can not recognize this person, it is permitted to post the photo'. But I know in many countries the rules are less strict. I do not know what the official rules/laws for TSE or all Stack Exchange sites are. Likely the USA laws?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

Accordion busker in Odessa, Ukraine. August 13th, 2019.

Comment: This is a beautiful shot, congratulations!

Comment: You won the bragging rights, most upvoted photo during the competition month.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Mouldy piano in a kindergarten in Pripyat, Chernobyl Exclusion Zone. August 10th, 2019.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Does an instrument in a statue count? Taken in Stuttgart, on 03.04.2019.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

The organ in the Konstanz Cathedral in Germany. Taken on 20.04.2019.

Answer (score 5):

Ibagué, Colombia, around August 2009. Just in front of the [Alberto Castilla, the music conservatory](https://monumentosdeibague.es.tl/SALON-ALBERTO-CASTILLA.htm) of the city there is this cool sculpture of a trumpet player.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The organ in Ulm Cathedral, taken on 20.04 2019.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little cheeky since this photo is a representation of musical instruments in the form of a cake at an [Acord concert](https://www.facebook.com/acordensemble/) roughly a year or so ago rather than actual instruments and musicians.  That said, it represents, in an ekphrastic manner, the spirit of musical performance.  The concert was a creative contrast in writing and music, about the [difference between drummers and musicians](https://www.facebook.com/events/802368363290255/).

[image: A musical cake]

Answer (score 4):

[image: busker with violin-horn]
Taken 15-April-2017, in Den Bosch, the Netherlands.
At the time I asked for permission to take the photo but not to publish it. So I have blurred his face. (It would be hard to impossible for me to find him again to ask permission.)
With this instrument I do not have a name at all.

Comment: That is a stroh violin or often simply called a horn violin when used in Eastern European, especially Romanian, folk music.

Answer (score 3):

A large Gong at [Prasat Wat Sa Kamphaeng Yai](https://thailandtourismdirectory.go.th/en/info/attraction/detail/itemid/1152) in Si Sa Ket province, Thailand:

[image]

Photo taken in July of 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Guča, Serbia, around August 2010.

Tons of street players gathering in the [Guča Trumpet Festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gu%C4%8Da_Trumpet_Festival), where a tiny village holds a colourful weekend with tens of thousands of visitors.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

May 2011, Krakow, Poland

Still trying to work out how he does this...

Comment: I have seen somewhere that the stick in fixated to the ground and goes through his sleeve forming a seat beneath him, hidden by the clothes. Something like that.

Comment: @undefined There is no need to fix anything to the ground. The pole is mounted on a large, sturdy plate, which is covered by the carpet. Then, there is as you said a seat under the clothes, which is mounted onto the pole. Since the center of mass is above and not outside the bottom plate, the arrangement is stable without overturning.

Answer (score 1):

[image: A guitar-lute being handed over]

In this case the instruments is traveling, at its change point in Germany. It is called a guitar-lute or lute-guitar (I am not sure.) It has been in my house on display for 10 years before being stored for an other 20.
Photo taken by Ken, (a friend whom I traveled with.) I got permission to post this pic from the guy holding the instrument.
Photo taken 6-10-2019, in Bremen Vegesack.

Answer (score 0):

[image: young man playing sax]
Taken from high up, while doing a tour of the Sacré-Cœur, Paris. 5 April 2015.

This man was just outside the church, in a location where the public can come.