# February 2020 Photo Competition - Lighthouses

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

**The February photo competition is now Finished!**

**Congratulations** to **[jason.kaisersmith for the winning entry](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6483/40422)!**  Entered later than most but pulled ahead very quickly, well done!

And the **virtual prize** for the [virtual lighthouses](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6476/40422) goes to **Dirty-flow**

---

The theme for February 2020 - **Lighthouses** by [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill)

> A lighthouse is a tower, building, or other type of structure designed to emit light from a system of lamps and lenses and to serve as a navigational aid for maritime pilots at sea or on inland waterways.
>
> - [Lighthouse - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighthouse)

**Note:** *To open this up to those who aren't near waterways or lighthouses, we will accept photos of buildings that are built to look like a lighthouse, even if they are nowhere near water (and have never functioned as a traditional lighthouse).*

Rules for February 2020:

- Photo is of a lighthouse
- One (1) photo per answser.
- You can post up to three (3) answers.
- All entries should include a line of text with the location and subject of the photo and when the photo was taken, date for recent photos, month for 'a few years old' and year only of old ones.
- Remember we are *Travel* stack exchange. If you can give the photo or its description a travel connection, you should get more votes (and/or stand a better chance on getting the virtual prize.)
- The photo has to be taken by the user who posted it, or one of a two person team (including the user), give credit to the actual person who took the photo, nick names are acceptable.
- Try and keep it non offensive.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo does not need to include people, but when it does, make sure they are either agreed with them being in and online or show them in such a way they can not be recognized. (Doctoring the photo to block out faces is allowed.)
- No entries/photos to be posted before the 1st of February, 2020
- No entries/photos to be posted after the end of February, 2020.
- Voting will run till midnight, the last seconds of February 2020* and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself. (*Or as soon after as your main judge can see the votes.)

**Please do not delete posts if you do not get upvotes (or even get down votes.) It is what you entered, stand by it.**

(If you think a photo does not meet the rules, you can post a comment or ask about it in the chat.)

---

If you want to join in sharing themes for future competitions, please see [Possible topics for the photo competition](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition). 
Just edit your suggestions into the community wiki answers there.
And to have a say in which one will be selected next month, do a suggestion, soon after a month started, in the [You Are Here chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)
Be ready to defend your choice for a while, as more people might post suggestions.

Comment: Midavalo, can you please accept the winning photo?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

St Marys lighthouse in Northumberland.

Taken in April 2018, while on holiday in Northumberland.

[image]

Comment: That is a beautiful photo!

Answer (score 14):

[image: Faro Les Éclaireurs]

Here's a photo I took of a bunch of [cormorants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_shag) hanging out at the [*Faro Les Éclaireurs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Eclaireurs_Lighthouse), at 54°52′S, 68°5′W in the Beagle Channel off the coast of Ushuaia, Argentina. This was taken February 19, 2019.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Point Vicente Light, California]

Looking south toward the Point Vicente Light in December 2014, atop the 130-ft (40m) cliffs of the Palos Verdes peninsula near Los Angeles.

"We have lighthouses in the Netherlands," my skeptical visiting 16-year-old niece had said. "But they don't have California around them," I responded.

Answer (score 9):

Lighthouse in Akaroa, Canterbury, New Zealand.

19 Dec, 2005.

```
SONY DSC-V3
ƒ/5.61/40023.4 mmISO100
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Picture taken on 21.04.2019 in Konstanz, Germany, by the Bodensee.

In the picture one can see:

- The boat that makes the connection between Konstanz and Friedrichshafen
- The lighthouse
- The statue called Imperia, which keeps spinning non-stop
- A Zeppelin
- Far in the distance, the Alps

Comment: A friend gave me this link, the same location pre 1890: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Konstanz_Hafenturm_pre1890.jpg

Comment: @Willeke amazing. The lighthouse has changed a lot in these "few" years.

Answer (score 8):

The Key West Lighthouse, in Key West, Florida.  Photo taken by me (or my wife - can't remember) on Nov 20, 2019.  [Google Maps location](https://goo.gl/maps/8JgSq97R9FZmx3KEA).

The lighthouse is about half a kilometre from the sea, but since everything is so flat there are no obstructions.  The Light is about 30m above sea-level (it was raised at one point to be sure it was above the tree-line).  It was decommissioned in 1969.

Unfortunately we didn't have time to go in or up, just got some photos from the fence. It's also almost right across the road from Ernest Hemmingway's house ([map pin](https://goo.gl/maps/e3D2VU1X4YSJxN8w8)).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image: a small lighthouse in a town setting]
Phare Rouge de La Rochelle, France, photo taken by Willeke, 5 March 2015.

When walking around in the area I thought this was a 'fun' lighthouse, a miniature in some ways, but looking on the map and seeing its name it seems a proper working one, if small, at the entrance to a port (now mostly used as a marina) on this photo behind it.

Comment: What's the green-topped one in the background, Willeke? Is that a lighthouse too?

Comment: @Midavalo, google maps shows it as 'Phare Vert Quai Valin' (the green lighthouse) and it is a very nice one to see close up. It seems to be a normal house of just two stories and an attic and the tower goes from the ground to about 5 more stories. Google streetview link: https://www.google.com/maps/@46.1569309,-1.1498661,3a,60y,62.08h,95.82t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sEuGLHrYVC7P29BrNVdftfg!2e0!7i16384!8i8192

Answer (score 7):

Cremorne Point Lighthouse, Sydney, Australia, 16 Nov 2016 at 18:58.

Nexus 6P phone camera.

Auto-'enhanced' by Google, but hey it'll do.

[image: Cremorne Pt Lighthouse]

Answer (score 6):

This is Castle Point lighthouse, in New Zealand, north of Wellington on the east coast of the North Island.

This is a beautiful day trip from Wellington driving among the winding roads of the South Wairarapa to reach this remote shore, or a nice detour on a road trip between Hawke's Bay and Wellington.

Taken on April 25, 2019

[image: Castle Point lighthouse]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Tarhalsen]
Lighthouse at Tarhalsen, Sørøya, Hammerfest Komune, Finnmark, Norway, with the Norwegian Sea in the background.  70°52'N, 23°19'E.  Taken 2012-09-06.   See [location on map](https://norgeskart.no/#!?project=norgeskart&layers=1004&zoom=13&lat=7882705.92&lon=804304.21&markerLat=7883652.658854166&markerLon=803275.4856770833&panel=searchOptionsPanel&sok=Tarhalsen).  Weather was around 3°C, wet, and windy.  Photo taken by myself.

IIRC this lighthouse was newly constructed ca. 2009 because of the [Snøhvit natural gas field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sn%C3%B8hvit).  The trail was brand new when I got there, and I discovered it entirely by chance.  On the way there is a [small cabin with 3 beds](https://ut.no/hytte/10105/tarhalshytta) that is free to use.

As a bonus, a few photos on the way to get there (hidden by default because they violate the one photo per answer rule, hover over to see):  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCCIG.jpg) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHjsc.jpg) [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jx3w.jpg) [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raevZ.jpg).

Comment: Love how you've included those extra photos - it gives a bit more to the location without breaching the rules. Would be great if we had some kind of photo album to share some of our travels 

Comment: @Midavalo, some of us do publish albums online. They can add a link to their answers. I do not publish many photos but some are on Flickr.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Lighthouse at Beacon Cove Port Melbourne Australia.  The lighthouse is in Port Phillip Bay and apparently it used to have a bridge joining it to the mainland. There is a second lighthouse a little way inland in a park.

The photo was taken by myself on 3-September-2019.

It is beside Station Pier which can be reached by light rail from the centre of Melbourne.  The ferry to Tasmania departs from that pier.

Comment: Wow that's bigger than I first thought - looked like a marker buoy to start with, until I zoomed in :)

Answer (score 5):

The Stonington Harbor Light, in Stonington, Connecticut ([Google Maps location](https://goo.gl/maps/SC9UHMWzo3Y2K3P28)).  Photo taken Sept 27, 2017.  Due to car troubles creating havoc to our vacation plans, my family ended up staying for 3 weeks in NW Connecticut, so we did a lot of day trips in a friend's car.

We decided to drive to the coast, as we had never seen the Atlantic Ocean, and ended up going through New London, Mystic, Stonington, and on to Misquamicut Rhode Island.  We found this beautiful old stone lighthouse in Stonington.  And I guess those places technically might not quite be considered on the Atlantic, but it was close enough for us!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I don't have any photos of a real lighthouse but I will try to win the virtual prize with these virtual lighthouses.

*Photo taken on 9th of February 2020 in Mainz, Germany*

[image]

Comment: When I was trying to find my lighthouse photos I found a photo of a painting or mural of a lighthouse... I wondered at the time whether I could post that :)

Answer (score 3):

Norah Head Lighthouse, NSW.  Allegedly [you can see Sydney from here on a clear day](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/88397/101).

10 Jan, 2015.

```
HTC HTC_0P6B
ƒ/21/44943.82 mmISO125
```

[image]