# March 2020 Photo Competition - Travel Favorites

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

**The March photo competition is now closed!**

---

The theme for March 2020 - **Travel Favourites**

> A favourite photo from your travels - maybe it's your favourite because it looks amazing, or maybe there's a background story to the photo (please include the story!) - Keeping it broad this month so that everyone has a chance to enter!

Rules for March 2020:

- Photo is your Favourite Travel photo - anything *travel* related
- One (1) photo per answer.
- You can post up to three (3) answers.
- Include an explanation as to why this is your **Favourite Travel photo**
- All entries should include a line of text with the location and subject of the photo and when the photo was taken, date for recent photos, month for 'a few years old' and year only of old ones.
- Remember we are *Travel* stack exchange. If you can give the photo or its description a travel connection, you should get more votes (and/or stand a better chance on getting the virtual prize.)
- The photo has to be taken by the user who posted it, or one of a two person team (including the user), give credit to the actual person who took the photo, nick names are acceptable.
- Try to keep it non offensive.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo does not need to include people, but when it does, make sure they are either agreed with them being in and online or show them in such a way they can not be recognized. (Doctoring the photo to block out faces is allowed.)
- No entries/photos to be posted before the 1st of March, 2020
- No entries/photos to be posted after the end of March, 2020.
- Voting will run till midnight, the last seconds of March 2020* and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself. (*Or as soon after as your main judge can see the votes.)

**Please do not delete posts if you do not get upvotes (or even get down votes.) It is what you entered, stand by it.**

(If you think a photo does not meet the rules, you can post a comment or ask about it in the chat.)

---

If you want to join in sharing themes for future competitions, please see [Possible topics for the photo competition](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition). 
Just edit your suggestions into the community wiki answers there.
And to have a say in which one will be selected next month, do a suggestion, soon after a month started, in the [You Are Here chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)
Be ready to defend your choice for a while, as more people might post suggestions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

06.04.2019 in Pula, Croatia. Taken with a GoPro.

This was the first time I've been to cave, my first time kayaking, my first time in Croatia... Lots of "first times" in this picture. And it looks amazing. BTW, that's me in the picture.

Comment: Tied for first place! Voting has been extended.

Comment: Congratulations @undefined - great photo!

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Dettifoss, Iceland, in August 2018. I walked over 60km that day from my camping spot in Ásbyrgi and back; it's also possible to get relatively close with a car, but given the minimal amount of sunshine that day I would have surely missed this beautiful rainbow caused by the 'cataractagenitus' clouds.

Comment: Tied for first place! Voting has been extended.

Answer (score 8):

Solar eclipse, Novisibirsk, Siberia, Russia, August 1, 2008.

Not the crispest of images, but I got the diamond ring, and a couple of stars visible in the background. My first of 3 total solar eclipses.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A road in the Teide National Park in Tenerife, Canary Islands, Spain. The roads there were really nice, with nice panorama views. There were rocks and minerals in many different colours and compositions.

*September 30, 2016*

[image: Teide National Park]

Answer (score 7):

Horseshoe Bend, Sep 2 2012.

The Grand Canyon is spectacular, Meteor Crater is unique, but this...this was special.

[image]

Comment: Is this that same photo with a little camp on the beach?

Comment: similar. I took a LOT of photos there.

Comment: I think I got this picture too :)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

02.02.2019. Marrakech, Morocco. Taken with a OnePlus 5T.

Picture looks really good and I thought it captured the "essence" of the city.

Answer (score 6):

Machu Picchu, Peru, October 14, 2010.

I ran at gate open to the top to get my shot sans-tourists. There are a couple in frame (I do have others with none) but this is one of my favourites.

(I then collapsed for a good few minutes to get my breath back, stupid altitude and running)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: A set of stairs and an escalator as 'street' in Lisbon]
Still in Lisbon, 31st of December 2019, we took this 'street' in a try to get to visit the [Castle in the city.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGQIS.jpg) It turned out not to be the best route but it was fun. An escalator going up at least the level of 4 stories of the houses next to it, followed by a shorter one, as normal street in the city. The Castle was closed as all staff were given a day off, for New Years Eve.

Answer (score 4):

A dream came true as I attended the Monaco Formula 1 Grand Prix in 2015. The whole week on the French Riviera was magnificent, but my personal highlight was walking the entire lap of the circuit.

*May 20, 2015.*

[image: Monaco Grand Prix]

Answer (score 4):

One of my favorite places in the world: San Francisco and environs. Taken November 20, 2018 with a Samsung Galaxy S7 Plus (reduced for size). My family had driven up to stay with friends in Livermore and went into the City. This was during the fires so the air was quite smoky. I believe this was the first time I'd taken a harbor cruise.

[image: Golden Gate Bridge from a boat]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

20.04.2019. Konstanz, Germany. Taken with a Mate 20 Pro.

Saw this pretty girl while walking by the river. Never thought I would be able to take a picture of the egg as well.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Cow]

December 3, 2019, near Nagpur, India. Taken on Kodak Ektar 100 film and self-scanned.

Got up close to a wandering cow. There are quite a few of them who wander around the neighborhood and eat things residents serve to them.

Answer (score 3):

The best view I have ever had from a restaurant.

On our roadtrip through the Alps we made a stop in the Appenzell District, Switzerland. Our host recommended us the [Berggasthaus Aescher-Wildkirchli](https://aescher.ch/en/). The hike was really nice but the view from terrace was stunning.

May 30, 2019.

[image: Aescher]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Dogs]

December 2019, at Korambi River Park, near Nagpur, India. Shot on Kodak Ektar 100 film and self-scanned.

Couple of dogs <s>enjoying</s> sleeping in thick mud. The mud is so thick that it could have consumed them; it shows how brave these dogs are.

Answer (score 2):

[image: A red Lisbon tram and a green double decker bus.]
When in Lisbon, 30 December 2019, we visited the Tram museum and I took this picture of the 'little' tram they use to transport the visitors between the different parts of the museum. It is a tram like run in the city but the [insides are pretty fancy, soft upholstery.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVFMK.jpg)
In a city where most sights and museums were packed by crowds, this museum could certainly do with more visitors. It is back to back with the [Pilar 7 bridge experience](https://www.visitlisboa.com/en/places/pilar-7-bridge-experience), which in itself was also worth visiting, (but the photos I took there do not meet the quality I would post in this competition.)

Answer (score 1):

Bucharest, Romania, from QR196 Brussels to Doha in December 2019:
[image]

I'm including it because it was interesting to have such a clear (at least for a phone pic) photo at cruising altitude.

Answer (score 1):

[image: small sailing boat under sail]
Taken 4 May 2017, spending a day with a group of friends (most of us knot tyers) in the Bideford / Appledore area, Devon UK, we saw this little boat sailing a few times on different parts of the water.

What makes this photo even more a travel photo is the backdrop with cars and boats almost at touching distance from each other.