# May 2020 Photo Competition - Waterfalls

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I will be hosting this month's photo competition. The theme chosen for this month is waterfalls! This theme was suggested [on this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition) by *obligated to keep his content*.

According to [the dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/waterfall), a waterfall is defined as:

> a steep fall or flow of water in a watercourse from a height, as over a precipice; cascade.

**This can be either natural or man made**.

Rules adapted from *Willeke*'s competition:

- **Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st May (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted**
- Please include the name of the waterfall (if known) and where and when the photo was taken
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named
- One post per photo, three posts max per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted, you have two more chances
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission (or blur their faces)
- No offensive photos
- **No downvotes**, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree
- **Photos may be posted until 00:00:00 1st June (UTC Time)** when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue

If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here). Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or add it to [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5049/105447).

**Congratulations to [our winner](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6596/105447) - *Chris H*.**

Comment: Is there a minimum height?

Comment: @undefined No, but it has to be of a reasonable height. You can decide what 'reasonable' is :)

Comment: Is it allowed to repost [earlier entries](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6507/28333)?

Comment: @Glorfindel You can, but there have been negative comments before of similar/same re-posted photos

Comment: OK, luckily I have dozens of waterfall photos from that same trip :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: Svartifoss]

After getting married in August last year, my wife and I spent our honeymoon hitch-hiking in Iceland. At [Skaftafell, a region of the Vatnajökull National Park](https://www.vatnajokulsthjodgardur.is/en/areas/skaftafell), I took this photo of Svartifoss. The basalt columns make it look like something from another planet.

Answer (score 13):

This is my picture of the Iguazu Falls, that I took last February. The Brazilian side of the Iguazu falls is a bit underappreciated, but this was my favorite spot, where you can look down into the water, see them in a distance, and are surrounded by them (huge fall to the left of this picture too).
[image: Iguazu Falls]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Kaieteur Falls]

Kaieteur Falls, Guyana, taken by me on 9th Feb 2019.

Pretty much the only way to get there is to fly a small Cessna from the capital, and you fly really low over the waterfalls several times. It's really deep in the jungle, you can see some cool animals around (like cock-of-the-rock and colorful frogs).

Answer (score 9):

[image: river going into a waterfall, seen from above]

This is one of my favorite pictures of [Gullfoss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullfoss), a waterfall on Iceland. Likely the best known, as it is a very great view and relatively close to the capital city.
Photo taken on 20-9-2014, by Willeke (and I put it in the public domain now.)

On this one trip I visited both this fall and Niagara falls from the Canadian side, and preferred the Icelandic one.

Answer (score 8):

Niagara Falls, taken by me on July 2, 2018, from Niagara Falls, Ontario, Canada.

[image]

I had plenty of others that I think probably look better, but they all have me or my wife or both of us in it.  Plus I love how the water just seems to disappear in this one!

Answer (score 8):

[image: Chapada dos Veadeiros]
One of many waterfalls in Chapada dos Veadeiros in central Brazil.

To get there you need to go to Brasilia, drive for few hours and sleep in a quilombo (a settlement founded by escaped slaves in 19th century). Whole national park is brilliant, full of trails with dozens of waterfalls every few kilometres, so you can walk and swim all day.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Nan Lian Garden]

Not every restaurant has a waterfall inside of it, but this one ([Chi Lin Vegetarian](https://www.google.com/search?q=chi+lin+vegetarian)) does. This is  the Long Man Lou waterfall in the [Nan Lian Garden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nan_Lian_Garden) in Hong Kong; photo taken May 13, 2016.

Answer (score 7):

Kaiate Falls, Welcome Bay, New Zealand.  Photo taken by me on April 6, 2019.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A wide and shallow waterfall in Thailand: Pa Wai Waterfall, taken in November of 2018:

[image]

Not as pretty as the stock photos, but I guess those are either taken in the rainy season and/or further downhill. I think it's an interesting picture though, with the trees in the stream.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

This is along the Mist Trail in Yosemite National Park, California, USA, and, true to its name, there was enough mist to get some lovely rainbows along the waterfall. One of my oldest photos that I have digitally, this was taken in July, 2001.

Comment: Would love to visit Yosemite... one day, after the grand canyon (just because that's a shorter drive away)

Comment: @Midavalo It's been some time since I was last there, but it's such a lovely place; hope you do manage to get out there soon! I've heard that a huge percentage of tourists don't ever get up out of the valley — make sure that you do, though!

Comment: @Midavalo So much worth it. Definitely go up the Mist Trail, Yosemite Point and Glacier Point while you're there!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

I took this photo at [the Batereyskiy waterfall](https://goo.gl/maps/BZWunn1z9RuD4T4V9)  last year. Located near Teriberka, a small Russian town inside the arctic circle, you can see that even though our visit was in mid-May, the waterfall and area around it was still partially frozen. From the fall, a stream runs for about 100m before emptying out into the Barents Sea

The woman visible in the bright green jacket and pink hat is my wife. Shortly before I took this photo, she took [this one of me making my way across the rocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCuZE.jpg), which I also really like (especially in combination).

Answer (score 6):

Bowen Falls at the head of Milford Sound (which is actually a fjord), New Zealand.  Photo taken in February 2020.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

These falls start several levels up from this point, and drop another several levels down behind me to the right.  Not huge - we could climb up/down each drop easily enough (by climb I just mean a large step and pull LOL)

I'm not sure if these falls even have a name - we were lucky enough to stay at a lodge in the lower Kaimai Ranges (Bay of Plenty, New Zealand) for a week before returning to work in Mexico, and this river and these falls (and others) went through the property.

Photo taken by me on April 30, 2019.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Gulfoss, Iceland taken on July 3rd 2017.

Took a long exposure shot with my phone from a vantage point right in the middle of the falls.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Water falling from a cliff face]
One of the many waterfalls we saw when I took a day tour from Reykjavik to Jökulsárlón (the Glacier Lagoon,) which is a long distance along the #1 road, Iceland.
I think this is the [Seljalandsfoss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seljalandsfoss) but not completely sure.
Photo taken 23 September 2014, at the falling of the evening.
We did go behind the fall but it was already too dark for the camera I used.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right with the Seljalandsfoss!

Answer (score 4):

[image: Niagara Falls]

Do I really need to say where? Probably the most famous waterfall in the world: Niagara Falls. I think I got lucky with the lighting in this shot on what was otherwise a fairly average day for photography (13th of August, 2012).

Answer (score 4):

Lulumahu Falls in Hawaii on the island of Oahu!  Photo taken in January 2020.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hotnica Waterfall in Bulgaria.

*September 2015*

[image: hotnica waterfall]

Answer (score 3):

Triberg Waterfalls - the highest waterfalls in Germany.

*August 2018*

[image: triberg waterfalls]

Comment: Highest or tallest?

Comment: @Midavalo according to https://www.triberg.de/ -> the highest

Answer (score 3):

[image: Webster’s Falls]

Webster’s Falls at Spencer Gorge Conservation Area, Dundas, Ontario, Canada. Taken August 17th, 2012.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Iguazú Falls]

Everyone who visits Iguaçu Falls on the Brazilian/Argentinian border wants to get close—as they should: they're impressive, and a bit of cooling mist is always welcome in such hot weather! This was taken January 31, 2019.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The Vøringfossen  waterfall, Eidfjord, Norway. 24th July 2019. Taken by me on a cruise stop.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
A portrait of my son taken a few years ago in the Chinese Garden in Sydney. It was taken without a tripod and I was amazed that I managed to keep him fairly sharp with the long exposure needed to blur the water.

Answer (score 2):

[image: water streaming out of a sluice]
This is where the Canal de Marans à la Rochelle meets the Vieux-Port de La Rochelle, France. Taken 5 March 2015.
Not meant to be a waterfall but these water levels in the canal and the harbour it became one.

Answer (score 2):

Seasonal waterfalls in Taroko Gorge National Park, Tawain!  Photo taken in September of 2018.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Close-up shot of the large waterfall at Los Peñasquitos Canyon Preserve, San Diego, California, USA.

Taken on Kodak Ultramax 400 film on October 20, 2019. This is one of the best results I've ever managed to achieve from this particular film stock.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a picture I took at the Fainter Falls in Victoria (Australia), December 12th, 2019. It was not the waterfall that impressed me most.  I was completely alone on the short trail to the waterfall, and you clearly see the small leaflet on the bottom left. It was the story about [Riley](https://www.facebook.com/rememberingRiley2015/) , who died before his first birthday. It touched me a lot, and it still makes me appreciate all the things I can do a bit more.
[image: Fainter Falls]

Comment: Victoria where? Canada, Australia, somewhere else?

Comment: Australia, I thought that was unambiguous, but apparently not :)

Answer (score 1):

Once again the Hotnica Waterfall in Bulgaria, but this time from the top.

*September 2015*

[image: hotnica waterfall]