# June 2020 Photo Competition - Local Markets

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I will once again be hosting this month's photo competition. The theme chosen for this month is *local markets*! This theme was suggested [on this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition) by *obligated to keep his content*.

A description of the theme was decided [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54469400#54469400):

> A local market of a place you live/you visited. A supermarket is ok as long as it is not your average supermarket, but something a bit out of the ordinary/unusual

Rules adapted from *Willeke*'s competition:

- **Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st June (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted**
- Please include the name of the local market/supermarket (if known) and where and when the photo was taken
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named
- One photo per post, three posts max per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted, you have two more chances
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission (or blur their faces)
- No offensive photos
- **No downvotes**, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree
- **Photos may be posted until 00:00:00 1st July (UTC Time)** when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue

If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here). Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or add it to [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5049/105447).

---

**Congratulations to [our winner](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6619/105447) - *undefined*.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

The entrance of the Souk in Marrakech. The foto is from 2.Feb.2019.

Device: OnePlus 5T

Comment: Wow! I really like the lightning in this picture!

Comment: Perhaps you meant Lighting?

Comment: This photo had the most votes at the end of the month.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Local market (I can't remember which one it was) in Cuenca, Ecuador

Photo taken by me in March 2019

Answer (score 6):

[image: Little India, Diwali Market]

Little India in Singapore. Seasonal market during the Diwali festival.

Photo by myself, on October 5, 2018.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Crowds in the Djemaâ el Fna at sunset in 2008]

The Place Djemaâ el Fna in the Marrakech medina at dusk, February 2008. The minaret of the Koutoubia Mosque is visible to the left and the souks are behind the food stalls to the right. We were seated on the upper level of a cafe towards the eastern end of the plaza to watch the sunset, but I cannot remember the name or details of the place, unfortunately.

We were treated to tremendous [mint tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maghrebi_mint_tea) wherever we traveled in Morocco—in the countryside, that is. Here in the city, they charged ~6 USD for supermarket-grade black tea, but they knew it wasn't the tea people came to buy.

Comment: I loved this place. Where did you take this picture from? Was it from the upper floor of one of the cafes in Jma El Fna?

Comment: @undefined It was from an outdoor patio area on the upper level of one of the cafes toward the eastern end of the plaza. I do not recall the name, unfortunately. The former Bank Al-Maghrib building at left in the photo still stands and is visible from Google Street View if that helps with orientation; we wanted a place with a view of the sunset.

Answer (score 4):

[image: fruit]

There's a "tradition" in my family of taking pictures of fruit stands when travelling—so when I stopped by [La Boqueria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Boqueria) in Barcelona, I knew I had to snap this shot.

This photo is from July 23, 2007.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Fish market Kardha]

A local street-side meat and fish market in a small suburban town in central India.

Taken by me in early December 2019, on Kodak T-Max 400 black-and-white film.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Market of Lights]

**Market of Lights**

Photo taken at Arab Street in Singapore by myself during month of Ramadan.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Dead llama fetuses at the "Witches' Market" in La Paz, Bolivia 2019 (sorry for the name, the concept of witches was horribly used during witch hunts). As well as many other supposedly medical drugs in the background with typically no scientific evidence supporting their use.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Where do you go when you've got 24 hours in Seattle and want to go somewhere touristy?

**Pike Place Market**

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pike_Place_Market) it's the 33rd most visited tourist attraction in the world, yet still a continuously operated public farmer's market.

To be fair we just went there because our friend who grew up in Seattle said we should check it out... it was definitely worth the effort!

Photo taken by me on Feb 5, 2018, on intersection of Pike and Pine, Seattle, WA.  [Google Maps link](https://goo.gl/maps/94haFRZuTrSHxmZi9)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Food Market]

A hawker center, aka **Food Market** in Singapore during Chinese New Year. Photo by myself.

Comment: Nice photo. But can you please add the date? (If long ago a year or even a decade would do.)

Answer (score 1):

[image: tea market]

The Fāngcūn Tea Market in Guangzhou is a huge (this photo really doesn't show the scale of it, unfortunately) wholesale market for [all the tea in China](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_the_tea_in_China). I had no wholesale business to attend to, but stopped by anyway, and some of the vendors were willing to sell in retail quantities. I also bought a set of teaware, which I carefully carried with me to Hong Kong, shipped home to New York (it wouldn't fit in my luggage), and carelessly broke the second time I went to take it off of my shelf to actually use it.

This photo is from May 10, 2016.

Answer (score 1):

[image: lit up deli]

Sometimes, you travel and find yourself in a new environment; other times, you stay in one place and the environment changes by itself. After ["Superstorm" Sandy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Sandy), most of Lower Manhattan lost power for several days. But this bodega had access to a generator: it's a way to draw a crowd! Today, the environment has changed again, drawing a crowd is no longer such a great idea, and [bodegas are wondering](https://ny.eater.com/2020/4/10/21214971/nyc-bodegas-coronavirus-survival-grocery) what their next move should be.

This photo was taken November 1, 2012, on the Lower East Side of New York City.