# July 2020 photo competition: "Human- or animal-powered vehicles"

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the July photo competition is "Human- or animal-powered vehicles". Essentially, this covers any object used for transporting people or goods, that receives all or most of its motive power from one or more humans or animals. (The humans or animals need not be in the picture.)

(For human-powered vehicles, the vehicle should be intended to transport at least one other human aside from the operator, or be intended to transport goods; things that are *solely* intended to transport the human operator - e.g. a bicycle - may be submitted, but are not preferred.)

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Only one photo per answer.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo was taken.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin July 1, 2020, 0:00 UTC, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/11329). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

## Results

I (gparyani) win the bragging rights for having the most voted photo this month, of the bullock cart moving crops in India.

Ray Butterworth wins the virtual prize, for their photo of the horse and buggy parking at The Home Depot (awarded after a [suggestion from Midavalo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55125095#55125095)).

Comment: About 7 hours before the deadline, I remembered the contest when a horse and buggy passed me in the opposite direction.
I u-turned and 5 minutes later managed to pass (horses go uphill faster than I can, but apparently don't speed up much going downhill), parked my bike, readied the camera, and then the horse made a left turn.  So the first photo ended up cropped from a small detail in a much larger photo (I later re-edited the entry to crop it even further). That semi-failure inspired a visit to the horse parking sheds at Walmart, Conestoga Mall, and Home Depot, all of which were empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part two of two of pathetic last-minute attempt, taken in Waterloo, Ontario.

I'd hoped to get the horse and buggy and the shelter in the same photo, but no joy.
(That's my bicycle, so I guess that counts as the vehicle.)

[image]

Comment: Well, it seems your last-minute attempt paid off. After a [suggestion from another user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55125095#55125095), I've decided to award this photo the virtual prize.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Bullock cart]

A bullock cart moving crops from a farm to the nearby city, in central India.

Taken by me in early December 2019, on Kodak Ektar 100 color film.

Comment: A better view for the driver than the old horse & buggy setup with the driver behind the horse.

Answer (score 6):

Dry goods delivery – can wait while the driver drinks tea and watches satellite TV.

[image]

Taken by me in Marrakech, Morocco in January 2011.

Answer (score 5):

Buggy rides for the tourists at Nassau, The Bahamas.

[image]

This horse was *not* having a good day - the sea was rough and was crashing up over the roads.  The driver drove the buggy down the Esplanade, with the waves crashing about it which caused the horse to flinch and complain, only to find the other end of the Esplanade was completely flooded and he couldn't get through.

So he turned around and tried to go back the way they'd come.  But by now the waves were bigger and the horse just refused - they must have made 5 or more attempts, and the driver got out a couple times to calm the horse.  Eventually there was a long enough break in the waves to get out of the lane again.

I'm actually surprised that none of my photos of this actually showed the waves crashing up over the road.

Photo taken by me, November 18, 2019. Junkanoo Beach, Nassau, The Bahamas.  [Google Maps Link](https://goo.gl/maps/b977RKVDRnhdXaZ18)

Answer (score 3):

The Horse-Drawn Street Car at Disneyland!  Los Angeles, CA, USA.

[image]

Photo taken by me in November 3, 2015.  (faces pixelated by me)

Answer (score 2):

Two for the price of one?  An old horse buggy and an ice-cream cart (and the driver) outside a restaurant in Rosarito, Mexico.

[image]

Photo taken by me, October 20, 2017

Answer (score 2):

These are rikshaws in New York city, at the south end of Central Park. I was actually surprisied to see them in this place. The thing are rather expensive, but I found it hilarious, because the one on the left is 3.00 $/min and the one on the right 2.99 $/min. The picture is from October 2014.
[image: New York]

Answer (score 0):

Part one of two of pathetic last-minute attempt, taken between Waterloo and Saint Jacobs, Ontario.

[image: Horse and buggy near maple syrup and summer sausage signs.]