# August 2020 photo competition: Mountains

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the August photo competition is "Mountains" (proposed by [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo?tab=profile)). Essentially, this covers any photo of a feature of land that meets the [definition of a mountain](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mountain): *a natural elevation of the earth's surface rising more or less abruptly to a summit, and attaining an altitude greater than that of a hill, usually greater than 2000 feet (610 meters)*.

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Only one photo per answer.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo was taken.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin August 1, 2020, 0:00 UTC, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/11329). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

---

## Results

Dirty-flow wins the bragging rights for having the highest-voted photo, of Aescher in Switzerland. Kuba wins the virtual prize, of their photo of the Tehran skyline with the mountains visible in the background.

Comment: IMO a [**Munro**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munro) would be a better definition of what qualifies (3000 feet) as a mountain than a dictionary, although specific to Scotland. Or for those who have moved on from 19th century measurements, perhaps 1000m is a nice round number.

Comment: 1000 meter. And that leaves England without mountains. (Big grin.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]
Mountains over Tehran, Iran

April 2016

Comment: Wow, totally not how I had ever pictured Tehran!  I guess I always thought it was in the desert.  Today I learned something new  thanks!

Comment: Ah, I was there like 3 months later. Beautiful country

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I've decided to award your photo the virtual prize. Congratulations!

Comment: Nice, thanks @gparyani!

Answer (score 16):

Aescher - mountain inn and restaurant with a stunning view, located in Switzerland.

*photo taken today - Aug 5 2020*

[image: Aescher]

Comment: Congratulations! Your photo was the highest-voted at the end of the month.

Answer (score 11):

[Mount Ngauruhoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Ngauruhoe) in winter, seen from the slopes of [Mount Ruapehu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Ruapehu).

[image]

I took this in 2013 while on a skiing weekend on New Zealand's largest volcano. Both Ruapehu and Ngauruhoe are active volcanoes, which can be exciting when the [lahar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lahar) alarms go off.

The strangest thing about skiing here is the scenery. I learned to ski in the French Alps where mountains stretch as far as the eye can see. These two mountains are two isolated snow-covered peaks set in the midst of flat, lush green countryside!

Comment: Thank you for the reminder of home ☺

Answer (score 9):

[image: Denali mountains]

Mountains at Denali National Park in Alaska.

Taken in June 2018, on my smartphone. (I hadn't gotten into film yet at the time.)

Answer (score 9):

[image: O]

One of my favourite photos, taken at Yosemite National Park - with Half Dome and El Capitan visible.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Volcán Barú]
Do shadows of mountains count?

This is the view from Volcán Barú in Panama, with the shadow of the mountain reaching the Pacific Ocean at dawn. It was a beautiful morning, and looking to the other side you could see the Atlantic Ocean (but without such an impressive shadow of course).

May 2016

Answer (score 7):

[image]

This is [Machapuchare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machapuchare) (माछापुच्छ्रे) in the Nepali Himalaya. The mountain, which was named for its fishtail shape, is considered sacred and has never been fully climbed. I took this photo on March 12 of this year, just before Nepal closed its borders to foreigners to prevent the spread of covid-19. I don't know when we'll be able to travel again, but I hope to be able to visit somewhere almost as striking!

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Otay Mountain (near San Diego in the USA) on the left, Cerro Colorado (in Tijuana, Mexico) on the right.  The border runs across the lower part of Otay Mountain.

Photo taken from Cañón del Sainz in Tijuana, Mexico, on January 3, 2019.

Comment: I think I've seen these mountains onboard airplanes when they were making approach into San Diego airport.

Comment: @gparyani Quite possible.  The typical flight path into SAN seems to be just north of Otay, so you'd possibly it from the left side of the airplanes.  Cerro Colorado would be several miles further south so you might see it too but it may get lost with all the others around Tijuana.  Flights into TIJ would fly between the two

Answer (score 5):

[image]

This is the observatory on [Pilatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilatus_(mountain)), just outside of Luzern, Switzerland. This is a very easy mountain summit to reach, as you can take a gondola to the top (and buy an expensive Swiss watch while you're up there if you're so inclined), but still, at over 2100 meters high, this is not a mountain to be underestimated!

I took this photo on August 23, 2018.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

This is [Chacaltaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chacaltaya), at an altitude of over 5000 meters in the Bolivian Andes, a short drive from the capital city of La Paz. Although it's only 16° South of the Equator, the high altitude means a ski resort was built on this mountain in the 1930s. Skiing continued into the early 21st century, but, because of climate change, the glacier is, as you can see, now gone and the area is now suitable only for hiking — a pretty hike, even if the high altitude makes it quite tiring.

I took this photo on February 5, 2019.

Answer (score 5):

This is taken at dawn in the Nelson Lakes National Park, New Zealand, from the Robert Ridge route, on the way back to St-Arnaud from the Angelus Hut (in February 2019).

[image: Robert Ridge, Nelson Lakes National Park]

The [Robert Ridge route](https://www.doc.govt.nz/parks-and-recreation/places-to-go/nelson-tasman/places/nelson-lakes-national-park/things-to-do/tracks/angelus-hut-tracks-and-routes/#pinchgut) is a day hike to reach Angelus hut and its beautiful surroundings. It is located in the Nelson Lakes National Park, on the South island of New Zealand.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Walking up the Hooker Valley, with Mt Cook ahead, near Lake Pukaki, South Island of New Zealand.

Comment: And thank you too for another reminder of home  I miss NZ at times

Answer (score 4):

This photo resembling the Dr.Mann's planet from Interstellar was taken at Dzongri in Sikkim, India. This is a short detour(1 or 2 hours) from the Goecha La pass trek on day 2.

Altitude: 13600 ft

Taken: 23rd April 2015

[image: Dzongri]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Sunrise in the [Aosta Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aosta_Valley), July 7th 2012 at 4:57 in the morning. It's taken on the mountain ridge between Val d'Ayas and Val di Gressoney, on the [Testa Grigia](https://goo.gl/maps/gUPjV1C5QSV2FGq26) (we slept that night at [Bivacco Lateltin](https://goo.gl/maps/4mqsBchWV1uWQjuc9)). [This Google Maps 3D view](https://www.google.nl/maps/@45.8166342,7.7717634,1026a,35y,45.25h,77.58t/data=!3m1!1e3) (for me, it only works in Chrome) shows where we stood and which mountain we were looking upon, the [Pyramide Vincent](https://goo.gl/maps/DPavT2yyuA3qTbvG7), part of the Monte Rosa massif.

Answer (score 3):

[image: View of the mountains from Lindau. Taken on 25.07.2020.]
View of the mountains from Lindau. Taken on 25.07.2020.

Answer (score 3):

Mount Teide, Tenerife, Canary Islands (Spain), taken by me in January 2012.

[image]

The highest mountain in all of Spain – even the Pyrenees – is free from snow at this moment. Only the very top of the mountain is shown, with the land falling away sharply to the tree line which is above the cloud layer, and the north coast of Tenerife is unseen far below.

On the right horizon is La Palma island, a half moon is above the peak, and cable car pylons on its left.

Answer (score 2):

Taken on the M41 highway in Tajikistan.  I love this view as the left of the (mine-laden) river is Tajikistan, and the right side is Afghanistan.  Spent two days travelling along this very militarised road from Dushanbe to Khorog, [before needing to evac back to Dushanbe for medicine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/983/101).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Northern Peru, mountains near Huaraz, close to Laguna Willcacocha.

March 2019

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Cerro San Isidro, between Tijuana and Tecate, Mexico.

Photo taken on May 27, 2020.

The foreground in this photo (and in the other Tijuana photo I posted) means more to me than the mountains.  These houses can look so awful from a distance, but the people who live in them are so proud they have their own place, a home that they've built and provided for their family.  They sweep and clean out their yards and keep them far tidier than I ever bother with my own place, and inside each house is so clean and tidy and you forget what the "shack" might look like from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

Grossglockner - the highest mountain in Austria, and the Pasterze Glacier - the longest glacier in Austria.

Photo taken on Jun 10 2018 from the Grossglockner High Alpine Road.

[image: Grossglockner]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Mauao, or "The Mount" or Mount Maunganui (which is really the name of the town at the base), in Tauranga, New Zealand.

Photo taken on April 4, 2019, while we were back in NZ for a visit.

Comment: I'll be back there in 3 weeks :D

Comment: I've sailed Hobie Cats off that beach. I'm not sure this really fits the description 'mountain', though.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Well people climb it to see the view from the top, and it fits part of the definition above "natural elevation of the earth's surface rising more or less abruptly to a summit" but doesn't make it in the "attaining an altitude greater than that of a hill, usually greater than 2000 feet" category LOL, but "usually" is vague.  It's virtually a mountain :D  Maybe it could be considered for the virtual prize

Answer (score 1):

Aerial view of a mountain range somewhere over Romania. Photo taken in December of 2019 on a flight from Brussels to Doha:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Far in the distance one can see the Atlas Mountains in Morocco. Taken on 01.02.2019 from the Menara Gardens.]

Far in the distance one can see the Atlas Mountains in Morocco. Taken on 01.02.2019 from the Menara Gardens.

Answer (score 1):

Stelvio Alpine Pass in Italy. It has snowed 2 days ago and the pass was closed until today.

*photo taken today - Aug 5 2020*

[image: Stelvio]

Answer (score 1):

Workers repairing the path to the top of [Doi Pui Ko](https://www.chiangmainews.co.th/page/archives/838115/), Thailand. Picture taken in November of 2018.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mount Ruapehu, New Zealand.  Photo taken on August 7, 2016.

We had taken a road trip to Wellington (from our then-home in Tauranga) to visit the Embassy of Mexico to get our residency visas, and on the drive home a couple of days later there had been a decent snow dumping on the Desert Road (the main highway through the central North Island) and so we were diverted around the back of the mountains and greeted with some stunning views!  My kids first (and only) experience in snow, and only my second.  We threw some snowballs on the side of the road

[image]

Also got great photos of [Mt Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Doom#Adaptations) (I mean, Mount Ngāuruhoe) and Mount Tongariro.  The mountains are active volcanoes, with eruptions as recently as 2012.

Thanks to @gparyani for [special permission](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55191715#55191715) to post an additional entry

Comment: My photos of [Ngauruhoe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPNRa.jpg) and [Tongariro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crmjG.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Traveling from Olot to Estany de Banyoles, both north of Barcelona in Catalonia, Spain, looking north I saw these mountains. I was not sure at the time and can not find the name (or exact location) now. (Happy to hear which mountain it is.)

[image: Mountains in the distance, one (likely) covered in snow.]

Photo taken 21-March-2013, by me.