# November 2020 Photo Competition - Nature/Wildlife

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I will be hosting this month's photo competition. The theme chosen for this month is *nature and wildlife*! This theme was suggested [in this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5049/105447) by Mark Mayo.

The photo can relate to any part of nature. For example, it could just be a field in the countryside, or a plant in a busy park. The theme is quite open to allow for a bigger variety of photos.

Rules adapted from Willeke's competition:

- **Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st November (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted**
- Please include a description of what your photographing, for example the name of a plant or animal or the name of a place (if known) and where and when the photo was taken
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named
- One photo per post, three posts max per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted, you have two more chances
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission (or blur their faces)
- No offensive photos
- **No downvotes**, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree
- **Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 30th November (UTC Time)** when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue

If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here). Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or add it to [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5049/105447).

---

**The winner is [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) with [his entry](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6773/105447)**

Comment: I mentioned the topic in the chat, but actually @MarkMayo suggested it in the question with the possible topic

Comment: @Dirty-flow Thanks, I updated the post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NIKON CORPORATION NIKON D80
ƒ/5.61/250135 mmISO400
Friday, 3 September 2010
```

Elephant Seal, near Valdez Peninsula, Argentina.

[image]

Comment: I think this is my favourite, but I really like all three of your entries :)

Comment: Hey. I thought this was a self portrait. Strange. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO goodness no, my nose is much worse ;)

Comment: This post has the most votes at the end of the month.

Answer (score 9):

[image: penguins]

If you're lucky enough to have the opportunity to visit Antarctica, you hope to see some penguins. But, still, I was not prepared to see tens of thousands of them on our very first landing! These [chinstrap penguins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinstrap_penguin) live near Baily Head on [Deception Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deception_Island), where I met them and took this photo on February 23, 2019.

Answer (score 9):

```
Huawei Nexus 6P
ƒ/21/10514.67 mmISO60
11 Nov 2018.
```

Echidna, near North Head, Sydney, Australia.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Karersee, South Tyrol, October 26th 2018

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image: A squirrel stood on its hind legs, staring at the camera with an apparent expression of surprise]

I took this in September 2018, in a small green area behind the Landungsbrücken station near the centre of Hamburg.

I stopped off on my way elsewhere because I knew the area had squirrels and it seemed like it might be a good opportunity to test out the new lens I'd recently bought. I was walking along the path, tracking a different squirrel up in the trees, when suddenly I came around a curve and this cute little thing was right there. I'm not sure which of us was more surprised.

I don't think this is necessarily one of the *best* photos I've ever taken, but the squirrel's dramatic pose (I can almost imagine it's clutching its chest in shock) makes it one of my favourites.

Comment: Proposed as a virtual price photo by gparyani in the chat and I agree, very good photo for the virtual price.

Answer (score 7):

The river Isar in the Karwendel mountain range, Austria, November 3rd 2018

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

A 'flush', when thousands of birds all take off together, usually to escape a predator. This was in Witless Bay Ecological Reserve, Newfoundland, 2016.

Answer (score 5):

Flamingos in southern Bolivia, just by the border with Chile.

Taken by me in March 2019

[image: flamingos]

Comment: Was this at the Laguna Colorada? I was there March this year, it's mre beautiful than the pictures can capture.

Comment: @Bernhard yeah, it's either the Colorada or one of the nearby lakes, I'm not 100% sure now. I only went there because it's close to Salar de Uyuni, but it ended up being more impressive than the salt flats!

Comment: I did a trip from San Pedro de Atacama to Uyuni and it was one of the most impressive things ever!

Answer (score 4):

[image: large blocks of ice floating in a lagoon, under an early evening sky]

Jökulsárlón is a lagoon located directly at the bottom of a glacier in south-east Iceland. Large chunks of ice break off the glacier and slowly float around the lagoon until they melt. There are boat tours around the lagoon, this was taken from one of them.

My wife and I were hitchhiking for a few days during our honeymoon. This day was the hardest - we waited almost three hours for a ride when setting off in the early afternoon, and nearly missed our chance to take the tour. Thankfully we got there just in time to take the last trip of the day, it's an incredible place.

Answer (score 4):

Goofy monkey (macaque?) in Salvador, Brazil :)

Taken by me in May 2018
[image: monkey]

Answer (score 4):

Waldgeister (forest ghosts) near Bingen, Germany.

Juny 12, 2020

[image: forest ghosts]

Answer (score 3):

**Red squirrel**

[image]

Taken by me in August 2013 at Glen Trool, Dumfries and Galloway, Scotland.

Answer (score 3):

```
SONY DSC-V3
ƒ/41/50028 mmISO100
29 March, 2005
```

Rock Dassie, taken on Table Mountain, Cape Town, South Africa

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Path in Odenwald, Germany. Thanks to COVID-19 we were hiking a lot this year.

May 10, 2020

[image: Odenwald]

Answer (score 3):

White-tailed Deer.

Photo taken in Michigan, November 20, 2020

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: danger].

I love the contrast and harmony between nature and human-made works of art that you can see at the [Storm King Art Center](https://stormking.org/) in the Hudson Valley north of New York City. Sometimes, the art makes this contrast explicit, as with *We Are The Asteroid* by [Justin Brice Guariglia](https://www.guariglia.com/indicators-2018), seen here in front of some colorful fall foliage, in a photo I took on October 28, 2018.

Answer (score 2):

```
Samsung S7 Edge
ƒ/1.7 1/878 4.2mm ISO40
July 2017
```

Buffalo's on the road in [Phu Luang Wildlife Sanctuary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phu_Luang_Wildlife_Sanctuary), Loei, Thailand.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: a coastal scene with trees up to the water's edge, taken in late afternoon]

This image was taken in October 2010 in an undeveloped area outside Kronstadt, Russia (a town on a small island near St. Petersburg).

My wife and I had taken a trip from St. Petersburg to Kronstadt to visit the remains of an abandoned military fort (the area is now a nature reserve). Afterwards we decided to take a walk further along the coast. We barely saw any sign of other people, and the colours as the sun began to set were incredible.

This was my first trip to Russia, and completely shattered so many stereotypes.

Answer (score 2):

Soraga di Fassa, Italy, October 27th 2018

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seealpsee in Switzerland.

Aug 5, 2020

[image: Seealpsee]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Two trees, one without and one with leafs.]
Photo taken 2 May 2017, while walking on [Exmoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exmoor) UK with a friend.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Bird sitting on in a tree.]
Staying with friends in Devon, UK (near South Molton) I saw this bird out of my bedroom, in their garden.
Photo taken 2 May 2017.

Someone identified it, from this picture, as a Sparrowhawk.