# January 2021 Photo Competition: Best of Travel 2020

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the January photo competition is "Best of Travel 2020". The photo must be taken in 2020 and be somehow travel related. Travel in 2020 was not easy due to COVID-19. If your photo is COVID-related, that will give you extra points for the virtual prize.

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Only one photo per answer.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo was taken.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo competition will begin January 1, 2021, 0:00 UTC, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/11329). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Road sign informing drivers of pre-Covid19 social distancing on Belgian motorways:

[image]

Picture taken in August of 2020.

Comment: Congrats, you win the virtual prize for this month :)

Answer (score 12):

I may have posted this picture before in the waterfall contest, but this was one of my favorites spots at the Brazilian side of the Iguazu Falls. I took picture in February this year.

[image: Iguazu Falls]

Comment: Lovely rainbow!

Comment: @JonathanReez Two of them!

Comment: we have a draw. You are one of the winners! Congrats!

Comment: @Dirty-flow Yeah! Woohoo!

Answer (score 12):

Trzy Korony, Pieniny

This peak is normally full of people. Fortunately for us that day the fog was really thick and the weather in all the valleys was gloomy, so the trail was empty and we could see this stunning view from the top.

Taken in November 2020
[image: Trzy Korony, Pieniny]

Comment: we have a draw. You are one of the winners! Congrats!

Answer (score 9):

[image]
Do long walks along abandoned railroads count as travel?
Springfield, Oregon; January 2020

Answer (score 8):

Sunrise over Salzburg. July 2020.

[image]

Comment: That is an amazing shot. I guess it was not a lucky coincidence with the position of the sun relative to the cathedral?

Comment: @Bernhard no, I had to choose my position for that to happen :)

Answer (score 6):

Due to the pandemic I explored the area closer to my home. This picture (unedited, only HDR during recording), is one that I shot in November 2020 from my phone. This is in the Netherlands (near Rotterdam)

[image: Holland]

Answer (score 6):

My wife, sitting on Plansee in Austria.

It was the first day of our roudtrip in the Alps and the Plansee was really amazing.

*Aug 2 2020*

[image: Plansee]

Answer (score 6):

Lake Rotoiti, South Island, New Zealand

```
18.6 MP8064 × 23046.1 MB
```

Taken in December, 2020

[image]

Comment: When people say you should travel in your own country. And then you're a Kiwi.

Comment: @Bernhard it is handy :D

Answer (score 6):

[image: aquaduct seen from the platform of a rail station]

Taken 1-1-2020, when travel was still normal and allowed.

I was on the train station Campolide in Lisbon, Portugal, looking along the platform towards [an aquaduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81guas_Livres_Aqueduct).
I had to take a photo.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Took this photo on **25th Dec, 2020** on the way to **Mysore**, **India** from my hometown. This was when we stopped on the way to have our breakfast, which we had packed from home :)

Answer (score 5):

Slightly rhetorical welcome message on the Dutch-Belgian border. The message translates to:

> Are you coming from an orange travel zone?
>
> Urgent advice:
>
> 10 days in quarantine

Of course the message was put there knowing that Belgium was at the time, in August of 2020 when the picture was taken, an orange travel zone. ;)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Highway]

California State Route 56, a major highway in northern San Diego, connecting Interstate 15 inland with Interstate 5 near the coast. Normally, at this time, this highway is rammed with traffic from people commuting from work in Sorrento Valley, but is almost completely empty thanks to COVID.

Taken April 22, 2020 on Kodak Pro Image 100 film.

Answer (score 4):

On our roadtrip I have driven over 15 Alp passes and the Grimsel pass in Switzerland was one of my favourite next to Sustenpass and Hahntenjoch.

The roads and the views were really amazing.

*Aug 7 2020*

[image: Grimsel pass]

Answer (score 4):

Cool that we have not one but three shots, so I can add this second one from the same place and day as my previous answer. I like this one even more!

Xwejni salt pans in Żebbuġ (Gozo island, Malta) on the 13th of August 2020.

I shot this nofilter photo with my Samsung A50 phone and never posted it on [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/followmeontour/) or anywhere else before today. Not related to COVID19.

These three colors captured my heart.

[image: gozo2]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Liberty Island]

Usually you don't look at even the most famous things in the world when they're in your own neighborhood. But I can walk to the ferry to [Governors Island](https://www.govisland.com/) and sit outside for the short trip across, and once you're on the other side, you can get some world-class views.

This was on July 30, 2020.

Answer (score 4):

Split Apple Rock, Kaiteriteri, New Zealand

```
HUAWEI HMA-L29
ƒ/2.41/28093.95 mmISO50
```

Taken in December, 2020

[image]

Answer (score 3):

***Three shades of Gozo***

Xwejni salt pans in Żebbuġ (Gozo island, Malta) in this no-filter picture I took on the 13th of August of 2020 with my Samsung A50 phone.

[image: gozo]

Non COVID-related, originally posted on [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/CGYN34jHyAx/).

I managed to visit in between the two waves of the pandemy and hope to fly back there as soon as possible!

Happy 2021 everyone!! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

[image: Sailboats]

Parked sailboats at the San Diego harbor. With COVID in full force, these boats aren't going anywhere.

Taken December 6, 2020 on Kodak Ektachrome E100 film. Scanned from a mounted slide.

Answer (score 3):

The Zemen Monastary in Bulgaria.

This church was build in the 11th century and it‘s one of the oldest one in Bulgaria.

*Oct 30 2020*

[image: The Zemen Monastary]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Dike covered in grass, dunes to one side, lake to the other.]
This photo was taken on the Hondsbossezeewering, [(Wikipedia page in Dutch,)](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hondsbossche_Zeewering) looking north, 16 September 2020, and I walked as far as you can see on this photo.
That was a three day walk/hike from home, on the first night I took the train home and out the second morning, on the second night I slept in a hotel, only the second night in a hotel since the start of COVID 19. Not the shortest way to this location, but only about 40 km from home is the farthest I have been since January 2020.

This has for a very long time been the only bit of the West coast of the Netherlands that relied on a dike as protection against the sea. Only in the last couple of years the dike has gotten protection from dunes on the seaward side. Left in this photo. While on the right, between the main dike and a lower secondary dike, a small lake has been developed to give birds a place to nest and raise young.

Answer (score 3):

Tui in foreground, with Maruia Falls in background, near Murchison, New Zealand.

The waterfall was created by an earthquake in 1929.

```
HUAWEI HMA-L29
ƒ/1.81/20534.75 mmISO50
```

Taken in December, 2020

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I saw this exercise bike, likely dumped in nature, at a corner of a bike lane and a dead-ended road. It felt as if we had as much freedom of movement as riding this bike would give us.
The road signs you see near it are for bike routes, about the only exercise most people got. But use of this bike would not even give that.

[image: Exersize bike in a grass verge with some parked trucks behind it]

Photo taken 21 October 2020, Beverwijk, the Netherlands.
Photo cut down from a bigger shot and adjusted to get the shape more natural.

Answer (score 2):

**Doubly in the bubbly**
Boating is off due to the river being in flood – and also under Covid-19 restrictions.
The small chalk board on the boating stand says:

> **Due to C19**
> Self drive river trips
> 'FAMILY BUBBLE' only

But even that is out of date – under UK tier 4 rules leisure venues are now closed.

[image]

Taken by me on Christmas Day in Cambridgeshire, UK.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Elk in Oregon, September 2020.

Answer (score 2):

Airport activity in Anchorage Alaska, March 4, 2020

[image: The Airport in Anchorage, Alaska]

Answer (score 1):

Locks on a bridge in Salzburg. July 2020.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inside the infamous [CHAZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitol_Hill_Autonomous_Zone), Seattle. June 2020.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]
If we left in a hurry, can we say we blew a gasquet?
September 2020 (though I’m sure the sign has been there for years)

Answer (score 1):

Abandoned car on the Kaena Point State Park trail.  This was taken March 9th and was the end of the line for me and this abandoned car.  No more travel for the rest of 2020.  Stuck in Hawaii... :)

[image: Abandoned car on Kaena Point trail in Oahu, Hawaii]