# March 2021 Photo Competition: "Decorated walls"

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the March photo competition is "Decorated walls" (proposed by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)). This covers any flat or curved wall, indoor or outdoor, that has been decorated (made to look artistic, whether in its original form or through subsequent modification). Examples include painted murals, graffiti, and mosaics.

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Only one photo per answer.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo was taken.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin March 1, 2021, 0:00 UTC, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/11329). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

---

### Results

mlc received the highest number of votes, with their photo of [a wall in Switzerland "decorated" with road signs](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6921/11329).

[MattAllegro's photo](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6914/11329) of a wall with a face painted on it and lit from the bottom wins the virtual prize, per a [suggestion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57517138#57517138) from Willeke, the topic proposer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the 18th and 19th of July last year I was in [Prato (Tuscany)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prato), equipped with my Samsung A50 phone. In the night I caught this streetart, impressive to me, in [Piazza Santa Maria in Castello](https://goo.gl/maps/SHvLgYD22U9Yk2Lv6). This shot was taken from the restroom window at the venue called [Casotto Atipico](https://goo.gl/maps/rjHXG7uyk1bgYRu88). Enjoy!!

[image]

Comment: @Willeke love the support!! Thank you :)

Comment: Congratulations! Your photo wins the virtual prize for this month.

Comment: @gparyani 100% amateur shot but cool in the end ;) Seriously, I'm so glad it was appreciated!!

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Good luck figuring out where to go from here.

This is at the [Verkehrshaus der Schweiz](https://www.verkehrshaus.ch/en/home.html) (Swiss Transport Museum) in Luzern, Switzerland, on January 4, 2009.

Comment: This photo had the most votes at the end of the month.

Answer (score 11):

[image: wall with the picture of a wall on it]
Photo taken on 10-10-2014, in Toronto, Canada.

This month is a difficult one, too many photos to chose between but this one stood out to me, weather, colours, the memory of an unexpected sight when I came round a corner.

Answer (score 10):

April 2016

Isfahan, Iran

[image: Isfahan]

Comment: Wow, my Iran photo - I was debating between the US Embassy or my photo from this very place in Isfahan :)

Comment: @MarkMayo haha that's funny, I had the same dilemma (I also have several photos of that embassy wall), but you posted it first. Lucky for us, Iran has plenty of really photogenic places :)

Answer (score 8):

[image: Intricate and colourfully decorated walls and ceiling]

This image shows the intricate, colourful decorations of the walls (and ceiling) of the [Church of the Saviour on Blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_the_Savior_on_Blood) in St. Petersburg, Russia. This isn't just one section, the entire interior is decorated in the same way. It's entirely unlike any other church or cathedral I've visited.

I took this photo on my first trip to Russia, in late 2018.

Answer (score 7):

22 July 2015

The abandoned US Embassy, in Tehran, Iran.

ƒ/2 1/375 3.82 mm ISO100

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I play my card number 3 `;)`

This is a four-story abandoned building in [White Rocks](https://goo.gl/maps/RCcupbd4saL7pMhm9) (Pembroke, Malta).

This ghost town was originally housing the families of the British military forces in the 1960s, then became a student accomodation in 1995, finally it was abandoned few years later.

I visited this place several times and it would deserve dozens pictures. This was on 10/03/2019 and the camera Huawei ANE-LX1.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Asam Church, Munich.

Juli 2019.

Answer (score 6):

[image: coloured cat painted on a wall]
Photo taken 19 July 2017, in Flensburg Germany.
This cat is maybe a bit bigger than real life but not a lot, it was one street up from the Schifffahrtsmuseum Flensburg, a bit farther into the center of the city, in a small side street.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Throne room of Rosenborg Castle, in Copenhagen, Denmark.

August 2019.

Answer (score 5):

Wall at La Bodeguita Del Medio - Varadero, Cuba.

Taken 25 June 2015.

ƒ/2 1/33 3.82 mm ISO147

It's produced as a copy of the famous dive bar in Havana that Ernest Hemingway used to frequent.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Valparaíso, Chile, February 14, 2019.

Comment: drone shot or on a hill?

Comment: @MarkMayo Valparaíso is a very hilly city; this is just shot from higher up, no drone, but we did use [an elevator](https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/elevators-of-valparaiso) to get up there.

Comment: (Facepalm) I rode that elevator in 2010 and completely forgot. Sigh :)

Answer (score 5):

[image: wall mural mosaic]
Photo taken 27 September 2014, in Reykjavic, Iceland.

This mural is build up out of what looks like natural stone and maybe tile pieces. In sunlight it is even more amazing but with the size and the location it was not easy to get the whole on the photo.
(License plates doctored, not to show numbers.)

Answer (score 4):

Mildly political mural in La Paz, Bolivia

Taken 8 October 2010

ƒ/4.5 1/125 25.9mm ISO80

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It may not be very obvious, but it's a greengrocer

May 2019

Boquete, Panama

[image: Boquete]

Answer (score 4):

Picture taken on 2021-03-01 in Waianae, Hawaii.

[image: West Side Oahu Pillbox Murals]

This photo was taken inside an abandoned pillbox structure built in the 1940s during WW2.  These concrete boxes were built to direct defensive fire against invading enemy ships and a land invasion that never happened.  This one looks down along the Waianae coast of Oahu.

While its colorful and clean I suspect the interior decoration is not consistent with the original army style guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

Taken at Sheffield Tasmania, Australia in January 2019. Picking one is a challenge, as the town is full of murals. This one fits as a decorated wall.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A bit simpler than the others, but interesting nonetheless.

This was painted by music artist Daniel Johnston to promote his [new music album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hi,_How_Are_You). It's become an icon for mental health awareness as he was struggling through mental health issues at the time.

Originally, this was on the side of a Thai restaurant, which subsequently changed its name to honor the mural. Sadly, that restaurant [closed in January 2020](https://austin.eater.com/2020/1/3/21048195/thai-how-are-you-restaurant-closed-daniel-johnston-mural-hi-how-are-you-mr-gattis-closed-guadalupe).

[image: "Hi, how are you"]

Taken in early 2019 on Fujifilm Superia 400 film, in Austin, Texas, USA.

Comment: I cannot see this picture at work. For some reason i.stack.imgur.com works, but i.imgur.com does not.

Answer (score 3):

#### Where the neon lights are pretty

Subject is the [King Power Mahanakhon skyscraper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Power_Mahanakhon). Taken 25th of March 2021 from the Silom Road in Bangkok. If you look closely you'll see that the horizontal lights are in-between floors. They actually play a subtle light show in the evening but it's hard to capture that in a still image.

f/4.0 8.0s iso100 12.96mm

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This one is in the corner between [Desker Rd and Serangoon Rd](https://goo.gl/maps/fGHe9PeGBAQP9qJ97) in [Little india (Singapore)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_India,_Singapore). I passed by on the 8th of November 2018 after a great lunch and I took the picture with a Samsung J5 phone.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pope Francis riding a llama

April 2019

Buenos Aires (La Boca), Argentina

[image: The Pope riding a llama]

Answer (score 2):

[image: revolution graffiti wall]

¡Viva la revolución!

Havana, Cuba, May 7, 2006.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Jardin Majorelle, Marrakesch.

February 2019.