# April 2021 Photo Competition - Trees

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I will be hosting this month's photo competition. The theme chosen for this month is *trees*! This theme was suggested [in this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5049/105447) by Bernhard.

A futher description of the topic was [provided by Willeke](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57389952#57389952):

> That can be one solo tree but also forest pictures or even 'not real trees' which attracted the attention of the person with the camera.

The following rules apply:

- Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st April (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted.
- Please include a description of what you're photographing, for example the type of tree (if known) and where the photo was taken.
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named.
- One photo per post, three posts maximum per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted.
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission to post the photo online (or blur their faces).
- No offensive / NSFW photos.
- No downvotes, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree.
- Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 30th April (UTC Time) when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue.

If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here). Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or add it to [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5049/105447).

---

- Congratulations to the winner - [jcklopp](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/110701/jcklopp)!
- Additional congratulations to [Mark Mayo](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) for [winning the virtual prize](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6964/105447)!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a nice example of a giant Monkey Pod tree.  This one is known locally as the "[Hitachi Tree](https://www.hitachi.com/hitachitree/en/profile/index.html)".  It is located within Moanalua Gardens on the Hawaiian island of Oahu.  It is about 130 years old, 25 meters tall and 40 meters wide.  Photo taken in January of 2020.

[image: Hitachi Tree]

Comment: Is this even physically possible? :)

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Oberwesel, Germany, October 2020.

Comment: Wow! So beautiful!!

Answer (score 8):

Spotted this little copse on the Stirling University campus when dropping off my daughter in October 2020 so took a photo with my OnePlus 7.

[image]

Apologies for not knowing the types of trees.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Heidelberg, Germany, May 2019.

Answer (score 6):

This is a picture of a tree in Hobbiton, that I took during my trip to New Zealand in 2017.
The tree is not real, it is artificially created for the movie. It is only in the movie for a couple of seconds. And I heard the story that Peter Jackson didn't like the color of the leaves, so the leaves got repainted.
[image: Hobbiton tree]

Comment: damn, should have posted my one from there, great thinking and good shot!

Answer (score 6):

[image: Japanese maple]

A Japanese maple tree in Toronto, Canada. November 2020.

Answer (score 5):

This is a common Oahu street tree on the leeward side of the island.  Known as a Golden Trumpet tree, the name makes sense for a few months of the year.  Photo taken in May of 2020.

[image: Golden Trumpet]

Answer (score 5):

Snowy trees on the Nürburgring Nordschleife, called the Green Hell.

Photo taken during a track walk in winter
*Jan 24, 2021*

[image: Nürburgring Nordschleife]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[The Lowline](http://thelowline.org/) is (was?) a plan to build an underground park in a disused subway platform in the Lower East Side of New York City. While the current status of [the project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowline_(park)) is unclear, they showed off some of their cool technology for lighting and keeping plants alive by using fiber optics to pipe in sunlight. I took this photo at their "tech demo" (aboveground but with all the windows completely blacked out to simulate being underground) in September, 2012.

Answer (score 4):

Palm number 2: from Oia, Santorini (Greece). I was there on the 20th of September 2019 and took the pic with Samsung A50 phone. This one I had already posted [here](https://www.instagram.com/p/B946M-xIfjI). Enjoy!!

[image: palm of Santorini]

Answer (score 4):

The ruins of the Transportation Camp, where some 70,000 French prisoners were transported from mainland France and then sent to prison camps along the Maroni basin. It used to be the biggest penal colony in French Guiana.

Saint-Laurent-du-Maroni, French Guiana

Taken in March 2019
[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: One tree in winter and summer.]
One tree in the fields between Calne, Wiltshire, UK, and Bowood house, which is to the west of the town.
Photos taken 26 December 2018 and 18 July 2019. (Sizes adjusted so they are close to the same visual size.)

Answer (score 4):

Obligatory 'That Wanaka Tree', taken in Wanaka, NZ, on Nov 2 at 2019. It is famous enough to have its own instagram page ;)

[image]

Comment: Congratulations on winning the virtual prize!

Answer (score 4):

[image: Palm at Villa Cimbrone]
Maintenance of a palm tree at Villa Cimbrone, Ravello, Italy. September 2014.

Comment: The famous _Italian Scaffolded Palm_!! ;) Fantastic

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Bacharach, Germany, October 2020.

Answer (score 3):

If the topic is "Trees", I figured it'd make sense to post something from The Amazon :)

I'm not sure what's the scientific name, but the locals call it the Elephant Tree, I guess it's pretty obvious why. It's located lose to Jamaraquá community, several hours by bus from Santarém, Pará in Northern Brazil.

Taken in November 2019
[image: The Elephant Tree]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Story goes that this [Ficus Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus) is over hundred years old!

I like the contrast between the "short and fatty" Ficus Tree (I'm no botanist, I can't tell which one of the 800 species it is) and the "tall and skinny" tree on the front (which looks like a [Queen Palm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syagrus_romanzoffiana)).

Photo taken on a Xiaomi cell phone in March 2020 in a small farm deep in southern Brazil.

Answer (score 2):

Flowery tree at the Khon Kaen Avani hotel in Thailand. Picture taken on the 2021 April fool's day. Taken by me using my SONY DSC-RX10M3 with settings ƒ/2.4 4s 8.8 mm ISO100.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Tree mid-haircut

Taken in Khon Kaen, Thailand on March 31st 2021. Picture taken by me using my SONY DSC-RX10M3
ƒ/3.5
1/1000
8.8 mm
ISO100.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Waimahara Wharf in Picton, NZ.  Taken Feb 2020.  This is shortly after exports to China had been halted.  The lumber was piling up with nowhere to go.

[image: Trees piled up in Pictin, NZ]

That's a lot of trees!

Answer (score 2):

Mainz, Germany

*Oct 11, 2019*

[image: Mainz]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The beautiful fall foliage is dominated by the artificial treeform of the power transmission tower. Who's winning, nature or humanity?

I took this from VIA Rail's *[Canadian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_(train))* service near Washago, ON, on October 18, 2016.

Answer (score 1):

I am definitely not the *Lord of Trees*, but I have some cool palm pictures `;)`

This one (actually two) I caught on the isle of Gozo, [on my way](https://maps.app.goo.gl/eAZGv2UuM5VUHGwWA) from Kerċem to Ta' Pinu Sanctuary. It was on the 8th of August last year and I shot the photo with my Samsung A50 phone.

[image: palm of Gozo, Malta]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Looking up through the bare branches of a tree.]
Photo taken 4 May 2013, Hyde Park London, UK.

I am not sure if I ever knew the kind of tree but after the years have gone by I certainly do not remember. I was looking through my older photos and noticed this one, it stood out.

Answer (score 1):

Trees on the beach Playa de Las Teresitas in Tenerife, Spain

*Sept 26, 2016*

[image: Playa de Las Teresitas]

Answer (score 1):

Third answer, third palm: this one is in [Albisola Superiore (Italy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albisola_Superiore). On its background, the almost brutalist architecture hosting the club house called [Società di Luceto](https://goo.gl/maps/8XDLZx9uLTrSQFwL8). I took this image on 13/10/2019 with my Samsung A50 phone and originally posted it at the end of [this compilation](https://www.instagram.com/p/B6YtTBEIzbb/).

[image: palm from Italy]

Answer (score 1):

[image: a textiles wrapped 'boabab tree']
Photo taken on 1 December 2012, while it was dark.
To me it looks like a man made 'boabab tree', but I can not guaranty there is no real tree inside.

It was (as you can see in the photo) around the time of The Winter Festival, in and around the Southbank Center, London, UK.