# June 2021 Photo Competition - Castles and similar structures

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I will be hosting this month's photo competition. The theme chosen for this month is *castles and similar structures*! This theme was suggested by [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow) in [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5051/105447) and then later [broadened by gparyani](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58149883#58149883) to include other similar structures.

A further description of the topic was provided by Dirty-flow in the post linked above:

> Castles are usually quite big and have many faces. The photos can be from inside and outside the castle.

Examples of other structures covered by this topic include:

- Forts
- Capitols
- Any other similar structures

---

The following rules apply:

- Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st June (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted.
- Please include a description of what you're photographing, for example, the name of the structure (if known) and the date the photo was taken.
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named.
- **Up to five photos per post**, two posts maximum per person. Usually, we do not like people to change their photos, but this month I think it is permissible to add to your post and adjust each photo (or replace them) within 24 hours of posting. But do not keep fiddling about with your posts, once you are happy with it, post a bit of text saying so and keep off it from then, so people who are waiting with voting know you are done.
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission to post the photo online (or blur their faces).
- No offensive / NSFW photos.
- No downvotes, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree.
- Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 on 30th June (UTC Time) when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw / tie voting will continue.

If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here). Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or add them to [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5049/105447).

---

**Update (1st July): The voting period is extended until 5th July 23:59:59 (UTC Time) as the entries by [undefined](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7013/11329) and [Dirty-flow](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7012/11329) are tied at a score of 8 each.**

---

**Update (6th July): The voting period has now finished. Congratulations to the winner [undefined](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7013/11329)! The virtual prize goes to [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7016/105447).**

Comment: Wow, have I won the virtual prize again!? :)

Comment: @MattAllegro Yes. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Burgruine Ehrenberg in Reutte, Austria.

31.10.2020

[image]

Comment: that looks really nice. I will be in Tirol this weekend and could go there :)

Comment: It is really nice. I strongly recommend spending a day hiking there.

Answer (score 9):

The following pictures are from Urquhart Castle. I visited this old remainder of the castle on the shore of Loch Ness in september 2012. I was very lucky with seeing a beautiful rainbow on top of the castle. It was even more impressive in real life. I've also added a picture from the inside of the castle.

[image: Urquhart Castle]
[image: Urquhart Castle]

Comment: You beat me to it! When I read "castle" in this month's photo competition I instantly thought of some pictures I have from Urqhart castle! For sure one of the most beautiful I've ever been to!

Answer (score 9):

Hohenzollern Castle in Germany

*September 8, 2018*

[image: hohenzollern 1]

[image: hohenzollern 2]

[image: hohenzollern 3]

Answer (score 8):

Château de Chambord, France, July 15th, 2018

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Caerlaverock Castle, Scotland

Huawei Nexus 6P - ƒ/21/47854.67 mmISO64

21 Sep 2018

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The photos below were taken of Gallops Goshen at the intersection of highway US 20 and 15 in northern Indiana.  It certainly looks like a castle but I suppose it will qualify under the term 'similar structures'.  Regardless, this is a fortified travel plaza like no other!

[image: Front of Castle Entrance]

[image: Armored knight standing guard inside the keep]

[image: Castle roadway signage]

Photos captured on May 26th, 2021.

Comment: 2.39 a gallon?  Damn I need to move out of California...

Answer (score 5):

Eltz Castle in Germany. Built in 12th century and never been destroyed

*June 3, 2018*

[image: Eltz Castle]

Answer (score 5):

Some castle near Bacharach, Germany.

24.10.2020

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stahleck_Castle

Answer (score 4):

[Rochester Castle,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rochester_Castle) Rochester UK, from the outside and inside, looking out as well.
From a distance it looks pretty much like a castle, but when in it you realize that the roof is gone and with it most of the inside floors and such.
Looking out you can not miss the Cathedral, which is just next door.
Photos taken 1 November 2013.

[image: Castle in the distance]

[image: Castle from the outside]

[image: Cathedral from the castle]

[image: Top of the tower, looking over and seeing down]

[image: Looking up to the tower inside the walls.]

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late to the party, anyway please get to know the Forte de Mil Regos in Ericeira, Portugal, built in 1670 to protect Ericeira's coastline with some cannons. Pictures were taken on 2008-04-15.

[image: Forte de Mil Regos]

[image: Forte de Mil Regos]

[image: Forte de Mil Regos]

[image: Forte de Mil Regos]

Answer (score 3):

The Kraków Barbican - a late 15th century fortified gateway to the old town of Krakow.

- NIKON CORPORATION NIKON D80
- ƒ/81/25020 mmISO500

12 May 2011

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Fort Grosso in Pula, Croatia.

07.04.2019

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [**third circle of city walls of Bologna, Italy**](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mura_di_Bologna#La_terza_cinta:_la_Circla), was built in XIV century and mostly demolished at the very beginning of XX century. Twelve city gates were originally standing, nowadays only ten survive, some of them restored or rebuilt in time.

Here is a selection of five of them, I took all the pictures in 2019-2021.

- [Porta San Vitale](https://goo.gl/maps/ki3p3bT7ZVwbWtf96):

[image: San Vitale]

---

- [Porta Maggiore (Porta Mazzini)](https://goo.gl/maps/QcJLNqS5NBodoaDi9):

[image: Maggiore]

---

- [Porta Castiglione](https://goo.gl/maps/eJvEapUbDAc94dny8):

[image: Castiglione]

---

- [Porta Mascarella](https://goo.gl/maps/ixzmqT3kuUGbsgPJ6):

[image: Mascarella]

---

- [Porta Galliera](https://goo.gl/maps/vv7trDy6PTFmcExq5) (rebuilt in XVII century):

[image: Galliera]

Answer (score 3):

Forte de Santo Antônio da Barra

Salvador, Brazil

May 2018

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Karim Khan Citadel

Shiraz, Iran

April 2016

[image: Karim Khan castle]

Answer (score 2):

[La Rochelle,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Rochelle)  Tour de la Chaîne and de Tour Saint-Nicolas, together with some walls and tour de la Lanterne which is hidden in scaffolding.
And looking down on the rebuild [Hermione](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_frigate_Hermione_(2014)) from one of the towers.

[image: Tour de la Chaine and Tour Saint Nicolas]

[image: Two towers and a bit of wall across water]

[image: Two towers and a bit of wall but different ones]

[image: Looking across from one tower to the next]

[image: Looking out from the tower onto the re-build Hermione]

All photos taken 5 March 2015, La Rochelle, France. By me.