# July 2021 Photo Competition: Ten-Year Anniversary

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

In honor of this site's [ten-year anniversary](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel), the theme for this competition is **any travel-related photo taken in summer 2011 or earlier**, preferably prior to the site's private beta beginning on June 21, 2011.

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Only one photo per answer.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo was taken.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time within the time frame above.
- The photo competition will begin July 1, 2021, at the time this was posted, and continue until the end of the month (in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/11329). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

---

### Results

[Willeke](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke)'s [submission](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7041/11329) of a sailing ship from August 2010 received the highest number of votes.

[Glorfindel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28333/glorfindel) wins the virtual prize for their [photo](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7040/11329) of a lion in South Africa from August 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lioness in [Kruger National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruger_National_Park), South Africa, August 2008. Served as my desktop background for many, many years. A wonderful experience, I did not visit a zoo for quite a while, until about four years ago with my then-five-year-old nephew. It's really amazing to see these animals in their 'home town'.

[image]

Comment: I have a very similar photo from the same park in 2005.  Anyone know how to identify individual lions? ;)

Comment: Congratulations! You win the virtual prize for this month.

Comment: @gparyani it's an honor, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

[image: Tallship with many more vessels.]
This is a photo of the Dar Młodzieży, [(more photos and a description in Dutch)](https://www.sail.nl/schepen/dar-mlodziezy/) [(Wikipedia page in English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dar_M%C5%82odzie%C5%BCy) during Sail-in, 19 August 2010 between IJmuiden and Amsterdam, somewhere on the 'Noordzeekanaal'.   That is the Netherlands.
In the photo you see the flag of the event, as flown from the Margeja, which was the boat I was a passenger on. Also in the picture a few of the other boats in the canal.

[In this newspaper page](https://www.destentor.nl/kampen/kampen-tussen-de-grote-jongens%7Eaaa2c3c0/) you can see an area view of the event, with an other ship central. The water is crazily busy and the city of Amsterdam gets overcrowded during the (free to visit) event.

Comment: Congratulations! Your photo wins the bragging rights for the highest-voted submission.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Occupy and resist. Good advice when I took this photo (July 24, 2007, Park Güell, Barcelona); still good advice today.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I grew up in the Northeastern US, not far from the Atlantic Ocean, but this visit to Essaouira, Morocco (August 3, 2009) may have been the first time I saw the sun *set* over the Atlantic.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[Saint-Pierre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Pierre_and_Miquelon), part of a small French territory off the coast of Newfoundland, is, well, far from everywhere. But if your idea of "everywhere" is other bits of France, and you want to know just how far "far" is, they've got you covered.

I took this photo on August 1, 2004, on the first digital camera I ever owned, the Olympus C-1, with a maximum resolution of about 1.2 megapixels.

Answer (score 5):

Because I have always been on planes, since about the age of 4, I have always loved airports. When Heathrow T5 opened in March 2008, I decided that instead of taking my wife directly from Edinburgh to Paris for her birthday, we should go via T5 so we could check out the terminal.

It only opened 3 weeks previously so they were still having major logistical issues, so while this panorama looks lovely, we did spend 8 hours longer in the airport than anticipated, and missed our dinner in Paris...

[image]

Comment: Solid birthday plans. :D

Answer (score 5):

Photo taken at a school trip when I was a senior in high-school back in **November 2008**. It's a sky's view from a random building yard in the city of **Warsaw, Poland**:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To get a bit nostalgic: KLM's now retired 747 Rio de Janeiro at Schiphol airport in 2007. [The plane retired](https://www.nhnieuws.nl/nieuws/216238/afgedankte-boeing-747-van-klm-geland-in-twente) 10 and a half years after the picture was taken. The plane was taken apart and sold for scraps, which included [aircraft skin tags](https://www.aviationtag.com/en/produkt/phbfr01/).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An orca whale performing at the Shamu show in SeaWorld San Diego.

[image: Killer whale performing]

The killer whale shows were discontinued in 2017 after pressure from animal rights groups and incidents with multiple trainers.

Taken June 7, 2004, on a Vivitar ViviCam 3705.

Answer (score 4):

Volgograd Train Station, Russia.  Taken June 22, 2011, the same day I joined Travel.SE.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A few days after visiting [Amsterdam](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7050/77011) in the Summer of 2011, I moved to the crush of my 20ies, **Vienna**, capital of Austria. This is [Schönbrunn palace and garden](https://www.schoenbrunn.at/en/), UNESCO heritage site, seen from the [Gloriette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nbrunn_Palace#Gloriette).

[image: Vienna Schoenbrunn 2011]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Skógafoss]

Skógafoss waterfall in Iceland. August 2007.

Comment: Although you get the feel of its size by the intensity of the water, I love how that person is there to emphasize its monstrosity

Answer (score 3):

Balloon over downtown Prague, October 19th 2008. It was registered under "OK-0010" and operated for tourists sometime until 2011. Tried to find out why it was shutdown but the details have been lost in time. All we have left now is some photos.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A dancing monkey at Khao Takiab, Hua Hin, Thailand. Picture taken in the summer of 2006.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: several boats on a jetty]
This is the 'harbour' of the [Viking Ship Museum, Roskilde Denmark.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_Ship_Museum_(Roskilde))
Photo taken 28 September 2010.

Here the vessels are waiting, in these days they explore the fjord the museum is build next to. In the far past boats like these and the bigger versions not in this photo did sail all the way to the British coast (and changed the nature of the peoples there.)

Later in the day we joined other visitors and rowed and sailed on the fjord.

A very nice museum and worth visiting if you are in the right part of Denmark. (And worth a longer travel if you are into your boats and viking history.)

Answer (score 2):

Most of my photos of Dubai and the Emirates look dusty and grey. This view of the Burj al Arab from where I was eating dinner on the roof of the Madinat Jumeirah in Novermber 2006 is one I like[image: The Burj from Madinat Jumeirah at night]

Answer (score 1):

Metadata say this picture was taken in May 2011, but I believe it was August 2011 instead. Needless to say, this is one channel of **Amsterdam**, in the Netherlands.

[image: Amsterdam 2011]

Answer (score 1):

Hiking the Gower (South Wales) coast in May 2010. This is Three Cliffs Bay.

[image: Three Cliffs]

Answer (score 0):

In my third answer I upload a photo that was one of my favourites for a long time. Again, **Amsterdam** 2011. It was taken in front of number 416 of the street called Ceintuurbaan, housing the tattoo studio [Schiffmacher and Veldhoen](https://goo.gl/maps/MLXe49ugJ3rUys3k7) by the legendary Henk Schiffmacher "Hanky ​​Panky".

I like the front of the shop with the logo on glass and the tagline in golden characters on dark blue background (*In God we trust, everybody else pays cash*). Then, on the back of the bus stop, a poster promoting an exposition by [Anton Corbijn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton_Corbijn), who is actually Dutch and that I knew because he created record covers and directed music videos for one of my cult bands, the [Depeche Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depeche_Mode#Black_Celebration_(1986)). The blurry guy on the right completes this totally naive portrait.

[image: Ceintuurbaan 416, Amsterdam 2011]

Comment: All of the three photos I posted this month were taken by me, with a 4 Mpx Kodak camera.