# August 2021 Photo Competition: Beaches

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the August photo competition is "Beaches" ([proposed by Tomerikoo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58738375#58738375)). This covers any photo of or near a large body of water (ocean or very large lake) that meets land at a shore filled with sand or rocks.

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Only one photo per answer.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo was taken.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin August 1, 2021, 0:00 UTC, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/11329). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

---

### Results

undefined wins the bragging rights for the highest-voted photo, of a rope bridge in Pula, Croatia.

JonathanReez wins the virtual prize for their photo in the Olympic National Park, mainly because I happened to experience close to that exact scene two weeks after that photo was submitted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Olympic National park, summer 2019

Comment: That looks sooo much like Long Beach near Tofino, Vancouver Island

Comment: Which country is this?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Taken in Pula, Croatia. Date is 07.04.2019.

Comment: Congratulations! Your photo wins the bragging rights for the highest-voted photo this month.

Answer (score 8):

[image: United Airlines 757-200 landing at SXM in 2007]

A United Airlines 757-200 landing at St. Maarten (SXM), as seen from Sunset Beach Bar near Maho Beach, 6 Jan 2007 (also [wider shot](https://photos.app.goo.gl/gjPDm1T2DrsgRRY29) from a little earlier). We departed on one of its sisters the next day.

There are of course many [more dramatic](https://www.gettyimages.com/photos/maho-beach) Maho Beach runway photos, often with KLM or Air France 747-400s, but if you're interested in live action, you're in luck; the Sunset Beach Bar has re-opened and their website now has a [webcam](http://sunsetsxm.com/plane-info/).

Answer (score 8):

[image: Wild horses walk out to the beach at Assateague Island National Seashore below a rainbow]

[Wild horses](https://www.nps.gov/asis/learn/nature/horses.htm) saunter towards a rainbow at Assateague Island National Seashore in Maryland, 29 Jun 2019. We camp there every year, but usually don't see the horses on the beach itself, and especially right after a thunderstorm.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

The [Playa de Los Pescadores](http://turismorocha.gub.uy/atractivos/playas/playa-de-los-pescadores) (Fishermen's Beach) in [Punta del Diablo](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=14/-34.0426/-53.5688), Uruguay. I took this photo to mark so many ends: the edge of the land, at sunset, on the last day of summer (March 19, 2019), on my last night in my last destination on an extended period of travel before returning home.

Answer (score 7):

Second of three, the choice gets harder and harder. **Thailand** again! Here we have a view of actually both **Ton Sai Beach** (on the left) and **Loh Dalum Beach** (fully sandy on the right) seen from one of the many [viewpoint](https://maps.app.goo.gl/f4mStZrQmirugt1r6)s of **Ko Phi Phi Don**. Full panoramic view [here](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bw-G5TGnebE).
I took this picture with a Samsung phone in late Oct. 2018.
[image: phi phi islands]

Answer (score 7):

Split Apple Beach, Appleby, Marlborough, New Zealand.

December 28, 2020.

```
HUAWEI HMA-L29
ƒ/1.81/40654.75 mmISO50
```

[image]

Comment: Great photo.  Is that a bottlebrush plant?

Comment: @jcklopp Pōhutukawa - a NZ native, often called the NZ Christmas tree as it tends to bloom around then.

Comment: I love seeing the photos of NZ!  Makes me a little homesick, but there's no chance of getting back there anytime soon

Comment: @jcklopp They look similar from a distance, but when you get closer to the flowers they are quite different

Answer (score 6):

[image: Picture]

Long-exposure photo of bioluminescense at the beach in La Jolla, near San Diego, CA.

Taken April 2020 on Kodak Portra 400 film pushed to 800, 30-second exposure.

Answer (score 5):

This is literally [*The Beaches*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beaches), Toronto, Canada. December 2017.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One of my top 3 beaches must be this one, at [**Freeway Bar (and bamboo tattoo)**](https://maps.app.goo.gl/i5XY9xy7Y5KG5qwKA) on the west side of **Ko Phangan, Thailand**. I visited and took this photo with Samsung phone in October 2018. This was originally the last of 8 I posted [here](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bo3-kvjCS54).

[image: ko phangan]

Answer (score 4):

Laguna Colorada, Bolivia

25 July 2010

```
NIKON CORPORATION NIKON D80
ƒ/111/50018 mmISO400
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This shot is from the infamous big wave spot Praia do Norte, in Nazaré, Portugal. I think it definitely qualifies for *near a large body of water* :)

I took this picture on December, 11th, 2014 on a Canon 6D, iso 400, f/14, with 1/500 sec. and 400mm lens

[image]

Comment: That's crazy! Do you know what length lens you were using?

Comment: @MarkMayo I have a Canon 100-400mm and definitely used the full length 400mm

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Taken in Konstanz, Germany. Date is 21.04.2019.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Picture]

The beaches of Malibu, CA as seen from a nearby hill.

Taken July 2021 on Kodak Ultramax 400 film. (As a cheap film, you can see the grain clearly. This was just the basic scan from the lab; I'll upload a higher-quality copy once I've self-scanned the negative.)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Cabo San Lucas, Jan 2020

Answer (score 3):

[image: Haeundae Beach in 2017]

Photo taken from off the coast of Busan, South Korea with a bird's perspective of Haeundae (해운대) Beach.  March, 2017.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Praia de Carneiros, Brazil

November 2017

Answer (score 3):

Playa Carrillo, Costa Rica. January 2014.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The seagull ruined (or made?) the shot.  Pool right above the beach at the southern end of Playas Rosarito, Baja California, Mexico.

Photo taken by either me or my wife (probably my wife since it's so arty) on an iphone, on Feb 22, 2021. [Google Maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/@32.3217522,-117.0550889,3875m/data=!3m1!1e3)

[image]

Comment: These kind of happy encounters always makes pictures better, in my view.

Answer (score 2):

Third shot: [**My Khe Beach**](https://maps.app.goo.gl/NkMPCXq1Fuo2JzKH6) in **Da Nang, Vietnam**, one of my favourites ever. I took this pic with a Samsung phone on 08/01/2019. Zoom to appreciate the fisherman!

[image: my khe beach, da nang, vietnam]

Answer (score 2):

Varadero, Cuba

25 June 2015

```
HTC HTC_0P6B
ƒ/21/19663.82 mmISO100
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Lake Louise, Alberta, Canada. September 2019.

Answer (score 2):

The beach of Puerto Lopez, Ecuador with its many boats. Taken on July 2014, right before a whale watching cruise. Nice experience!

[image]

This other image doesn't seem fit as its own submission but I just like it so much and must share it. So this is a bonus for your viewing pleasure, not for voting: [Just a happy dead fish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VlT4.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The view from [Wat Khao Chong Krachok](https://www.tourismthailand.org/Attraction/khao-chong-krachok) in Prachuap Khiri Khan, Thailand. Taken in in August 2014 with an Oppo Find7 phone (f/2 , 1/1711 shutter time at 3.79mm with ISO 101, odd values, I know).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Picture]

Downtown San Diego as seen from Coronado Island.

Taken April 2021 on Kodak Ektachrome E100 slide film.

Answer (score 1):

This shot is covering a fishermen trying to catch octopus, just with a stick with a hook (and some crab covering the hook) at the Ribeira d'Ilhas beach in Ericeira, Portugal during a very low tide. To catch those waves in the back you'd need to pass all that reef.

This shot I took on October 23rd, 2010 with a Canon EOS 400 (Rebel), with the standard 18/55mm lens that came with it and a cheap fish-eye adapter (not a fish-eye lens) placed on top of it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Playa La Misión, Baja California, Mexico.  During the summer this beach barely has room to move, but in winter plus middle of Covid we saw very few on the beach.  We're here every second Wednesday, while our kids are busy just up the road (although for some reason we were here on a Monday when this photo was taken, probably due to Christmas)

Photo taken by either me or my wife, on an iphone, on Dec 21, 2020.  [Google maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/La+Misi%C3%B3n+Beach/@32.0928936,-116.8833711,1155m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x80d8dc3a87fb2e25:0x41210830ea01e41a!2s22765+La+Misi%C3%B3n,+Baja+California,+Mexico!3b1!8m2!3d32.092408!4d-116.8503918!3m4!1s0x80d8dc0f609eda99:0xca90a4255b0b8031!8m2!3d32.0977633!4d-116.8837488)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sunset Key, as seen over my kids shoulders from Mallory Square, Key West, FL on Nov 20, 2019.  My littlest never likes the fact that he has to sit further back and can't hang his feet out over the water (I would have let him, but  the wife doesn't even like that the teens are LOL)

Photo taken by either me or my wife on an iphone.  [Google maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/@24.5610583,-81.8126131,17z)

[image]