# September 2021 Photo Competition: "Places" (different rules)

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the September photo competition is "Places". This competition is a multi-photo contest, much like the past competitions on road trips and castles.

Each answer should consist of up to five photos of a given place, large enough to take multiple hours to explore but smaller than an entire city. Examples include:

- The downtown area of a city
- An amusement park resort area (e.g. Legoland, the Universal Orlando resort, etc.)
- A university campus
- A major hub airport

etc.

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The following rules apply:

- At least two and up to five photos per answer. You may edit your submission to add additional photos of the same place after submission, up to the limit.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts), but each attempt should be of a different place.
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo was taken.
- The photos have to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with an entry, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin September 1, 2021, 0:00 UTC, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/11329). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

---

### Results

[Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) wins the bragging rights for the photo collection with the most votes, of Tenerife at sunset.

[undefined](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90174/undefined) wins the virtual prize for their collection of photos from Luxembourg, of which the last two strike home to me as they resemble Balboa Park here in San Diego, where I live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Luxembourg in the first week of July 2020.

Comment: Congratulations! You win the virtual prize for this month. This place looks just like Balboa Park here in San Diego, and as such strikes home to me.

Answer (score 5):

From a visit to Tenerife in October 2018.

The view across to La Gomera at sunset, the cliffs of Los Gigantes in mid-morning cloud, part of the crater of Teide, a sea pool, and Teide's peak.

It is an island of huge skies

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Congratulations! Your collection had the highest score at the end of the month, and so wins the bragging rights.

Comment: Yay - I'm off to brag to all the people sat near me. Oh, wait, nobody here :-p

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The Acropolis of Athens, as seem on 31.08.2021.

In the pictures, we see the Parthenon, the Erechteion, the inside of the Propylaea, and the Temple of Hephaestus from the top of the Acropolis.

Answer (score 3):

The tropical Hawaiian island of Oahu provides frequent rainbows and stunning oceanic views.  For those brave enough to leave Honolulu and travel westward, the climate quickly becomes hot and dry.  Within a short span of time, one can easily encounter the following specimens of abandonment in and around the leeward coast.  Due to their near worthless scrap value, privately operated toe trucks won't touch abandoned vehicles, and so they sit.

[image: Near the Cave]

[image: Such wanton abandonment!]

[image: Abandoned cars along the abandoned monorail project]

[image: Sweet Home, Waianae!]

[image: Death of a truck on the rough side of Kapolei]

Abandoned cars along the leeward coast of Oahu.  Summer 2021.

Answer (score 3):

### Bangkok's Suvarnabhumi Airport, COVID-19 style

These pictures were taken in March and April of 2021, that's during the pandemic but before cases spiked in Thailand. Just a few months later the airport took on the role of [field hospital](https://www.bangkokpost.com/thailand/general/2146415/airport-to-open-field-hospital).

Let's start at the beginning, this was the welcoming party performing a pre-check on the paper work just after exiting the plane. We see some seats for the arriving passengers, set up to accommodate social distancing. The person in the middle is checking the paperwork and in the background we see some staff escorting passengers in wheelchairs.

[image]

There's another welcoming party at the exit. These are meant to guide arriving passengers to transport taking them to the quarantine locations. I think this group is waiting for repatriating Thais so they can be escorted by the pink bus on the left to a state quarantine facility.

[image]

Now, let's go back to the airport's departure hall. As you can see, it's not very busy in the departure hall. It's a bit more crowded at the end because that's check in for the domestic flights. Also there's some social distance seating on the left. :)

[image]

As you probably know, during the pandemic everything is a bit more informal. This Vietjet Air Airbus A320 is still featuring part of its WOW Air livery.

[image]

Let's skip to April now for a final departing picture. While midnight is normally a busy time international departures, this time I was able to take a picture of the of the sculpture just after passport control without any people standing in the way.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may already know what a fan of Maltese Islands I am...but I anyway chose again to try to show the beauty of a corner of them: the area next to Mellieha that is called [Selmun](https://maps.app.goo.gl/QC41v8TBeyMdQqHM7). The green, the blue and the wind in there are definitely a part of me!

So I selected the road to [Imgiebah Beach](https://maps.app.goo.gl/MGhGtLYe1FctWuDQA),

[image: selmun1]

then Imgiebah Beach itself.

[image: imgiebah]

This is obviously [Selmun Palace](https://maps.app.goo.gl/XyEnejaPe7Mobn8cA), bad of me not showing the chapel next to it.

[image: palace]

Again the blue sea seen from the top of [Fort Campbell](https://maps.app.goo.gl/6BhCeFPbkBqhQqtn8)

[image: campbell]

and, finally, the top (to me) of the local wild nature: [Blata il-Bajda](https://maps.app.goo.gl/hfJvBAwJiuw41Tca8).

[image: blata]

All the pictures are no-filter and were taken by me in 2019.

Answer (score 2):

**Santa Cruz, California**

So how do you define a "photo"?  Are the images below one photo, 3 photos, or several hundred photos?

In truth, they are all a part of the same image, which consists of several billion pixels, created using several hundred individual photos merged together.

Not surprisingly, StackExchange can't display the full image, so you'll [need to head over here](https://www.docbert.org/SantaCruz/) to view it.

[image: Santa Cruz 1]

[image: Santa Cruz 2]

[image: Santa Cruz 3]

Comment: That 2.5 gigapixel photo is impressive.  When was it taken, and how were all the photos merged together so seamlessly?

Answer (score 2):

[image: A very old vineyard.]

[image: the famous steps in front of the Sacre Coeur from the top of the church.]

[image: The Sacre Coeur seen from the Eiffel tower.]

[image: A well decorated building.]

[image: A leaded (coloured glass) window.]

5 pictures in one of the big cities, Paris. France.
The vineyard I found on my way to the Sacre Coeur, it is one what is mostly seen as the 'back' of the hill. There has been a [vineyard](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigne_de_Montmartre) on the spot for a long time, (maybe as old as 1000 years,) this is the last remaining (or replanted) of a wine area.
After this I went up the church and took a photo down the front of the church, down the famous steps.

Now a photo of the church from the Eiffel tower, showing the area the other photos are taken, or at least near it.

Walking down the hill, you find this well decorated building, just a shop with apartments above it.

[Across a little open space](https://www.google.com/maps/@48.880899,2.3377623,3a,75y,33.85h,86.67t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1syUHjRooul9sufgLOWf7Kiw!2e0!6shttps:%2F%2Fstreetviewpixels-pa.googleapis.com%2Fv1%2Fthumbnail%3Fpanoid%3DyUHjRooul9sufgLOWf7Kiw%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D107.283806%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i16384!8i8192) this [impressive coloured glass window,](https://monumentum.fr/immeuble-pa75090002.html) as the place was closed when I was there (several times) I have only seen it 'dark' but I am sure it will be very impressive with light behind it.

All photos taken by me, in April 2015.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Klosterruine Hirsau in Hirsau, Germany, on 03.07.2021.

Answer (score 1):

### Yale University, New Haven, Connecticut

While staying with friends in north-western CT, we took a day trip to New Haven for some Frank Pepe's pizza and a walk through the grounds of Yale.

Photos taken by me on an iPhone, July 30, 2017.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Google Maps Link](https://goo.gl/maps/QtYLj3DxxACas9aZ7)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some pictures from Geamăna, Romania, taken on August 14th, 2021.

Before a copper mine was built nearby in the late 1970s, about 1000 people lived in the village of Geamăna. They were relocated by the goverment and the mine operator was allowed to dump all the toxic waste water and sludge from the copper refinement process into the valley where the village used to be. Today, the only visible remnant of the village is the church spire raging out of the mud, but there are a few people still living along the shore of the toxic pit.

The deep orange colour in one part of the lake comes from the released pyrite, which when exposed to air decomposes and then reacts with rain water to form a solution of iron oxide (rust) in sulphuric acid. On the other side of the lake, the turquoise lime water is released on purpose to neutralise the acid. The lake also contains very high levels of heavy metals like lead, mercury and arsenic.

It is perhaps not so surprising that the Ceaușescu regime allowed this to take place in the 1970s, but the mine is still operating with approval from the current authorities.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: farm building]

[image: farm building with haystack]

[image: farm building in city building shape]

[image: farm building]

[image: village buildings]

I was in the [Openluchtmuseum, Arnhem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands_Open_Air_Museum) the Netherlands, early September 2021. This is a reasonably small park, so fits the competition rules. At the same time it shows buildings from many locations in the Netherlands.
In the Netherlands, each area used to have its own traditional building style, and I have taken pictures that show several different styles.

From top the top, front of a farm building in Harreveld, in the east of the Netherlands.
A farmhouse in Varik, in the Tielerwaard Polder, between the big rivers, so quite central/south in the Netherlands.
Manor (or better said a manorshaped farm) in Oud-Beijerland, which is in the West of the Netherlands, south of Rotterdam.
A stolp farm, Zuid-Scharwoude, in the north-east of the province North Holland. All of those are combined living and stable buildings, often with hay storage inside as well.
The last picture is a collection of village buildings from the Zaan area, likely not all from the same village but both the village buildings and the farms of the area had and at times still have, this painted wood outside.

All photos by me, most only reduced in size but in one I edited out a sign in a corner.