# October 2021 Photo Competition: Local parks

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the October photo competition is "Local parks" (i.e. city/neighborhood parks). This covers any place that is located within an urban or suburban area, which is set aside for urban recreation (e.g. for children), intended for use by local residents.

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Only one photo per answer.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo was taken.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin October 1, 2021, 0:00 UTC, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/11329). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

---

### Results

JJJ wins the bragging rights for the highest-voted photo, of a Komodo dragon crossing a path in Bangkok.

mlc wins the virtual prize for their photo of a dragon-shaped slide in Berlin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

I met this friendly dragon in [a playground](https://www.berlin.de/ba-friedrichshain-kreuzberg/politik-und-verwaltung/aemter/strassen-und-gruenflaechenamt/gruenflaechen/spielplaetze/artikel.222290.php) in Berlin, January 4, 2019.

Comment: Congratulations! Your photo wins the virtual prize for this month.

Comment: @gparyani thank you!

Answer (score 8):

A scary looking [dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_dragon) crossing the jogging path in [Lumphini Park, Bangkok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumphini_Park). Taken in April of this year with a Sony RX10M3 at ƒ/4, 1/250, 128.59 mm, and ISO160.

[image]

Comment: I've visited that park and thanks God no such meetings :D

Comment: @MattAllegro They keep to themselves, I guess. [Back in 2016 the population grew to 400 or so and some were relocated to other parks](https://www.bangkokpost.com/thailand/general/1090700/beasts-of-bangkok-booted-from-park-lair). They're cool creatures though, and mostly harmless. :)

Comment: This is the highest voted photo at the end of October.

Comment: Congratulations! You win the bragging rights for this month, per above.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Cyber Park, Marrakesch, 02.02.2019.

Dozens of orange trees in there.

Answer (score 5):

Kurhauspark in Wiesbaden, Germany

*photo taken on 9th Oct 21*

[image: Kurhauspark]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The view from [Cemetery Overlook](https://www.presidio.gov/places/national-cemetery-overlook) in the Presidio in San Francisco, with a view of the Golden Gate Bridge in the background, May 19, 2013.

Comment: Nice photo, but a cemetery is not a park for children.  I suppose you could argue that it's a park for decaying bodies.

Comment: @jcklopp [The Presidio](https://www.presidio.gov/) is very much a "place within an urban area, which is set aside for urban recreation, intended for use by local residents." If you don't like my photo, feel free not to vote for it.

Answer (score 4):

On the 12th of August last year I took this photo at [Victoria Bay Park](https://maps.app.goo.gl/D8s529Rtx83LExdv8) in Victoria (or Rabat) on the island of Gozo (Malta). Tomorrow I'm flying back there again for five days and I'm so happy!!

[image: gozo malta]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Resolution Park]

This is a small city park along the southern edge of downtown Anchorage, Alaska. It's dedicated to the English explorer, Captain Cook who visited long ago
while on his final adventure.

Answer (score 3):

I took this photo from just out of the gate of [Lower Barrakka Gardens](https://maps.app.goo.gl/tdEXHhbmQHQ6qed79) in Valletta, Malta, on the 26th of August last year, with my Samsung A50 phone. Actually, I can't believe I'm flying back there in four days from now, after three flights canceled in 2021!!

[image: Lower Barrakka Gardens]

Answer (score 3):

I took this photograph on 2nd April 2021 at [Williamson Park](https://goo.gl/maps/o7BnX3xYoUcfY9hW7), Lancaster, UK. I used a Google Pixel 3 phone.

[image: Williamson Park]

Answer (score 2):

Still in Victoria on the island of Gozo (Malta), a corner of [Villa Rundle Gardens](https://maps.app.goo.gl/dDBqsr4Cd6qY1hPS8). The garden was named after the British General Leslie Rundle around 1915 and has a variety of native and imported trees giving visitors a shade from the sun.

I took this picture on 9 October 2021 with my Samsung A50 phone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Along the [*Coulée verte*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coul%C3%A9e_verte_Ren%C3%A9-Dumont) in Paris, January 20, 2019.