# November 2021 Photo Competition: Photos gone wrong

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the November photo competition is "Photos gone wrong".
Like blurs, light seeped in, night photos where you had the camera moving so the lights make a kind of lines, focus on the wrong part of the photo. Does not need to be a beautiful photo but people will still vote for what they like,

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Only one photo per answer.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo was taken, or if you can really not see what is in, an explanation of what is there.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin Novenber 1, 2021, 0:00 UTC, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

(Posted a bit late due to nobody posting the competition yet.)

Comment: Just for fun, the [village of Boccadasse, Genova, Italy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tisEY.jpg) (Jan. 2022).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solar eclipse gone wrong, some sort of light issues in the lens at the moment?

```
NIKON CORPORATION NIKON D80
ƒ/131/2500135 mmISO1000
```

El Calafate, Argentina, 12 July 2010.

[image]

Comment: This photo wins the virtual prize. It would have been the perfect photo, if not for that fail. I hope you got a good photo as well.

Answer (score 10):

The lighthouse in Porto, Portugal

September 2015

It was taken on a rainy day, with long exposure with no tripod, but I think it ended up looking cool

[image: Porto]

Comment: This photo was the most upvoted at the end of the month, you win the bragging rights.

Answer (score 6):

The majestic male Kudu.  Note the curved horns, the stripes, and....the poop. Sigh.

```
SONY DSC-V3
ƒ/41/40028 mmISO100
```

- Kruger National Park, 14 April 2005.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Self-portrait at the Great Salt Lake in Utah from a long time ago.  This was taken with a homemade pinhole camera.  Considering the equipment, it turned out pretty well!
[image: Utah 1998]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Harbour view by night]

This photo, of Leuvenhaven Rotterdam, the Netherlands, was taken free hand on a long time setting. As part of testing out the camera as much as trying to snap the scene. Photo taken 4 September 2011

Answer (score 4):

Field of Lights Uluru taken shortly after having a few wines over dinner, June 2019.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: shopwindow]
I took this photo in Brugge, (Bruges Belgium,) because I liked the display of chocolate figures.
It turned into a kind of selfie but does not work either way.
Photo taken 17 December 2011.

Answer (score 2):

Cat in garden, December 2018.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Me in Cambodia in 2018 with Samsung J5, again. Blurry portrait of people living on boats in the floating village named [Kampong Phluk](https://maps.app.goo.gl/zZNQkXWvfeXw7MF6A).

[image: Kampong Phluk]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Eiffeltower in the distance, tree branches near]
This is what we called 'the landmark from the landmark'. Standing next to the 'basilique du Sacré-Cœur' looking to the 'tour Eiffel'. The photo I wanted to take did not work out, I could not get the tower sharp in the weather conditions that day. But those tree branches in the foreground did get sharp in focus.

Taken 17 March 2016, in Paris, France.

Answer (score 2):

The majestic Forth Rail Bridge, rising out of the low mist on a bright sunny day in August while bike touring.  Unfortunately the sun on my (phone) screen was so bright I didn't realise how long it had taken actually take the picture, so I was already putting the phone away.

UleFone Armor X70.  I didn't have room for more than a compact camera  with me, and that was packed too deeply to get out.

[image: Forth Bridge - just]

Answer (score 1):

The view looking south from [the Siam Square intersection in Bangkok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siam_area). Taken in April of this year with a Sony RX10M3 at ƒ/2.4, 1/2s exposure, 8.8mm, and ISO100.

[image]

It's not a bad picture, if I may say so myself, but there's a lot more potential. To get an idea, I was going for something closer to the first of [this photo series by Michael LaPalme in 2012](https://michael-lapalme.blogspot.com/2012/12/50-long-exposure-photographs-of-bangkok.html).

The main difference between the two photos is the exposure time. Mine took 0.5 seconds while holding my camera on a railing while his took 50 seconds, probably using a tripod for stability. I had my tripod with me but as it turns out they [don't allow them on the BTS Skytrain walkways anymore](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293916-i3687-k11053893-o10-Tripods_in_Bangkok-Bangkok.html).

Answer (score 1):

Burnside Bridge in Portland, Oregon.

Shot this on long-expired, preserved slide film. As you can see, the colors are quite shifted, the image is very grainy (more visible if you zoom in), and the lab where I had the film developed complained that the film jammed their slide mounting machine and left scratches.

[image: Photo]

Taken August 7, 2021, on FPP Retrochrome 400 film, rated at 320 (based on recommendations I received).

Answer (score 1):

Cottage restaurant at the entrance to Bridal Veil Falls, near Portland, Oregon.

Shot on the same roll of film as [my other submission here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7163/11329). Additionally, the film got a bit stuck in my camera when rewinding (it was the last exposure and my camera shoots in reverse order), so this one was exposed to a bit of light. If you look carefully, you may even see a scratch caused by the lab's machines jamming.

[image: Photo]

Taken August 7, 2021, on FPP Retrochrome 400 film, rated at 320 (based on recommendations I received). Scanned myself, as I've generally done with all my film rolls for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

My folder of pictures from Cambodia seems to be particularly suitable to compete here! I took this one [here](https://maps.app.goo.gl/oTpWpU7BrCjdpKoQ6) in Phnom Penh on 7 Dec 2018 with my Samsung J5 phone. Of course a totally amateur photo, but lights and blur (also due to the timing of the car and the scooter) were not meant to look like this...

[image: phnom penh]

Answer (score 1):

The majesty of Vivid in Sydney, Australia. You can just make out the Opera House on the left.

17 Jun 2017, Nexus 6P.

[image]