# December 2021 Photo Competition - Places/buildings/scenes that no longer exist

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I will be hosting this month's photo competition. The theme chosen for this month is **Places/buildings/scenes that no longer exist**! This theme was suggested by [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill) in [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5049).

A description of the topic is:

> Any places/buildings/scenes that no longer exist for any reason. Please include the date the photo was taken (if known), the name of what is in the picture, and a brief description of why it no longer exists (e.g. building demolished, destroyed by nature etc.). The missing buildings can be photos of buildings taken when still there (link to a map service appreciated) or it can be buildings that are gone, where you can still see some remains (location appreciated as well).

---

The following rules apply:

- Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st December 2021 (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted.
- Please include a description of what you're photographing (if known), and the date the photo was taken.
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named.
- One photo per post, three posts maximum per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted.
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission to post the photo online (or blur their faces).
- No offensive / NSFW photos.
- No downvotes, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree.
- Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 on 31st December (UTC Time). The winner will then be announced. If there is a draw / tie voting will continue.

If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here). Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or add them to [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5049).

Comment: Yay! I had in mind "pictures that can no longer be taken today", which would *not* include ruins of historical buildings. Ruins and remains of buildings would be an entirely different topic for a photo contest.

Comment: @GregHewgill I added that line per the suggestion of Willeke to broaden the theme.

Comment: Photos of buildings which are no longer there are very hard to take.

Comment: @GregHewgill, this was discussed in the chat, well before the competition was posted and after posting there were a few days before the start of the month. In that time we could have changed things.

Comment: @Willeke *“Yes,” said Arthur, “yes I did. It was on display in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying ‘Beware of the Leopard.”*

Comment: @GregHewgill, It was in an almost empty room (so easy to find) where every month people are asked to post about upcoming competitions. So not as hidden as you suggest. (But you see, three entries this month so far, it is a difficult topic and not even my suggestion helped.) I am also stuck, no good photos for either the original topic nor for my suggestion.

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to be hard. It requires some digging through your own photo archives to find something that meets the criteria. It's different because it's not about going out and planning to take a great picture, but rather being lucky enough to have captured an interesting photo in the past that can't be replicated. I am pleased to see the Azure Window here!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A picture of the Azure Window (also knows as the Dwejra Window) in Gozo (an island off Malta):

[image]

Photo taken on the 5th October 2016, a few months before it [collapsed on the 8th March 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Window).

Comment: The highest voted photo for this month.

Answer (score 5):

Damaged shops in Christchurch, New Zealand from the [2010 Canterbury Earthquake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_Canterbury_earthquake) on 4 September 2010 (photo taken later that same day). Today the chemist in the foreground still exists but the row of two-storey shops behind are gone and only one has been rebuilt. [Street view today](https://goo.gl/maps/qXtR6v94aWHSUviB6)

[image]

Comment: Aha, knew there'd be a chch quake photo in here ;)

Answer (score 5):

This sign was found in Nimbin, NSW, Australia on the exterior wall of the Nimbin Museum. The museum and other buildings were destroyed in a [fire on 13 August 2014](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/aug/13/fire-that-destroyed-nimbin-main-street-buildings-suspicious-police-say). This picture was taken on 20 Dec 2004.

[image]