# January 2022 Photo Competition - water-based modes of transport

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I will be hosting this month's photo competition. The theme chosen for this month is **water-based modes of transport**! This theme was [suggested by me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60014855#60014855).

Here is a further description of the topic:

> A photo of any form of transport which predominantly operates in water.

The following rules apply:

- Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st January (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted.
- Please include a description of what you're photographing (if known), when and where the photo was taken.
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named.
- One photo per post, three posts maximum per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted.
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission to post the photo online (or blur their faces).
- No offensive / NSFW photos.
- No downvotes, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree.
- Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 31st January (UTC Time) when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue.

If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here). Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or add them to [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5049/105447).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oct 10, 2010
Lake Titicaca, Peru
Boats of the Uros Islands, floating islands on the lake

```
Panasonic DMC-TZ8
ƒ/3.31/254.4 mmISO400
```

[image]

Comment: This photo had the most votes at the end of the month.

Answer (score 10):

26 Dec 2007

Feluccas on the river Nile, near Aswan.

```
SONY DSC-V3
ƒ/51/40021.5 mmISO100
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Transport for marbles, perhaps. Part of the Chihuly exhibit at the [New York Botanical Garden](https://www.nybg.org/) in The Bronx, New York City, August 6, 2017.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Seals are perfectly happy to use ice floes for transport, but humans tend to prefer to use boats.

I took this photo on February 26, 2019, just very slightly north of the Antarctic Circle, in the [Matha Strait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matha_Strait) north of [Adelaide Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelaide_Island) off the coast of the Antarctic Peninsula.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Floating livingroom]
This photo was taken during [Sail Amsterdam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAIL_Amsterdam) 2015, 20 August 2015, Amsterdam the Netherlands.
As usual during the event some people had taken something deemed safe enough to float, added a living room on top and an outboard motor (if it did not have a build in one) and gone out on the water. In this case either the Noordzeekanaal or the IJ, and while it is rather quiet right now, it is often very busy on those waters during the event.
No, Life jackets are mostly not worn on those 'self builds' but by this time of the day those have survived a canals tour with many other self builds (and rescue boats which are really needed) so if they still float, they are deemed good.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Boat on wheels, on dry land,]
Photo taken 23 September 2014, in [Jökulsárlón](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6kuls%C3%A1rl%C3%B3n) Iceland.
This boat is still very much on wheels on dry land, but as soon as the people have put on the orange life jackets and filed onto the deck, it will go onto the lagoon, between the ice.

(I do not think I used this photo before but I certainly did use several of this day.)

Answer (score 6):

DHL boat in Venice, Italy, July 2013.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

14 April 2013, NYC harbour

Staten Island Ferry in front of Statue of Liberty

```
NIKON CORPORATION NIKON D80
ƒ/7.11/800135 mmISO500
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

November 9th, 2019.  Princess Cruises ship preparing to dock in the port of Hilo, Hawaii.

[image: Star Princess back in the good old days!]

Answer (score 5):

Passenger boat close to Santarém in Pará, Brazil, where the Tapajós river (blue) meets with the Amazon river (brown)

November 2017, taken when travelling on a similar boat between Manaus and Belém

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Crossing the Panama Canal (Miraflores locks), this ship was just lifted from the sea level to cross the lake

May 2015

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Vehicle ferry to Fraser Island, Australia, December 2004.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a picture of two of the tall ships at the Ocean Institute's Maritime Festival in Dana Point, California. Taken with a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge, September 8, 2018 from another tall ship.
[image: sailing ships offshore of Dana Point, California]

Answer (score 3):

A couple of boats arrived at St. Kitts almost exactly 15 years ago the other night, and I was aboard one of them:

[image: RMS Queen Mary 2, left, and S/V Polynesia, right, docked at St Kitts]

The brand-new Cunard flagship, RMS *Queen Mary 2*, is at left. I was not on that one.

I was on the windjammer S/V *Polynesia* at right, originally built as a fishing vessel in 1938, whose technically functional but mostly decorative sailing masts did not even reach the windows on the QM2's upper decks.

Our boat was 248 ft (75.6m)  long, theirs 1,132 ft (345m), The difference is even [more dramatic from the side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb4C5.jpg).

As it was a New Year's cruise, I imagine the QM2 had close to its capacity of around 2600 passengers, and we were at capacity with about 100. But the QM2, for all its fine restaurants and art galleries and clean toilets, has a critical flaw: it's too damn big. There are only a few Caribbean ports that can accommodate it, so they must round up their brood early to have time to sail all the way to the next one. We had no ambitions beyond Nevis, 2 miles away, and could linger on the beach [watching the money sail away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S440o.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

Hovercraft ferry to the Isle of Wight, coming in to pick up passengers, October 2004:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Traghetto (gondola strictly for canal crossing) in Venice, taken from the "water bus" near sunset, fall 2012:

[image]

The vehicle coming towards the camera above the head of the first passenger is another water bus.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Some small boats by the [Ver-o-peso market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver-o-peso) in Belém, Brazil, January 29, 2019.

Answer (score 2):

Wa'a Kaukahi (Hawaiian single hull outrigger canoe), Hilo, Hawaii, March 2010.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a flat bottom skiff crossing the mouth of the Puzi River where it flows into the Taiwan Strait.  Photo taken near the fishing harbor of Dongshi, Taiwan in January 2022.  [image: Looking for oysters]

Answer (score 2):

A boat full of colors! I took this picture just next to the [Lantern Bridge](https://goo.gl/maps/qLWV1YVXeFmLkiXZ8) in the old town of Hội An (Vietnam) on 6 Jan 2019 and I originally posted it [here](https://www.instagram.com/p/BsSLO8rBrg3/).

[image: hoian vietnam]

Answer (score 1):

[image: A cycling canoe]
Photo taken 19 August 2010, in Amsterdam during the Sail Amsterdam event of that year.
Amsterdam, the Netherlands.

This canoe is driven by pedals that work in a normal cycling fashion, it drives a propeller under the vessel.

I have found more pictures on internet but not (yet) on a site I feel right to link here. (But the names seem Wave and Native, and 'cycling canoe' or 'Fiets kano' if you want to do your own search.)

Answer (score 1):

*"Yes, and mostly Toyota!"*

Many boats in [Tonle Sap (Cambodia)](https://goo.gl/maps/5yqSUV6WnRnBtXQd7) seemed to me to be powered with second-hand diesel automotive engines.

I shot this photo on 3rd Dec 2018 and I shared it [here](https://www.instagram.com/p/B7zTOB9IObw) exactly one year ago today.

[image: tonlesap]