# February 2022 photo competition, Foreign Food

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I will be hosting this month's photo competition. The theme chosen for this month is Foreign Food, as sugested by [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo?tab=profile).

Here is a further description of the topic:
**A photo of any form of food, which is foreign to some of our members. (It can be you, it can be food which is from your home but which will be foreign for others.)**

The following rules apply:

- Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st February (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted.
- Please include a description of what you're photographing, when and where the photo was taken(if known).
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named.
- One photo per post, three posts maximum per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted.
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission to post the photo online (or blur their faces).
- No offensive / NSFW photos.
- No downvotes, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree.
- Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 28th february (UTC Time) when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue.

If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in [chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or them to [this post.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition/5049#5049)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: Dessert]

[Trdelník](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trdeln%C3%ADk), a Slovak dessert treat popular in the Czech Republic. It's a hollow cylinder made of baked wheat strips, with cinnamon and vanilla sugar sprinkled on. In the photo, it's seen on the left side, behind the brown cake slice.

I baked that cylinder myself for my mother's birthday in 2020. The other desserts seen in the image weren't baked by me.

Shot on Kodak Portra 400 film.

Comment: This photo has the highest number of votes and has won the bragging rights.

Answer (score 8):

28 July 2015

```
HTC HTC_0P6B
ƒ/21/303.82 mmISO200

Isfahan, Isfahan Province, Iran
```

The Persian designation pacha stems from the term pāče, literally meaning "trotter".[3] The combination of a sheep's head and trotters is called kalle-pāče, which literally means "head [and] trotter" in Persia.
In the bowl is bits of the brain. From the head, the cheek was the best part.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Plate with meat and some other items]

A plate with beefsteak tartare, in the French way.
Photo taken 11 March 2016, in Honfleur, France.

This is meat to be eaten raw, with the egg yolk and some of the items in the collection of bottles and the pickles on the plate, with chips/fries on the side.

Not allowed to be served in England for a while, it is a tradition between an English friend and me to order it at least once when we met in France (which used to happen yearly till Covid.)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

This photo was taken in the Maasai Mara reserve in Kenya in November 2021.

This zebra is certainly foreign food to me, both because I'm not from Kenya and because I don't eat raw zebra meat like this lion seems to like :)

P.S. I put a photo in which we don't see any flesh but feel free to remove remove it if considered offensive/crude.

Comment: This photo has won the virtual prize, as it is an explanation of 'food' I had not expected.

Comment: @Willeke Sweet, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I definitely understand that the following content may hurt some people sensibility, in this case feel free to immediately delete if not appropriate. I enjoy these monthly contests so much and I do not want to seem/be unfair. I post what follows because I was the first one impressed by the fact that what is shocking in my country or culture can be normal somewhere else.

> Grilled dog meat served on 27 Jan 2019 at [Truong Dog Meat Restaurant](https://goo.gl/maps/RFsuSbtDRTzEwReJA) in Ho Chi Minh (Vietnam). I shot the photo with my Samsung J5 phone.

> [image: grilled dog meat]

Comment: Interesting, for some reason I didn't expect it to be that colour.  Good job on hiding it, and as a dog owner it upsets me, but it's interesting to see, as you say how different cultures vary!

Comment: As someone who grew up with dogs as housemates (or even 'brother and sister') I was not upset, but it is the photos of before butchering which always upset me.

Comment: I am glad that this post was intended for what it wanted to be: discussing a topic, although it is controversial, without any urge to make a scoop :)

Answer (score 5):

[image: South Korean not-pizza]

This "Chicago" style "pizza" was once served in South Korea.  It would make anyone from Chicago look twice.  The crust was like a donut covered in powdered sugar.  The ketchup-like red sauce covered large amounts of cheese.  Of course, pickles and jalapenos on the side completed the mandatory ingredients of any deep dish Chicago styled pizza.  Photo taken in the Myeongdong neighborhood of Seoul, South Korea circa March of 2019. Sadly, the restaurant has since closed.

Comment: .... was it good?

Comment: Yes!  Once the preconception of what Chicago style pizza should taste like was cleared from the mind, this was surprisingly delicious.

Answer (score 5):

This was taken by me in June 2019. It was taken at the Karrke Aboriginal Cultural Tour near Kings Canyon, Northern Territory Australia, and shows a variety of desert grains.  Only anonymous feet, legs and hands in this particular photo. [image: bush tucker]

Answer (score 4):

20 July, 2018
St Leonard's/ Crow's Nest Sydney

```
Huawei Nexus 6P
ƒ/21/304.67 mmISO877
```

This restaurant was showing up on social media for their desserts, which looked uncannily realistic.  We had to try it!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This delicious **Thai rice with chicken** was served to me on 20 Oct 2018 on the island of Koh Phangan (Thailand), in a restaurant somewhere close to [Chaloklum](https://goo.gl/maps/LKR5FqS1G9WNF9QU7). It is paired with lime, cucumber and the typical (and amazing) spicy pepper in fish sauce. I shot this photo with my Samsung J5 phone and I originally posted it [here](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bs9uRFnnlR8/).

[image: Thai rice]

Comment: The restaurant is actually called [Nong View](https://maps.app.goo.gl/RMeU1svQiZvivPzY9)!

Answer (score 2):

1 Aug 2014

```
LGE Nexus 4
ƒ/2.651/204.6 mmISO400
```

Kobe, Japan

Kobe steak, on recommendation from @Pops.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Plate of sweet stuff]
A 'grand desert' with many lovely options.
You were served this for yourself, to eat all of it, at the end of a good dinner.

Photo taken 11 March 2016, to finish off the dinner where the raw meat was one of the courses.

Answer (score 2):

Aji (Horse Mackerel) sashimi prepared freshly for us at a small sushi bar in Tokyo in April 2009. The chef did not speak any English, so the teenage dishwasher translated for us.

[image: Horse mackerel sashimi]

Answer (score 1):

#### Chicken hearts!

The photo below, taken by me in 27th November 2021 in a farm in southern Brazil (somewhat close to Uruguay border) shows a typical barbecue with an assortment of meat and sausages.

Even though barbecue is not foreign food for a lot of western cultures, this one has a few distinguishing features:

1. It's cooked in a trench on the ground using log fire
2. Next to the sausages are tiny pieces of meat which, as far as I know, are foreign to most of the cultures I know. Those are chicken hearts!

Kids usually love chicken hearts, that explains why they are placed in a short skewer, since kids are expected to help prepare the barbecue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let us go back to my favourite, Maltese Islands!

**Qassatat** is a savoury pastry pocket that can be filled with spinach and anchovies as in the image below, but also [with ricotta cheese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hekxh.jpg) or [with mashed peas and paired with a lovely local beer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8dkK.jpg).

Apparently, it somehow takes its name from Sicilian *Cassata*, but this latter is a dessert instead. Whereas Italian *ricotta* is made from leftovers from the production of other cheese, Maltese *irkotta* used to fill qassatat is produced by heating fresh milk before adding salt to form the curd. The price for one quassatat ranges from 1 to 2 euros and this chubbier cousin of [pastizzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastizz) is definitely deliciously tasty and worth trying.

The one you see here was served to me at [Palazzo Gatto in Mdina](https://goo.gl/maps/fS73veYdANrXeam7A) on 11 March 2019 and I shot the photo with my Huawei phone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An experiment to find out if Spanish Lentejas Pardinas (on right half of image) are an adequate substitute for French Lentilles Vertes (on left half of image) when used in the oven without being soaked or cooked first. Our judgement: good enough so long as the lamb juices and a little water make their way down into the base of the tray. The photo was taken by me last autumn in the Subbética region (Córdoba province, Andalucía, Spain).

[image]