# April 2022 Photo competition, Signs of change of season

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I will be hosting this month's photo competition. The theme chosen for this month is **Signs of change of season.** This theme has not yet been suggested so it is by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke).

Here is a further description of the topic:
**The signs of change of season can be natural, like new flowers coming through or autumn/fall colours in the forests but also festivals usually connected to a 'new season' or the end of a period, like end of a period of fasting.**

The following rules apply:

- Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st April 2022 (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted.
- Please include a description of what you're photographing, when and where the photo was taken.
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named.
- One photo per post, three posts maximum per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted.
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission to post the photo online (or blur their faces).
- No offensive / NSFW photos.
- No downvotes, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree.
- Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 30th of April (UTC Time) when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue.

If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here). Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or them to [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition/5049#5049).

Comment: What an excellent idea! I think I have a few good photos for this one :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Trees that change color with the seasons, metals that change color with the decades: autumn at the [Storm King Art Center](https://stormking.org/). This is [*Four Corners*](https://collections.stormking.org/Detail/objects/450) by Forrest Myers, in a photo I took on October 28, 2018.

Comment: You won the bragging rights, the most votes at the end of the month.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Tiny Snowman in Anchorage somewhere along the the Chester Creek Trail]

This tiny Alaskan snowman is unhappy about winter turning into spring. The big April fools joke is on him as he drips away with the spring thaw and washes out to the ocean. So sad... Photo taken in Anchorage, AK.  Late March 2022.

Comment: You win the virtual prize, most unexpected sight but keeps bringing a smile on my face.

Answer (score 5):

A nutria in a park in Prague, Czech Republic, November 2018

[image]

Answer (score 5):

First signs of autumn, British Columbia, October 2018

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My mom, who knows, says that the [almond tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almond) is among the first ones to bloom in springtime. This one is in the garden of my house in [Bologna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna), I took the picture on March 9, this year and now all the blossoms have already gone after a hard rain falling two days ago.

[image: almond tree]

Answer (score 3):

[image: daffodils]

My first daffodils of the year. They were under snow two days ago. My garden - West Lothian, Scotland. April 2, 2022.

Answer (score 2):

[image: A tree with an Easter egg.]
An easter egg in a tree, down from the Sacre Coeur in Paris, France, on the more quiet side of the hill, a photo taken 5 April 2015.
Not just the egg but also the leaves and flowers in the garden give signs of a change of season.

Answer (score 2):

[image: A tiny tree with yellow leafs.]
Taken near the Þingvellir, Iceland, on 20 September 2014, this little tree has changed colour and lost many of its leafs. It is almost ready for winter although that might take a few more weeks for it to really arrive.