# May 2022 photo competition, Doors, Gates and other Portals

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I will be hosting this month's photo competition. The theme chosen for this month is **Doors, gates, or other portals**, suggested by [choster](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster)

The following rules apply:

- Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st May 2022 (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted.
- Please include a description of what you're photographing, when and where the photo was taken.
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named.
- One photo per post, three posts maximum per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted.
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission to post the photo online (or blur their faces).
- No offensive / NSFW photos.
- No downvotes, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree.
- Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 31th of May (UTC Time) when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue.
- If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here). Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or add them to [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition/5049#5049).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: One-legged Torii, Nagasaki]

This is the famous one legged torii gate near the Sanno Shrine in Nagasaki, Japan. It lost a leg in the atomic blast at the conclusion of world war two and has remained precariously balanced in this manner ever since. Photo taken in January of 2019.

Comment: You got the bragging rights, highest voted photo at the end of the month.

Answer (score 4):

The wonderful arch to St Bartholomew's Church in East Smithfield, London

[image]

Taken by me on a Oneplus 7 Pro in Nov 2021

Comment: You get the virtual prize, one of the old spots in London, I always like it.

Comment: Awwww - thanks. I always like walking past there as there are so many cool alleyways and arches

Answer (score 3):

[image: Gate B18 at Chicago ORD]

Chicago O'Hare International Airport last winter.  Behind this invitingly open door I found a portal to Hawaii.

Answer (score 3):

Gate made out of old fishing nets and related equipment in a small community in Lençóis Maranhenses, Brazil

July 2018

[image: Gate]

Answer (score 3):

Now one of my favourites: [Genial](https://maps.app.goo.gl/VESUnp8KB2kpUGZG6) of Archibishop Street in Valletta, Malta. I took this photo in 2019 and originally posted it [here](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bt7IGpFHmGZ/).

[image: Genial]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The [Golden Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Gate) and its eponymous bridge, San Francisco, August 8, 2008.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Guarding the entrance to a tea farm near [Udhagamandalam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ooty) (Ooty) in the [Nilgiri mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilgiri_Mountains) in Tamil Nadu, India. I took this photo on October 20, 2014.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go for the door of a private house, in [Trani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trani) (Italy): I took this picture with my Samsung A50 phone on the 24th of August last year.

[image: blue house door]

Answer (score 2):

[image: blue and white markee front with entrance openings.]

Markee frames and fronts already put op, but open to the sky, Henley on Thames, getting ready for the Royal Regatta, which will be in July. Photo taken 30 April 2022, Henley on Thames, England.

Answer (score 2):

Science gate at the University of Cork, Ireland, March 2009.

[image: Partially open metal gate with the word SCIENCE on it]

Answer (score 2):

[image: A set of lock gates]
Photo taken 8 May 2022, in Flatford, England.
It is a set of lock gates, or in Dutch, sluis deuren (so doors.)

This is in John Constable country, just outside the family mill he grew up and in the landschape he used as inspiration or actual view for many of his paintings.

Answer (score 2):

Gate of All Nations, Persepolis, Iran

June 2016
[image: Gate of All Nations]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A Torii gate at the [Brooklyn Botanic Garden](https://www.bbg.org/) winter Lightscape, on December 27, 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Pink Mosque, Shiraz, Iran

June 2016

[image: Pink Mosque]

Answer (score 1):

I play my card number 3: [Caccia](https://maps.app.goo.gl/kqvdNVk53chMS1HAA) (Gozo), last month. I took this picture of the triple with my Samsung A50 phone. I wish I could make one more step back but the court was narrow!

[image: three house doors in Gozo]