# June 2022 Photo competition, Statues and other pieces of Art or 'art' that decorate fountains, streets, squares or the middle of a roundabout

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

This month's photo competition theme is **Statues and other pieces of Art or 'art' that decorate fountains, streets, squares or the middle of a roundabout.**
You can post up to three photos of the same piece of art or of the same series of statues if they are a group.

The following rules apply:

- Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st June 2022 (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted.
- Please include a description of what you're photographing, when and where the photo was taken.
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named.
- Up to three photos per post, three posts maximum per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted.
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission to post the photo online (or blur their faces).
- No offensive / NSFW photos.
- No downvotes, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree.
- Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 30th of June (UTC Time) when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue.
  If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here). Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or add them to [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition/5049#5049).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Lille, France, there is a series of statues that look like they are there for a short term. They are called Moss people as a group and each has its own name. For the photos I have selected the Philosopher and the Doctor. And added a view of the street with more of the Moss people.
More information [from this site (PDF)](https://utopia.lille3000.com/app/uploads/2022/03/lille3000-UTOPIA-DP-GB_032022-MAIL.pdf):

> Kim Simonsson, Moss People
> LA RAMBLA (RUE FAIDHERBE), LILLE - 14 May > 02 October 2022
> Born in Finland in 1974, Kim Simonsson graduated from
> the School of Arts, Design and Architecture in Helsinki.
> He lives and works in Fiskars, Finland.
> His sculptures evoke an imaginary world, often populated by fairy-like figures from Nordic tales in which small
> characters are gradually transformed into parts of the
> plant world.
> For Utopia, the Moss People are wanderers from the
> Nordic forests. They are gatherers wearing cauliflower
> shoes and headgear for some to protect them from the
> elements. The Moss People communicate with the primordial universal sign language they have created together. Like migratory birds, they move from one place to another, each with a purpose to find their sign. Through
> a narrative that weaves between the real world and the
> supernatural, the ten elves draw us into the heart of the
> Taiga, those dense northern forests rich in tales of the
> imagination.

[image: The Philosopher, one of the Moss people]

[image: The Doctor, one of the Moss people]

[image: The street with Moss people]

All photos taken 21 May 2022.

Comment: Most upvoted post at the end of the month, thanks for the votes.

Answer (score 4):

This masterpiece of Socialist Realism is located in [Hang Dau Garden](https://maps.app.goo.gl/9nFBQ21vc9WJn5CSA), Hanoi (Vietnam). Over-exposed photos by me, January 2019.

[image: statue in Hanoi Vietnam]

[image: back of the monument]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The [Giant Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_Swing) in Bangkok at sundown, October 23, 2019.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Renato Gaucho kicking the Sun]

This is a statue for [Renato Gaucho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renato_Ga%C3%BAcho), a brazilian soccer Player for his accomplishments as both a soccer player and manager. The statue is located in [Gremio's stadium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arena_do_Gr%C3%AAmio) , one of the teams he played during his career.

Since he was famous for having scored important goals, I took this picture in February 2022 in an angle where he was (supposedly) about to kick the Sun.

Answer (score 2):

Sculpture of dragon with umbrellas, Venice (Campo San Salvador), July 2013.

[image: Sculpture of dragon with umbrellas]

Comment: Hm? I'm seeing neither a dragon nor umbrellas in the photo...

Comment: @Martha: It's not just me, a photo of the same sculpture appears on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbrella with the description "An iron sculpture of a dragon holding three colorful umbrellas in Campo San Salvador in Venice, Italy".

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Some cute painted planters on the sidewalk promoting the love of digital anonymity and privacy, which I spotted in Quito, on September 5, 2017.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Tórshavn, the capital of the Faroe Islands, is a lovely place, but chilly year-round. Even the statues, like this one outside of the tourist office downtown, are shivering. I took this photo on August 5, 2015.

Comment: You get the virtual prize, makes me smile.

Comment: @Willeke thanks, glad you liked it!

Answer (score 2):

In Maranello, everything is Ferrari. Even the roundabouts

*Photo taken exactly 3 years ago - June 1, 2019*

[image: Maranello]

Answer (score 2):

[image: King Sejon sitting above Gwanghwamun Plaza]

This is a statue of King Sejon in the center of Gwanghwamun Plaza. This area is the heart of Seoul, South Korea.  It has been the site of many massive and peaceful protests as well as celebrations and fun events.  Photo taken early 2017.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I liked this because of the old overlooking the new, and the mixture of real people with images of people. Taken by me in Norwich, UK in August 2018.

Answer (score 2):

This metal loop sits in the middle of a roundabout, is shows rather different faces depending on which angle you approach it.

[image: Big loop on a roundabout.]

[image: Big loop on a roundabout.]

This piece of 'art' or Art is situated on the crossing of de Jan van Kuikweg and De Baandert, Heemskerk. [Here is a link to the location on Google maps.](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Jan+van+Kuikweg+%26+De+Baandert,+1963+RE+Heemskerk/@52.5103459,4.6842671,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c5fa093159d0fb:0x6c7f47af5103a430!8m2!3d52.5103459!4d4.6864558)

Photos taken on 7 June 2022. Heemskerk, the Netherlands.