# Upcoming 2022 photo competitions, themes not decided yet

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

As there is very little feedback about the competitions before they are posted and I am running out of inspiration, I wonder if you regulars are willing to post comments or edit into this question what theme you would want for the July competition.
Before the start of the month I will edit this question with the normal competition information and adjust the header to the theme decided on.

As usual, you can post in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) instead.

This question did not work as I expected, I am going to leave this one open for a while longer and take one of the answers for the July competition. (A few more days before I am going to post it.)

Answer (score 7):

How about something focused on a particular color. For example: photos highlighting real world examples (natural or man made) of various shades of purple (or whatever color you prefer to see).

Comment: This was a good suggestion: Most beautiful (or curious) banknotes collected in travels, by MattAllegro

Comment: Pictures of ice at various scales might also be interesting and a good summer time distraction from the heat.

Comment: I have taken this answer, most upvoted for now, for the July 2022 competition. Please post the other ideas as answers as well, they will stand out better that way.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we've had anything like *things (far) out of place*.  That could include things like a souvenir that now goes on your travels with you, or something completely unexpected like a piano on a mountain top.

Even people - a bagpiper in front of the colosseum for example.

Answer (score 4):

I just checked the [Possible topics for the photo competition](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition/5049) post and did not find a topic I really thought would've been in the monthly competition so far: single photos showing parts of 2 or 3 countries (since [there are no quadripoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadripoint) currently).

Perhaps it can more generally be written as *photos of an international border showing parts of more than one country*?

<sub>P.S.: I recently have been to a [tripoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tripoints) so I might, perhaps, be biased since I have a few very good photos on this subject.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I enjoy to stay focused on landscape images...so why not *Mountains and sea in the same photo*? Or any variation you may like, since more people have more creativity :)

Answer (score 2):

How about photos showing three or more different forms of transport? All motorised wheeled road vehicles count the same but rail traffic is distinct. Human-powered wheeled vehicles and animal powered vehicles are each separate categories. Different non-human animals count as one but count separately from human animals (so a total possible for foot transport of two). It is a count of forms so the start of the Boston Marathon only counts for one human pedestrian.

I suspect the rules might need a bit of fine tuning but I am not a lawyer.

Comment: "All wheeled road vehicles count the same" - I'd say all *motorised* wheeled vehicles count the same; *human-powered* wheeled vehicles like bikes and kick-scooters should count separately, and animal-powered of course a third.

Comment: @ChrisH-UK yes, that seems a fair addition. I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

I propose a theme of **Pictures that want to lead you somewhere unseen.**

This is distinct from a previous theme of **Doors, Gates and other Portals.** It is not about the portal itself (although that might help), but what might lie beyond that we cannot see.

It could be a doorway, stair or anywhere that *does not show where* it actually takes you, but teases the imagination. The emphasis is on the intriguing or mysterious.

Here is an example of a stairway, and an archway. We can't see where they go, but would perhaps like to find out.

[image]

These examples were taken by a relative; I don't have any myself.

Answer (score 1):

Willeke's own suggestion of  "Items you have made/repaired that you use while traveling, either your own inventions, variations on well known items or very useful repairs on travel items." is quite appealing; an alternative version would have the improvisation itself taking place while away.