# July 2022 photo competition: Photos highlighting real world examples (natural or man made) of various shades of purple

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

This month's photo competition theme is: Photos highlighting real world examples (natural or man made) of various shades of purple, as suggested by [jcklopp](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/110701/jcklopp) in reaction to [this question.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/upcoming-2022-photo-competitions-themes-not-decided-yet?cb=1)
You can post up to three photos per post if they are in some way connected, please explain the connection.

The following rules apply:

- Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st July 2022 (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted.
- Please include a description of what you're photographing, when and where the photo was taken.
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named.
  Up to three photos per post, three posts maximum per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted.
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission to post the photo online (or blur their faces).
- No offensive / NSFW photos.
- No downvotes, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree.
- Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 31st of July (UTC Time) when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue. If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in chat. Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or add them to this post.

Comment: Do photos shot on a film stock that deliberately shifts colors towards purple (LomoChrome Purple XR) count as a man-made example?

Comment: I say yes, if the resulting picture has purple tones in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the season of lavender blooms in France! We were apprehensive but got lucky to witness these majestic beauties in person.

**Place:** Lavender fields near Valensole, France

**When:** June 2022

**Shot by:** Self

[image: rows of lavender plants]

[image: lavender buds close up]

[image: purple lavender everywhere]

Comment: You got the most votes at the end of the month, the bragging rights are yours.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am truly elated and so shall my partner who chose this destination to travel :)

Comment: I also really liked your purple food photo, you missed out on the virtual prize as you won wij h this one.

Answer (score 7):

When (the then) Asia's best and [global top 5](https://www.theworlds50best.com/previous-list/2019) restaurant opened its doors in a new format, me and my friend were quick to reserve our spots.

Known for its emoji menu, flamboyance and rock music, we were served this course on a purple cloth tied with an embroidery hoop. The fried snack was made with purple ingredients including edible purple flowers.
Aptly, the emoji for this course was  with Prince's [Purple rain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6Y1gohk5-A) playing in the background.

**Place:** Gaggan Anand restaurant, Bangkok, Thailand

**When:** November 2019

**Shot by:** Self

[image: a deep fried purple snack served on a purple cloth]

Answer (score 6):

This sea urchin was photographed last April on the rocky shores of Moku Nui, a small islet east of Oahu, Hawaii. Unlike most sea urchins which have sharp, spiky spines, this type has flattened spines that look like purple shingles. It has evolved to withstand the full force of pounding waves.

[image]

and from above it looks like this

[image]

Comment: You get the virtual prize this month.

Answer (score 5):

A passion fruit flower, taken close to Playa del Ancón, Tenerife

June 2022

[image: passion fruit flower]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Taken by me with a disposable camera at Todra Gorge, Morocco in March 2006.

The sheer purple cliff dwarfs the buildings at its foot.
Vendors in the foreground have clothes on display in various colours, including purple.

Answer (score 4):

A hibiscus hybrid called the Mountain Mist has some nice shades of purple along with the Hawaiian Ti plants behind it. Photo taken on Oahu on July 4th.

[image: Mountain Mist Hibiscus Flower]

Answer (score 3):

A purple bus with a photo of Dési Bouterse, the then president of Suriname (and a very controversial figure).

Paramaribo, Suriname

February 2019

[image: bus]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Photo]

Mountainous sunset with moon

Photo taken Tuesday, July 12th on i90 in Washington State, USA, near to Lake Keechelus

Answer (score 3):

Shades of purple: The reflection of the sail's shadow on the water. A shot I took against the afternoon sun on 2011-07-21 in Ericeira, Portugal at the Matadouro Beach.

I used a Canon EOS 400D DIGITAL @ 1/640 ISO-100 f/7.1 with a cheap 100-300 zoom lens

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'll have a go with a sunset I caught earlier this month [in Tarifa](https://maps.app.goo.gl/KQwepbktXpAkt1E26), Spain. Hope you will enjoy this picture I took with my Samsung A50 phone!

[image: Sunset over Tarifa Spain]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Keyfob with two knots and some braiding.]
This is a keyfob with two Wee Vos Knots, (the knot is named for the late Jan Vos, who was a top knot tyer.)
There is some purple string in the knots, but the main colour is kind of purple itself.

The knots were tied June 2nd to 4th, the photo was taken June 5th, 2022, Velsen Noord, the Netherlands.