# August 2022 photo competition: Things (far) out of place

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

This month's photo competition theme is **Things (far) out of place.**
That could include things like a souvenir that now goes on your travels with you, or something completely unexpected like a piano on a mountain top.
Even people - a bagpiper in front of the colosseum for example.
Theme suggested by [Chris H - UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/18491/chris-h-uk) in a reaction to [this question.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/upcoming-2022-photo-competitions-themes-not-decided-yet?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The following rules apply:

- Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st August 2022 (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted.
- Please include a description of what you're photographing, when and where the photo was taken.
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named.
- Up to three photos per post have to be about the same item out of place, three posts maximum per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted.
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission to post the photo online (or blur their faces).
- No offensive / NSFW photos.
- No downvotes, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree.
- Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 31th of August (UTC Time) when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue. If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or [post in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here). Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or add them to [this post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Giraffe on the roof

[image]

This picture was taken by me in Ely, UK in April 2022.

Comment: I know a giraffe in a front garden in Calne UK, but never took a picture. Yours is better, more unexpected.

Comment: @Willeke it can be seen from some distance away from another direction!

Comment: If you have a second photo, it can be added to the post, this month (like the last few) allows for up to three photos.

Comment: @Willeke sadly I don't have one. I would have to take a safari to Ely and get a camera better suited to wildlife pictures, at that range.

Comment: You win the bragging rights, the highest voted photo at the end of the month.

Answer (score 8):

["I wonder if it will be friends with me?"](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/198068-another-thing-that-got-forgotten-was-the-fact-that-against)

[image: whale tail sculpture]

Whale tail sculpture in the Icelandic countryside, about 20km north of Akureyri on highway 82.  June 2021.

Comment: You win the virtual prize, already just for your quote but the photo itself is also good.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Moscow? China? No, this is [Superkilen Park](https://www.visitcopenhagen.com/copenhagen/planning/superkilen-park-gdk707822) in the Nørrebro neighborhood of Copenhagen, Denmark, filled with a variety of signs, fixtures, and art from Denmark and from all around the world. I took this photo (and [some more](https://www.flickr.com/search/?sort=date-taken-desc&safe_search=1&tags=superkilen&user_id=66458073%40N00&view_all=1)) on January 7, 2019.

Answer (score 6):

Bagpipers playing in front of Museu do Amanhã, Rio De Janeiro, Brasil

July 2017

[image: bagpipers]

Answer (score 1):

This photo taken in June of 2020 shows remains of a crashed B-24 Liberator Bomber that is slowly sinking into a muddy hillside on Oahu.

[image: One of four engines from a B24 that crashed on Oahu]

On May 5th, 1944 this plane was headed to Australia. It flew only six miles before failing to turn and crashing into a mountain ridgeline. All 10 crew members were killed in the accident. The site was rediscovered in 1993 and the debris have been slowly falling down the steep hillside with each passing storm. The site is a stark contrast to the public hiking trail and beautiful nature reserve in which it resides. Today it represents a fading memory of the world's largest ranging and most vicious battle.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say that in my standards, a winery inside a jewellery is at least unusual. Instead, in *Antoniou* it is not!

Picture by me, from Santorini, September 2019.

[image: Antoniou Jewellery and Wines, Santorini]