# September 2022 Photo competition: Photos showing three or more different forms of transport

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

This month's photo competition theme is **Photos showing three or more different forms of transport.**
All motorised wheeled road vehicles count the same but rail traffic is distinct. Human-powered wheeled vehicles and animal powered vehicles are each separate categories. Different non-human animals count as one but count separately from human animals (so a total possible for foot transport of two). It is a count of forms so the start of the Boston Marathon only counts for one human pedestrian.
Theme suggested by [mdewey](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/66146/mdewey) in a reaction to [this question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/upcoming-2022-photo-competitions-themes-not-decided-yet?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The following rules apply:

- Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st September 2022 (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted.
- Please include a description of what you're photographing, when and where the photo was taken.
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named.
- One photo with three modes of transport per post three posts maximum per person. Do not delete or change photos once posted.
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission to post the photo online (or blur their faces).
- No offensive / NSFW photos.
- No downvotes, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree.
  Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 30th of September (UTC Time) when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue.

If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here). Please suggest any more ideas for themes there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: USS Midway in San Diego, California]

Ships (most prominently the USS Midway), airplanes, cars and people walking. Photo taken in April 1st, 2012 in San Diego, CA. It's also worth noting that the US aircraft carrier contain multiple unique methods of transportation within itself.  This includes multiple catapults to launch planes, large lifts to move aircraft to and from the deck, and a wide array of defensive weaponry to stop incoming threats.

Comment: You got the extra vote, after the end of the month. You now have the bragging rights for this months competition.

Answer (score 5):

**Boats** on the River Thames
**Train** at (left) Charing Cross Station
**Buses** on Waterloo Bridge
**Ferris wheel** capsule

[image]

Taken by me from the London Eye in February 2011.

Comment: + people in capsule

Comment: @RussellMcMahon true, but they are not travelling by foot, not pedestrians, although there are some ant-like people bottom right, on the ground, and on Waterloo Bridge.

Comment: You are under-selling yoursel :-) . The people are people so would seem to count. An empty car seen through a closed showroom window feels (to me) as if it would count. An overturned cart or bicycle would apparently count. That they appear to be standing puts them in "transport mode" but I'd imagine that just being there would suffice.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon when I posted it, I zoomed into the image to see if I could spot any bicycles, but did not. I overlooked 'walking' as a means of transport.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Bicycle parking, skips, train and people walking]
Paddington station, London UK, 1 May 2016, with bicycles, skips (on wheels, so transports) people walking, and trains.

Comment: I believe that's London Paddington station :)

Comment: It might be, coming in from Maidenhead. Edited: It is, it even says so in the full version of the photo, Welcome to Paddington Station, on the big notice in the center of the roof arch.

Answer (score 3):

Pedestrians, mixed engine-powered vehicles and an original bicycle in Ho Chi Minh City, on 2 Jan 2019.

This is in front of the Opera House where, back in the day, Vietnam and Japan were collaborating to build the urban railway infrastructure including the [Opera House Metro Station](https://maps.app.goo.gl/cuCZtgEicnB6C2tK9).

[image: ho chi minh city]

Answer (score 2):

**Wheelchair** (left)
**Bicycles** (background)
**Motor vehicle** (right)
**Carousel** (round and round and up and down)

[image]

Taken by me in York, UK in September 2017.

Comment: You get the virtual prize, for not just one but two photos with things just going round, although I think this one is worth the actual prize, as it goes round and round and round and some more. (If you want a prize you can feel, you have my permission to go to your nearest road roundabout and go round it a few times, but just in times of little traffic, all cost and risks on you.)

Answer (score 2):

Last of 3 - out of 40+ candidates.

Left to right:

- People
- Pushchair
- Cars & light truck
- Light armoured vehicle
- Bren gun carrier
- Trailer & Truck

[image]

Pushchair - far left

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Qingdao, China.
Too many potential images. China offers much :-)

Left to right:

- Van (& almost hidden motorscooter)
- 3 wheeler - reminiscent of Mr Beans car (it's qute different, of course).
- Motorcycle
- Truck

[image]

Comment: "All motorised wheeled road vehicles count the same" so there is only one example here.

Comment: @WeatherVane True, alas.  I'll delete the answer as invalid. I did like the re car thingy :-)

Comment: You missed an other rule, do not take out photos (or really posts.) You posted it, you should stand by it.

Answer (score 1):

"Convenient transportation elite gathered"
Shanghai, China (2012)

Left to right:

- Toiling worker
- Barrow
- Motorcycle
- Car

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Helicopter
- People
- Road vehicles

[image]

Comment: Given time a shot at far slower shutter speed would give tail rotor blur and maybe main rotor too.  Generally, the photo you take is better than the superior photo that you miss.

Comment: As @Willeke commented, you've deleted one of your three submissions, but now you added another. That's four submissions.

Comment: @WeatherVane  Yes. I commented on Willeke's comment to them. I apparently misinterpreted tge intention of the rule re deleting photos. You pointed out that my other post was not a valid one, so I deleted it. Fotunately, as I came late to the piece, and as nobody is voting for my submissions ten it will not affect anything. If I now delete this entry, or all my entries, I may be deemed  to be breaking the rules. That of course does not then affect outcomes but may be held against me subsequently. With about 3 days left to run, cowering in place now seems my best option :-) .

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, we let it slip this time, next time you might find the replacement and deleted both out of the competition.