# October 2022 photo competition: Yellow

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

This month's photo competition theme is: **Photos highlighting real world examples (natural or man made) of various shades of yellow**, a variation on a suggested theme by [jcklopp](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/110701/jcklopp) in reaction to [this question.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/upcoming-2022-photo-competitions-themes-not-decided-yet?cb=1)
You can post up to three photos per post if they are in some way connected, please explain the connection. Up to three posts.

The following rules apply:

- Please do not post photos until 00:00:00 1st October 2022 (UTC Time) - any photos posted before that time will not be counted.
- Please include a description of what you're photographing, when and where the photo was taken.
- Photos should be taken by you or a travel companion who is named. Up to three photos per post, three posts maximum per person. Do not delete or change photos or posts once posted. (Not even when they break the rules.)
- If there are any people in the photo, make sure you have their permission to post the photo online (or blur their faces).
- No offensive / NSFW photos.
- No downvotes, they are not counted. Please leave a comment if you disagree.
  Photos may be posted until 23:59:59 31st of October (UTC Time) when the winner will be announced. If there is a draw/tie voting will continue.

If you have any suggestions, please leave a comment or post in chat. Please suggest any more ideas for themes there or add them to [this post.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/upcoming-2022-photo-competitions-themes-not-decided-yet?cb=1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The infamous Chernobyl Ferris wheel, in Pripyat, Ukraine.

28 October 2008

[image]

Comment: Does it have a nice radioactive glow at night?

Comment: You win the bragging rights.

Comment: @Willeke woo! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

This thread needs a mention of **Hoi An**, the *yellow town* of Vietnam. Its [old town](https://maps.app.goo.gl/jjq5fWGgVaJuHj5A9), UNESCO heritage site since 1999, features the typical buildings developed in XV-XIX century. Their color was considered to be good wishing.

I took these photos in January 2019.

[image: hoi an 1]

[image: hoi an 2 cam pho temple]

[image: hoi an 3 cam pho temple]

In picture 1 a random palace, pictures 2, 3 and [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv82W.jpg) from Cam Pho temple.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Sea Kayaking off Oahu]

A yellow sea kayak! Photo taken in early August of 2022 from between Lanikai beach and the Mokulua and Mokuiki islands off Oahu, Hawaii.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Hawaiian Bananas]

A bunch of dwarf bananas grown in Ewa Beach, Hawaii.  Harvested in mid August of 2022.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Flower vendors at the Wiesbaden Sunday market]

Flowers for sale at a farmer's market in Wiesbaden Germany. Photo taken in late August, 2022.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Spirit Airlines plane landing at John Wayne Airport, Orange County, California, USA. Spirit is an ultra-low-cost airline which paints its planes in a bright yellow "taxi" color.

Taken June 17, 2022 on Kodak Ektachrome E100 film.

Answer (score 5):

At Easter the Dutch recumbent riders usually have a meet, so also in 2022.
These photos are related to that.

[image: Velomobile with Amsterdam Bijlmermeer in the background]
I took this photo, out of my bike, just outside Amsterdam, the Netherlands, on the way to the meet. 15 April 2022

[image: Group of velomobiles and other recumbents with some people talking]
This photo was during the day, before the actual activities of the meet, people discussing the bikes/trikes, standing between the parked ones. Mine is the yellow one with blue details behind the men. Photo taken 16 April 2022, near Otterloo, the Netherlands.

[image: Velomobile by night]
My Velomobile by night, taken with flash, so the yellow it just detectable, the blue is reflecting almost white. Photo also taken 16 April 2022, near Otterloo, the Netherlands, in fact within a meter or so from the one above.

Comment: Looks like a light cycle from the movie Tron.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Yellow tree, yellow taxi: autumn in New York. I took this photo by Tompkins Square Park in the East Village on November 23, 2013.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Just this little yellow dude I met along the *Coulée Verte* in Paris, on January 20, 2019.

Comment: I note that the background is also the complement of yellow - as a bonus, if you invert it you get this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvD2i.jpg

Answer (score 5):

[image]
[image]

Two views near Ushuaia, Argentina, the southernmost city in the world: the yellow plants and lichens on Isla H, and the yellow buildings in town. I took these photos on Feburary 19 and 20, 2019.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Escalators down to the Elizabeth Line]

I was delighted by the clean and bright escalators on my first visit to the Elizabeth Line, the newest of London's underground rail lines.

Taken by me 6th June 2022.

Comment: Striking, you get the virtual prize this month. (To go with the old radio show prize, free going up and down the escalators in your nearest station that has them, but not in the peak hour, then it will be too busy. Travel costs not included.)

Answer (score 5):

Yellow background on the traffic signs near the entrance bridge to Helsinki's Korkeasaari Zoo. Picture (cropped in post) taken last Sunday with my Sony RX10M3 at ƒ/5, 1/50, 18.21mm, and ISO200.

According to [Wikipedia on *"Major differences between Finnish and general European signs"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_signs_in_Finland#Major_differences_between_Finnish_and_general_European_signs):

> Whereas European signs usually have white background on warning and prohibition signs, Finnish signs have a yellow/orange colour. This is for the purpose of enhancing the visibility of the sign during the winter, as white signs would be hard to see in the snow.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Own picture of a layer of yellow flowers somewhere close to [Mellieħa](https://maps.app.goo.gl/zV4Z621ygCbveE547), Malta, March 2019.

[image: yellow flowers]

Answer (score 4):

Batman street art in Philadelphia, PA, USA on 18 April 2013.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Does food count too? [Tortellini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortellini) are one of favourite stuffed pasta in Bologna, Italy. I actually did these ones on Dec. 24th last year!

[image: tortellini]

Answer (score 2):

Chinese New Year decorations outside the Queen Victoria Building, Sydney, Feb 2016.

[image]