# Photo Competition Theme List to vote on

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

After reading these posts:

- [Upcoming 2022 photo competitions, themes not decided yet](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/upcoming-2022-photo-competitions-themes-not-decided-yet)

and

- [Possible topics for the photo competition](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition)

I was wondering, how to present the most appealing competition themes to our community.

I'd like to suggest to create a common Meta page (wiki style), where new themes can be posted and voted on. Each theme would be an answer you can vote on, community edits could help to enhance themes requirements.

Such an approach would surely be more visible than a chat post and would leave a nicely structured and comprehensive selection list to vote on. I also think it is a better approach for users which are not used to chat.

This Meta Page could be made HOT or Featured and placed on the right sidebar once a month during some days/a week. Highest vote wins. Once Voting is over, the winning theme is removed and all other themes remain, but are reset to 0, voting starts again.

Comment: Why reset to zero? That's what awards shows do, and look at all the actors that never won an Academy Award because they were consistently great for years but always got outvoted by someone who was extremely popular for one year.

Comment: @RayButterworth my reasoning is to give new themes a better chance to get chosen. As the world changes new ideas for themes can come up. For those new themes to "make it up the rankings" would maybe take too long and loose their actual attractiveness to our users.  But this is just an idea, anyway...

Comment: If I read right you want to force the person running the competition to use the highest voted theme, whether they like it, or even agree with it or not? At the moment we have enough trouble finding people to run it with the current rules. Are you offering to run the competition for the next year under the rules you set out here?

Comment: @Willeke, not at all, I don't want to force anyone! I just try to find a way, how to make it easier for who runs the competition to get more themes. This wouldn't mean that you have to stick to this theme list, but maybe it could be an inspiration?