# November 2022 Photo Competition: "Lights"

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the November photo competition is "Lights". This covers any photo that involves large displays of lights (e.g., electric Christmas lights, large displays of candles, etc.). I'm celebrating Diwali (a Hindu religious holiday all about lights) this week and decided to make a theme about it.

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be of the same subject.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin November 1, 2022, 0:00 UTC, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month. Posts submitted prior to the beginning date will not be considered.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/11329). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

---

### Results

After an extended voting period, Mark Mayo wins the bragging rights for the photo with the most votes, for their photo of the lights of Si O Se Pol Bridge.

Greg Hewgill wins the virtual prize for their photo of the lights of the BC Parliament buildings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parliament Buildings at night, Victoria, BC, Canada, December 2005.

From [BC Parliament Buildings](https://www.victoriabc.ca/bc-parliament-buildings/):

> The original idea for the lightbulbs was first brought to life in 1897 when the buildings were first completed. This was a time when electricity was still a novel phenomenon. While fewer than there are today, the lightbulbs were strung in honour of Queen Victoria’s diamond jubilee, as they were supposed to look like diamonds shining brightly in the darkness. The idea was brought back in the 1960s, and since then, the buildings have been lit every single evening at dusk.

[image: Parliament buildings at night]

Comment: Congratulations! Your photo wins the virtual prize for this month.

Answer (score 15):

People at/in the Si O Se Pol Bridge, Isfahan, Iran.

```
27 Jul 2015
Mon, 22:23GMT+04:30
HTC HTC_0P6B
ƒ/21/123.82 mmISO800
```

[image]

Comment: Congratulations! Your photo has the highest score after an extended voting period, so you win the bragging rights this month.

Answer (score 12):

Pilgrims lighting candles at [Kyaiktiyo Pagoda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyaiktiyo_Pagoda) in Myanmar/Burma. New Years Day, 2008.

I'm not normally a fan of negative space in photos, but in this case I think it works...

[image: Candles at Kyaiktiyo]

Comment: Wonderful photograph.

Answer (score 8):

Jemaa el-Fnaa, Marrakesh, Morocco.
The food market comes to life at the end of the day.

[image]

Taken by me in January 2011.

Answer (score 8):

Fountains outside the Mandarin Oriental, Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia

```
20 Oct 2018
Sat, 20:18GMT+08:00
Huawei Nexus 6P
ƒ/21/324.67 mmISO700
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The Vivid Festival, at Circular Quay, Sydney, Australia

```
28 May 2016
Sat, 19:39GMT+10:00
Huawei Nexus 6P
ƒ/21/184.67 mmISO1398
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Riverside paddleboat rental area in Chuncheon, South Korea.

[image: Chuncheon, South Korea]

It's well let to help stragglers find their way back. Photos taken in October of 2017. The second photo was taken from the water on a swan shaped paddle boat.

[image: View of shore from the swan shaped paddle boat.]

Answer (score 3):

Lights at Helsinki Vantaa Airport, Finland. Picture (cropped in post) taken in early October '22 with my Sony RX10M3 at ƒ/2.4, 1/30, 8.8mm, and ISO1000.

[image]