# February-March 2023 Photo Competition: Renovated

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

This month's competition will be run combined with next month's competition. The theme for this competition is "Renovated". This means any piece of travel infrastructure that was previously in an aging state but has since been renovated into new condition, or alternatively, rebuilt or re-made entirely. Examples include renovated train stations or rebuilt airport terminals. (Submissions that include before-and-after photos will have an increased chance of winning the virtual prize.)

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The following rules apply:

- At least one and up to four photos per answer.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a submission, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin immediately as of the publication of this post, and continue until the end of March (in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the March, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend into April.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/11329). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

---

### Results

Willeke wins the bragging rights for the highest-voted submission this competition, of the arena in Verona, Italy.

Relaxed wins the virtual prize, for their photos of the rebuilt Notre Dame monument in Paris.

---

Due to the lower engagement of the [first photo competition of this year](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8451/11329), the one who ran that competition decided not to post one for this month, and I couldn't post one due to other commitments at the time. After a [chat conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/conversation/combined-february-march-2023-photo-competition) with them, we decided it's best to post a combined competition for both this month and next month. I hope this will help to draw in more entries, given that the [previous competition](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8422/11329) had high engagement.

Comment: If a submission includes both a "before" and "after" photo, does the "before" photo have to be taken by the submitter too? Sometimes it's a lot more practical to find somebody else's historical photo.

Comment: @GregHewgill Photos not taken by those enumerated in the question can be linked, but not embedded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notre-Dame is one of the most famous monuments in Paris and currently being rebuilt following the fire almost four years ago. After some heated discussion, it was decided to rebuild it as close as possible to its most recent state, including the 19th century renovation (and the spire that wasn't there in the Middle Ages).

The theme of this competition gave me an occasion to go downtown to take a few pictures of the renovation with an interesting contrast of new and old.

[image: Notre-Dame enveloped in scaffolding behind a drawing of the church]

[image: Statue of Saint Stephen on the west facade of Notre-Dame de Paris with scaffolding and security equipment]

[image: Façade of Notre-Dame in Paris with a crane and “Notre-Dame en bande dessinée” exhibition]

[image: Virgin Mary fountain among construction site cabins]

All pictures taken by me on March 12.

Comment: I like that you made the effort! Congratulations; you win the virtual prize!

Comment: @gparyani Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Build a while ago, [Wikipedia mentions 30 AD,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verona_Arena) it has had some damage and has certainly been worked on to make it safe to use, this is the Arena of Verona, in Italy.

[image: Arena of Verona, outside]

[image: Arena of Verona, detail of outside]

[image: Arena of Verona, details of seating]

[image: Arena of Verona, overview of the inside]

And more work is done regularly, to make the inside ready for opera (and other events.)

Photos all by me.
I do not have pictures of before, as Roman and early Italian archives are not easy to search (or not at all, even.)

Comment: Congratulations! You win the bragging rights as the submission with the highest amount of votes.

Answer (score 5):

**Ancient bridge** in Wistow, Cambridgeshire, UK. Photos taken by me in May 2019.
Constructed in 16th century ~ renovated in 20th century.

[image]

The old bridge was "renovated" with a covering of concrete, using the old structure as a convenient foundation. When crossing it you are hardly aware that it is a bridge: just a tarmac roadway with railings each side. Certainly these is no clue to the older structure underneath. Here is the [Google Streetview](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@52.4140395,-0.1187185,3a,75y,226.62h,74.48t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sFxODcQ9pH90l_HQX5j28ZA!2e0!7i16384!8i8192).

But I noticed the word  in gothic script on an Ordnance Survey map, discovered that it is a [Scheduled Monument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduled_monument) and went for a closer look.

It was listed as such on 4th November 1982. I don't know whether this was because of the sheer desecration of the bridge, or whether the "renovation" was carried out later, despite its protected status.

The location of the top right photo is my favourite, although it loses something of my experience of the rippling stream, flora, insects and closeness to nature, a very different world from the roadway above, which doesn't know or care.

Answer (score 4):

The central train station (Hauptbahnhof) in Stuttgart, Germany is undergoing a major renovation.  It's a huge mess. In a visitor center, they promise that someday it will be nice with pictures and models of what is to come.  Photos taken in December of 2022.

Model of the future final product
[image: Model of future Stuttgart HBF]

Artist rendering of future conditions
[image: CGI of future Stuttgart HBF]

Current conditions
[image: Stuttgart HBF in December of 2022]
[image: More Stuttgart HBF in December 2022]

Answer (score 4):

Handley Page **Halifax**

The aircraft is the only remaining example of this WW2 heavy bomber. The renovation was really a reconstruction of the original, because it had been scrapped before it was realised it was the last one out of more than 6000 manufactured. It was rescued just in time, and rebuilt.

On close inspection it can be seen that it is a good mock-up but certain parts are incomplete. The engine exhausts do not connect anywhere, and the undercarriage retraction mechanisms are absent, with only simple struts to support the wheels.

[image]

[image]

Taken by me at Yorkshire Air Museum in September 2017.