# January 2023 Photo competition: New

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the January photo competition is "New".
Acceptable are all photos that show something new.
Think baby animals (human babies only if you have their legal guardian approval to post the photo.) New growth of vegetation after a dormant season. Freshly fallen snow. A flower opening. And please use your own imagination, as there have to be many other interpretations of the word 'new'.

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The following rules apply:

- Only one photo per answer.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo was taken, along with a description of the subject.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin Jauary 1, 2023, 0:00 UTC, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to [the list of possible photo competition topics.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition) Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Koru, Stewart Island, New Zealand, December 2007.

[*Koru*](https://maoridictionary.co.nz/word/3074) is a Māori word that refers to looped or coiled shoots of a plant. In this case it's a shoot from a fern.

[image: A green fern shoot extends vertically and is coiled onto itself at the upper end.]

Comment: The highest voted entry, by more than double the number for the second. You win the bragging rights this month.

Comment: @Willeke is there a February 2023 competition?

Comment: @WeatherVane I posted in the chat that I have not made one, due to lack of participation and being busy. But I will not stop you if you run it this month.

Answer (score 5):

[image: couple of lambs and a sheep with a lake behind]

Rather young lambs in front of a bit of water, with a sheep, likely their mother.

Photo taken 13 May 2017, near Calne, Wiltshire, UK.

Answer (score 5):

[image: monarch butterfly chrysalis]

A new butterfly about to burst forth.  Photo taken in March of 2022 on the island of Oahu.

Comment: You win the virtual prize this time, so new it is not really there yet.

Answer (score 4):

The **Millenium Bridge** and the **Tate Modern** gallery. The bridge crosses the River Thames and links the *City of London* with the *South Bank*.

New style – the innovative and award-winning method of suspension bridge construction.
New route – the first dedicated footway across the Thames in 100 years (since Tower Bridge).
New usage – the original Bankside power station reborn as a gallery (disused 1981 to 2000).
New ideas – the gallery houses modern and contemporary art, and frequent exhibitions.

[image]

Despite the vast expanse of brickwork, I felt a great sense of excitement and anticipation as I crossed the bridge to visit the Tate. Taken by me in February 2011.

Answer (score 3):

[image: The Gateshead Millennium Bridge with Newcastle behind it.]
Taken 30 August 2015, standing in Gateshead, the Millennium Bridge, which was still pretty new as bridges go. But it is here because of what is behind it, Newcastle, UK.

This is a [google maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/@54.9702957,-1.6003561,17z) to the location.

Comment: Oops a day early, I am going to delete and undelete tomorrow.

Comment: Now undeleted, as it is now January.