# May 2023 photo competition: Places of worship

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the May photo competition is "Places of worship" (proposed by [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow)). This covers any photo of all kinds of holy places, buildings people come to pray, open-air religious sites and associated for all religions.

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be of the same place of worship, which can be one building or a group of buildings, or something quite a bit smaller, like a statue or statuette.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- Be respectful to the religion and its worshippers and do not include recognisable people.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin on the publication of this post, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition).
Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

Comment: Thank you Willeke and all the mods and users who take the time to organize this monthly fun :) :) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Bahá'i World Centre in Haifa.

Taken by me on April 20, 2023.

[image]

Comment: Your post is the highest voted of the month, with +8 -1. You win the bragging rights.

Comment: Surely that down-vote was a wrong-button mistake. No other entry received a down-vote.

Comment: Maybe someone really doesn't like Baha'i.

Answer (score 8):

**St Mary's Church, Barton Bendish, Norfolk, UK.**
Taken by me in May 2014.

This church has [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Mary%27s_Church,_Barton_Bendish) and the Norman doorway shown in the second photo is supposedly one of the finest examples in England. The church boasts a harmonium as its musical accompaniment – but is nowhere near as old as some of its furniture. One of the wooden pews is dated 1637, a carved communion table is 1633, and it has a 14th century painting.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A church with a thatched roof is quite unusual. There are over 40,000 church buildings in UK (of various denominations) and only about 100 of these are thatched.

Comment: You win the virtual prize this month, seemingly on equal level with the most voted. And on top of that a lovely little church.

Answer (score 5):

[Wat Chedi Luang](https://maps.app.goo.gl/NeCJC1GNJj2aMjSJ8) is a complex of temples in the very center or middle of the city of Chiang Mai in the north of Thailand. One of the Thai worship places that impressed me most when I visited. I took this three pictures in November 2018 and selected them among many others of statues and finest ornaments.

[image: inside]

[image: outside]

[image: dragon]

Answer (score 5):

Here is the Wiesbaden Market Church (Marktkirche) in the center of Wiesbaden, Germany.  Originally built in the 1800s, it is described as a neo-Gothic brick church with a landmark main spire and a 49-bell carillon.  The first picture was taken from ground level.  The second was taken from the rooftop level while standing next to the main spire.  Both photos from March of 2023.

[image: Wiesbaden Marktkirche from ground level]

[image: Wiesbaden Marktkirch from the bell tower]

Answer (score 5):

Evangelical church in an indigenous community on the Amazon River (somewhere in Pará, Brazil)

November 2017

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The [Museum of the Moon](https://my-moon.org/about/) visits Lincoln Cathedral in the UK, in February 2022.

Photo taken by my mum, Sally Bleasdale.

[image: moon floating in Gothic vaulted interior with purple accent lighting]

Answer (score 4):

**Coventry Cathedral, UK.** taken by me in November 2022.

The previous gothic style cathedral was destroyed in a WW2 air raid and was not rebuilt but left in ruins as a testament to the futility of war. The new cathedral was built alongside, in a modern style.

The first picture shows part of the ruin on the left, with the new cathedral on the right.
The second picture is a closer view of the entrance, with a reflection of the ruin.
The third picture is taken inside the cathedral.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

These photos are of the [Cathedral in Norwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwich_Cathedral):
[image: Cathedral from the court]

[image: A few church windows]

[image: Babtismal font]

Photos taken 3 May 2022, Norwich, UK.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [church Jeanne d'Arc, (st Joan of Arc)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_St_Joan_of_Arc) in Rouan France, photos taken 31 October 2022.

[image: Outside of the church, roof]

[image: Outside of the church, windows and roof]

[image: Inside of the church, mostly windows]

Answer (score 3):

Close-up shots of the Nasir al-Mulk Mosque (aka Pink Mosque) in Shiraz, Iran

April 2016

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Mosque Keizerstraat and Neveh Shalom Synagogue located right next to each other in Paramaribo, Suriname

January 2019

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'll now change continent and century: [Parroquia de San José](https://maps.app.goo.gl/aN9wmsZbRMvde7MS9) in Estepona (province of Málaga, Spain) also houses amazing streetart by [Curro Leyton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0NJ6.jpg). I took these pictures on July 3rd last year.

I updated adding the third picture, instead of the link to the screenshot of it.

[image: front]

[image: view]

[image: streetart]

Answer (score 2):

This building in tin and wood impressed me much. It is the catholic church of [Ogheye-Dimigun](https://maps.app.goo.gl/FZdayXPYJJRZTm2o7) Community in Delta State (Nigeria), less than a mile from the Gulf of Guinea on river Benin.

Against the opinion of most tour operators, I visited and took this photo with my Samsung A50 in August last year.

[image: church in Nigeria]

Answer (score 2):

The Cardboard Cathedral, Christchurch, New Zealand

(14 July 2019)

[image: The Cardboard Cathedral]

Answer (score 2):

Zenkov's Cathedral, Almaty, Kazakhstan

(30 Jul, 2011)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Saint Martin sharing his cloak with a beggar]

Statue of Saint-Martin in Hungarian hussar dress sharing his cloak with a beggar, inside Saint-Martin Cathedral in Bratislava, Slovakia.

Two other views of the same church, on different days of January 2023:

[image: Saint-Martin Cathedral in Bratislava]

[image: Saint-Martin Cathedral in Bratislava]

Answer (score 1):

St. Sophia's Cathedral, Kiev, Ukraine

(27 October, 2008)

(photo taken by friend, Pascal)

[image]