# June 2023 photo competition: Road and water crossing

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the June photo competition is "Road and water crossing" (proposed by Willeke). This covers any photo of all kinds of ways for roads to cross a waterway, bridges, tunnels, ferries, fords, and whatever else you can find in your photo collection, take photos of and so on. This is a repeat of earlier competitions, please try to use new to the site photos if you have them.

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be of the same crossing/ferry/bridge/tunnel/whatever.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you have people recognizable in the photo you have to have their permission to post the photo, or make them unrecognizable.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin at the start of the month of June, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
- If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to [the list of possible photo competition topics.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition)
  Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

**Photos only, moving images will be disqualified and edited out of the post!**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: Abandoned pier]

Abandoned pier in Puerto Natales, Chile. Taken in December 2022.

Comment: This is the highest voted post at the end of the month. You get the bragging rights.

Comment: Hadn't seen this one until now. What a shot! Stunning.

Answer (score 7):

Puente Romano, Ronda, Spain

11 Sep 2018

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The highest arch bridge ever built in Europe, the Taminabrucke (bridge) spans the Tamina river which flows far below at the bottom of a deep gorge. The river flows from here directly through the city Bad Ragaz, Switzerland and dumps into the Rhine river.  Photos taken earlier this month.

[image: Tamina river gorge]

[image: Tamina bridge from above]

[image: Tamina bridge from just below]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Crossing Torneträsk]
Crossing [Torneträsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornetr%C3%A4sk) by bicycle, 11 February 2012, in northern Sweden.

There is a [road on the other side](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=12/68.2518/20.0113) that connects some villages but is not otherwise connected to any other roads. There are no ferries, so people drive cars or snowmobiles in winter or use their own boats in summer.  I wanted to see what it looked like, but the road was invisible below the deep snow (it looked like any snowmobile trail).  In the village of Latteluokta we were invited in by an old couple.  The woman was born there.  She told us she had seen cyclists there once before, many years earlier, coming from the north by mountainbike in summer (going north, there is a rarely used hiking trail that reaches a road after around 100 km). Years later she still referred to our visit on her blog, "not much has happened since the cyclists were here". I think our visit might have been the biggest event in the village in decades.

[image: Second crossing photo]
Nearly there.

The snow was thicker on the other side, so the last part we were pushing.  There was water below the snow, which I didn't expect at all.  My feet got all cold and wet. The woman who invited us in gave me dry socks and thick fur  boots for me to keep.

[image: A ride back]
They gave us a ride on the way back.

On the way back we were given a ride by snowmobile. It's the only time I ever hitch-hiked by snowmobile. The ride was very bumpy and I didn't manage to take any photos during the crossing.

Comment: You win the virtual prize, the most unexpected crossing, and by an unusual (for the location) vehicle.

Answer (score 5):

**Richmond Bridge** over the River Swale, North Yorkshire, UK.
Taken by me from the ruin of Richmond Castle in September 2008.
Constructed in 1788.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

14 Oct, 2018
Ponte Vecchio, Florence, Italy

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Photos taken 1 December 2012, London UK.
Of the [London cable car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_cable_car), (also known by sponsors names.)
[image: Cable car from near one terminal]
Before going up.

[image: Look from a car on the cable]
Up in the air

[image: The whole of the cable car setup from a distance, seen over the Thames]
Looking at the cars from a distance, seen over the river they cross, if in a different point.

Answer (score 3):

**Old and new**.
This 20th century bridge over the river Great Ouse frames another that is nearly *700 years old*. A third (foot) bridge crosses just this side of the ancient one. Taken by me in Huntingdon, Cambridgeshire, UK in February 2008.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The [Rainbow Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Bridge_(Niagara_Falls)), and, as it promises, a rainbow.

Taken at Niagara Falls, ON, Canada (though you can also see the US side in the photo), on an unseasonably beautiful fall day, October 19, 2016.

Answer (score 3):

The [Erasmusbrug, Rotterdam, Nederland, also known as 'De Zwaan', (Erasmus Bridge, Rotterdam, the Netherlands,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erasmusbrug) also known as The Swan.)
Photos taken 4 and 5 September 2011.

[image: Bridge by day]
By day full in view.

[image: Bridge by day, behind the lines of a sailing ship]
The bridge open, taken from the Tres Hombres, the lines echoing the shape of the bridge and its open deck,

[image: The Erasmus Bridge behind an other bridge by night.]
The lines of the bridge emphasized by being picked out by floodlight.

Answer (score 3):

One of my favourite bridge groups, the first, second and third Forth Bridges. The top pic is the third Forth Bridge, taken from the second Forth Bridge.

[image]

The other picture is taken from South Queensferry, with North Queensferry across the water, and then the three bridges. Of course the most famous is the Forth Rail Bridge - it doesn't qualify for this competition, but snuck in anyway :-)

[image]

Comment: A train going over a bridge is still bringing people across water, so even the train bridge fits.

Comment: Ooooo - good point @Willeke

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The [Alaska Marine Highway System](https://dot.alaska.gov/amhs/index.shtml) may be the most "road over water" name possible for a fleet of ferries. This is their MV Fairweather, at port in Haines, AK, USA, with mountains behind it, on July 14, 2018.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Some bridges have signs telling you not to jump off them because your friends and family love you. This bridge? If you survive, they'll come to your hospital room and arrest you.

Taken along the [North County Trailway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_County_Trailway) in Yorktown Heights, NY, US, on August 6, 2011.

Comment: "If caught" — do they have some big net to catch jumpers? ;)

Answer (score 1):

An unnamed minor road crosses the [Gloucester and Sharpness Canal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloucester_and_Sharpness_Canal) at Saul Junction.  Sunset in January last year, on a chilly but not quite frosty ride into Worcestershire from Bristol.  This is a swing bridge to allow ships using the canal to pass.

Mine is the rather large bike on the left.

[image: Bikes on a bridge over a canal]

Answer (score 1):

Ponte Sant' Angelo, Rome, Italy: Ancient bridge built by Emperor Hadrian (Αδριανός); panorama taken from the Castel Sant' Angelo's roof:
[image]

Ponte Vittorio Emanuelle II, historic bridge with 3 arches in Rome, Italy, which too crosses the Tiber River:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

These photos are taken on a crossing from Calais to Dover, of the ferry I was on and others I did see from it.
Photos taken 1 May 2011.

[image: Ferry being loaded in Calais.]

[image: One of the open decks of the ferry.]

[image: Two other ferries seen from the one I was on.]

Answer (score 0):

19 Nov 2014

Celebrity Cruises ship, Sydney Harbour, Sydney, Australia

Moving image removed, may be replaced by a still image of the same ferry.

Comment: Please photos only, no moving images

Answer (score 0):

[image: Crossing the road to get to the Stabroek market in Georgetown, Guyana]

Crossing the road to get to the Stabroek market in Georgetown, Guyana. Taken in Georgetown in January 2019.

Comment: This is a very free interpretation of the theme, no water involved.

Comment: Ah. I misread the assignment.