# No message or voting notifications

Tags: bug, notifications

On most stacks that I am a member of, message and voting notifications arrive at my browser automatically (when I am logged in) so I can go and have look.

However I get no notifications from Travel Meta photography competitions such as [June 2023 photo competition: Road and water crossing](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/june-2023-photo-competition-road-and-water-crossing?cb=1).

Why is that? Is there a setting I must make?

Answer (score 3):

You do not get notifications for rep earned on a site meta, so it is right you got no message.

If things go as they should you will get a message for this answer.

Comment: Yes, I got a notification that there is an answer to my question, thank you.

Comment: But *why* don't we get notifications for voting?

Comment: I think that is because voting on the site metas is to express agreement or disagreement with the post, completely different from voting on the main sites.

Comment: Interesting. I got a notification of that comment too. But does it mean I don't gain any rep from upvotes on the photo competitions?