# November 2023 Photo Contest: On the trail

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I'll (cocomac) be running the photo contest this month (November).

**The topic is "On the trail"**, meaning photos taken on a trail or in a forest of some type. Plants, animals, perhaps a campsite, stunning views and similar are all fair game.

Remember that if your photo includes people (other than you), you need to get permission *prior* to posting the photo. Alternatively, you can make them unrecognizable.

The contest will end at the end of November (UTC time). The following rules apply (credit to Willeke, but slightly modified):

- Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be of the same trail or forest area, may be a different part of it.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, [CoC-compliant](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct), non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you have people recognizable in the photo you have to have their permission to post the photo, or make them unrecognizable.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
- If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to [the list of possible photo competition topics.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition)
  Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Curonian Spit, Lithuania, September 3rd, 2023

Comment: You win for having the most votes - congratulations!

Answer (score 7):

[image]

[image]

[image]

The Dechmont Woods, about 5 miles north of where I live, in March 2021 - a time when we explored every walkable trail in our county, I think...

Comment: I especially like the middle picture. In fact, I think this'd be a stronger entry with just the middle picture.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Langedrag, Norway, January 28th, 2023

Answer (score 5):

[image]

‘On the end of the trail’ is perhaps a bit too far fetched, but I'll give it a go nevertheless.

Stange Kirke, Norway, February 5th, 2021

Answer (score 5):

Stuttgart Germany. August 2023.

[image: German Deer]

Answer (score 4):

McLaren Falls bush-walk, Bay of Plenty, New Zealand.  Photos taken by me on my iphone, March 2023

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Congratulations on winning the virtual prize this month!

Comment: @cocomac Wow thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Leaf covered trail near Wiesbaden, Germany in the Taunus mountains.  Photo taken 2023-11-08.

[image: Taunus in autumn]

Answer (score 4):

Last night I slept in the area called [Tràng An](https://maps.app.goo.gl/G5BnRpVpUdLQHPQU9), UNESCO site in the province of [Ninh Bình](https://maps.app.goo.gl/pKiFQcCwUCpP5VPq8) in northern Vietnam. When I left the homestay on *my* scooter some two hours ago I thought to do [the longer route](https://maps.app.goo.gl/ZTUzTL8FyKMLbSbf9) to enjoy the landscape. This was my reward!

[image]

[image]

[image]