# December 2023 Photo Contest: Festive

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I'll (cocomac) be running the photo contest this month (December).

**The topic is "Festive"**, meaning photos that are celebratory - anything from a glass of champagne to an outdoor display are fair game.

Remember that if your photo includes people (other than you), you need permission (from them) *prior* to posting the photo. Alternatively, you can make them unrecognizable.

The contest will end at the end of December (UTC time). The following rules apply (credit to Willeke, but slightly modified):

- Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, [CoC-compliant](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct), non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you have people recognizable in the photo you have to have their permission to post the photo, or make them unrecognizable.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider commenting on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
- If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to [the list of possible photo competition topics.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition)
  Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us decide which topic to choose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Schlossplatz Stuttgart]

The Stuttgart, Germany Christmas markets. Photo taken on the market's official opening night, Nov 28th, 2023.

Comment: Nice photograph.

Comment: This post had the most votes at the end of the month.

Answer (score 4):

Sitting on the steps of the Lincoln Memorial (Washington DC), 4th of July, 2018.  Photos taken by me on iphone SE

(First and only July 4th we've ever been in the US for, so it was a pretty cool experience for us)

[image]

[image]

There were a LOT of people there!

Answer (score 3):

Xmas 2022, the light of the Ellinikon Experience Park in Greece meets the moon in a cloudy-sky setting!
The airplane hangar in the background is from the old Hellenic International Airport of Olympic Airways.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Republic Street](https://goo.gl/maps/txb89U9dFRK8q1dL6), Valletta (Malta) on August 15th, 2020. My own pictures taken with smartphone.

[image: Malta1]

[image: Malta2]

Comment: I tried to keep it travel related, I just turned 40 and my phone is full of birthday pictures ;)

Answer (score 2):

5/1/2022, Xmas decoration in Ano Glyfada, Greece:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Brussels sprouts.**
Prepared fresh – peeled, cut and cooked – eaten by me at home in December 2021.

[image]

It wasn't my *only* Christmas dinner but the only one I made myself :)

Comment: Congratulations - you win the virtual prize this month!

Comment: @cocomac thanks – I guess that will be a cabbage!

Answer (score 1):

A very festive occasion occurred last year at my home, when my and my friends became champions, after beating the Elite 4!

My friend Tom had lent me Nintendo Switch and a Pokemon game, where I caught for the 1st time in my life a shiny Pokemon (green Zubat, now pink Crobat); excluding the iconic Red Gyarados that appeared by default in the early Pokemon games. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Christmas tree given to a friend of mine.

[image: stappenboor/step drill in Christmas tree stand]
Photo taken 9 December 2023, in Heemskerk, the Netherlands.