# January 2024 Photo Contest: Horizon Lines

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I'll (cocomac) be running the photo contest this month (January).

**The topic is "Horizon Lines"**, meaning photos that contain a horizon line of some sort - sunsets and landscapes are two examples. Feel free to ping me [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) with thoughts on the photo contest themes or if you have ideas!

Remember that if your photo includes people (other than you), you need permission (from them) *prior* to posting the photo. Alternatively, you can make them unrecognizable.

The contest will end at the end of January (UTC time). The following rules apply (credit to Willeke, but slightly modified):

- Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, [CoC-compliant](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct), non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you have people recognizable in the photo you have to have their permission to post the photo, or make them unrecognizable.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider commenting on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
- If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to [the list of possible photo competition topics.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition)
  Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us decide which topic to choose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mountains next to Lake Titicaca, Bolivia

March 2019

[image]

Comment: This answer has the most votes, had so since the first day of the new month.

Comment: Congratulations on having the most upvotes at the end of the month and winning the January 2024 photo contest!

Answer (score 9):

Chicago, December 2016.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Salar de Uyuni, Feburary 2019.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Sunset over the Moai, Easter Island

June 2018[image]

Answer (score 6):

Departing from runway 19 at Keflavik international airport last month. In Iceland during the winter months, the horizon frequently appears as a subtle change of grey with an occasional fiery volcano.

[image: KEF Departure from Runway 191]

Comment: Taken from the cockpit?

Comment: Yes, indeed. That is where the best views are generally to be found ;)

Answer (score 6):

Sunrise over La Gomera, from Los Gigantes in Tenerife, October 2018.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I am lucky to live on the top floor of a Hong Kong high-rise building. I have fantastic views... This is Shenzhen, specifically Shenzhen Bay. No filters: I am an absolute idiot when it comes to photography. Nature provided. :-)

[image: Shenzhen Bay at sunset]

*Shenzhen Bay at sunset*

[image: Shenzhen Bay day-time]

*Shenzhen Bay day-time*

[image: Another beautiful sunset]

*Another beautiful sunset*

Answer (score 4):

[image: view over the dunes.]
Taken on the top of the then very new tower on top of 'de Kruisberg' the highest point in that part of the Heemskerk Dunes, the view reminded me of a line in a Dutch song:

- Het zegt u waarschijnlijk niets maar het is waar ik geboren ben.
  (It will not mean anything to you but I was born there.)

[image: part of the tower with a bird cut out of the steel plate, with a view above.]

Taken the same day, same tower but a different part of the view.

Both photos taken 28 May 2023, Heemskerk, the Netherlands.

Comment: The 'berg' (mountain) is about 35 meter high, the tower adds an other 10 meter or so.

Answer (score 4):

Leaving Itajaí (city in southern Brazil) seaport. December 2023

[image]

Comment: Congratulations - you win the virtual prize this month!

Answer (score 3):

Over the Atlantic Ocean, heading towards Keflavík airport, August 2011.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Night at the sea, somewhere in southern Atlantic Ocean. Moon shines so bright it doesn't even look like complete darkness.
December 2023
[image: Night at the sea]

Answer (score 3):

Same location, but different heading. Here we have Tuen Mun in the back, and all the way down the island of Lantau and the airport.

[image: Day-time, blue sky and pretty clouds]

*Day-time, blue sky and pretty clouds*

[image: A glorious sunset]

[image: Just before sunset – here the sun seeming sets in 5 mn...]

*Just before sunset – here the sun seeming sets in 5 mn...*

Answer (score 3):

Sunset at São Paulo, Brazil. December 2016.

The reddish/purplish color is caused by high levels of air pollution.

[image: Colorful sunset]

Answer (score 3):

Green Flash, near Tofino, Vancouver Island

16 Sep 2012

NIKON CORPORATION NIKON D80
ƒ/5.61/250125 mmISO800

[image: A photo I took of a green flash]

Answer (score 3):

Blue Mountains from Katoomba, Australia

```
27 Jan 2019
Sun, 10:19GMT+11:00
IMG_20190127_101927.jpg
22.4 MP9728 × 2304
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Honolulu, HI, United States

```
16 Jun 2015
Tue, 19:08GMT-10:00
HTC HTC_0P6B
ƒ/21/4093.82 mmISO100
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Skyline of Victoria, Gozo, from [this point of the Citadel](https://maps.app.goo.gl/XSpgw9iZxDradgvJ9). The church in the distance is the so called *Rotunda* (Church of Saint John the Baptist) of Xewkija, third highest unsupported dome in the world!

[image: Victoria/Rabat, Gozo]

Comment: I took this picture in September 2023 :)

Answer (score 2):

The skyline of Venezia from the terrace at [Fondaco dei Tedeschi](https://maps.app.goo.gl/7Gvn79HvghABFmR2A). I took this picture last week with my Samsung A50 phone.

[image: Venezia]

Answer (score 2):

Kaohsiung, Taiwan, from somewhere on the North end of [Qijin](https://maps.app.goo.gl/cpJu5xrwooyV4Xrh7). I took this picture last November with my Samsung A50 phone.

The tallest building on the right, [85 Sky Tower](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/85_Sky_Tower) is nowadays partially abandoned as an aftermath of the covid years.

[image: kaohsiung, taiwan]

Answer (score 2):

Sunset at [Dunas do Jalapão](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Dunes+Jalap%C3%A3o/@-10.5639472,-46.6651638,17z/data=!4m12!1m5!3m4!2zMTDCsDMzJzUwLjIiUyA0NsKwMzknNDUuMyJX!8m2!3d-10.5639472!4d-46.6625889!3m5!1s0x93310f527a6b9abf:0x1ab8001c2a590954!8m2!3d-10.5644174!4d-46.6615701!16s%2Fg%2F1ydkbd82m?authuser=2&entry=ttu), State of Tocantins, Brazil.

July 2018.

[image: Sunset at Dunas do Jalapão]

Answer (score 2):

[image: windmills]
Photo taken today, 27 January 2024, Zaanse Schans, Zaanstad, the Netherlands.
It was nice weather for a cycle ride and it was fun to be the topic of many photos, (always a lot of tourists there and I ride a different kind of cycle,) but it was also nice to take some photos.

Answer (score 1):

[World Showcase Lagoon](https://www.google.com/maps/place/28%C2%B022%2717.2%22N+81%C2%B032%2757.9%22W/@28.3714444,-81.5519943,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d28.3714444!4d-81.5494194?authuser=2&entry=ttu) at Epcot, Walt Disney World, Florida. December 2017.

[image: World Showcase Lagoon, Epcot]

Answer (score 1):

More interest below the horizon than above.
Taken by me in Tenerife 2012.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

East London and beyond, taken from Whitechapel E1. On the left is the Royal London Hospital; mid-right in the distance can be seen the cluster of offices at Canary Wharf. December 2023.

[image: Cityscape of East London at sunrise]