# February 2024 Photo Contest: Night photos

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I'll (cocomac) be running the photo contest this month (February). Sorry for the delay on this - I was busy with other things IRL and didn't post it.

Anyway, **the topic is "Night Photography"**, meaning photos that were taken at night (defining "night" is up to you, but roughly after the sun is down to before it comes up). Some examples might be astrophotography or a city at night. Feel free to ping me [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) with thoughts on the photo contest themes or if you have ideas!

Remember that if your photo includes people (other than you), you need permission (from them) *prior* to posting the photo. Alternatively, you can make them unrecognizable.

The contest will end at the end of February (UTC time). The following rules apply (credit to Willeke, but slightly modified):

- Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, [CoC-compliant](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct), non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you have people recognizable in the photo you have to have their permission to post the photo, or make them unrecognizable.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider commenting on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
- If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to [the list of possible photo competition topics.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition)
  Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us decide which topic to choose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Dreyfus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Dreyfus) tower, Kourou, French Guiana, not far from the [Île du Diable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_Island_(Kourou)) where he was imprisoned. I took this picture on February 24, 2019.

[image]

Comment: This photo had the most votes at the end of the month.

Comment: Congratulations on winning the photo contest for this month!

Answer (score 6):

Supper time at Jemaa El-Fna in Marrakech, Morocco.
Taken by me in January 2011.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Collage of the eclipse of the moon sequence on 3 March 2007 in UK.
Taken by me with my first digital camera, a 5mp Sony W15 compact.
I hope this can be accepted as one photo, not six.

[image]

Comment: I feel this is acceptable.

Comment: This would have been my virtual prize candidate.

Answer (score 4):

Two photos taken using my OnePlus 11 Pro balanced on the edge of a hot tub in Strathdon, in the Scottish Highlands. The Aurora pic was winter 2023-24, and the Orion pic was winter 2021-22.

With almost zero light pollution - no towns nearby, and only mountains in most directions, the limiting factors for astrophotography are:

- steam from the hot tub
- moonlight
- small camera (it has Hasselblad lenses, but it's a phone camera, so it is tiny)

[image: The aurora borealis]

[image: Orion]

Comment: Congratulations on winning the virtual prize for the photo contest this month!

Comment: Thank you cocomac

Answer (score 3):

Behold, the Eiffel Tower in Paris France after dark! As seen in January 2023.

[image: Well illuminated Eiffel Tower]

Answer (score 3):

It's [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuching#Etymology) a coincidence that the name of the city of Kuching, Malaysia, is the same as the Malay word for cat, but that hasn't stopped the city from embracing the coincidence and putting statues of cats all over the place, such as this one, which I photographed on August 19, 2023.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hong Kong. May 14, 2016.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is the [Triton Fountain in Valletta, Malta](https://maps.app.goo.gl/s94NipE8PAVUoJGr8), shortly before the midnight of April 14, 2022. I shot this photo with my Samsung A50 phone.

[image: triton fountain valletta malta]

Answer (score 3):

Shenzhen Bay, one of Shenzhen's glitzy areas, seen from Hong Kong's northwest, the poorest neighborhood.

[image: Shenzhen Bay seen from Hong Kong]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a photo of the milky way I took in 2023 from Washington, USA.

[image: Photo of milky way]

Answer (score 3):

The University of Texas Tower lit up in orange to commemorate the end of 2018:

[image]

Normally, the tower is lit up in white, but on special occasions, it is lit up in orange (the school's color). In this particular case, additionally, specific offices in the building have their lights turned on and their window shades open (the dots are simply windows into offices).

Taken December 2018 in Austin, Texas, USA on Fujifilm Fujicolor Superia 400 film.

Answer (score 2):

Cinderella Castle at Magic Kingdom (Walt Disney World Resort).

December 2017, Orlando, FL, USA.

[image: Cinderella Castle]

Answer (score 2):

Ye Olde Trip to Jerusalem, Nottingham, England.
September 2010.

This is [one of the many pubs](https://heritagecalling.com/2022/12/22/what-is-the-oldest-pub-or-inn-in-england/) that claim to be "the oldest inn in England". Regardless of that being true, the beer was great!

[image: Ye Olde Trip to Jerusalem]

Answer (score 2):

[image: street in front of a school]
In the area I live they use a lot of coloured reflective bollards to indicate schools, this is one such a street.
Photo taken 4 December 2023, Laan van Blois Beverwijk, the Netherlands.