# March 2024 Photo Contest: Breakfast around the world

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I'll (cocomac) be running the photo contest this month (March).

**The topic is "breakfast around the world"**, meaning photos containing breakfast from a variety of places in the world. Feel free to ping me [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) with thoughts on the photo contest themes or if you have ideas!

Remember that if your photo includes people (other than you), you need permission (from them) *prior* to posting the photo. Alternatively, you can make them unrecognizable.

The contest will end at the end of March (UTC time). The following rules apply (credit to Willeke, but slightly modified):

- Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, [CoC-compliant](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct), non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you have people recognizable in the photo you have to have their permission to post the photo, or make them unrecognizable.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider commenting on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
- If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to [the list of possible photo competition topics.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition)
  Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us decide which topic to choose.

Comment: This is a cool and yummy topic!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following pics refer to two amazing breakfasts that I had in [Warri, Delta State (Nigeria)](https://maps.app.goo.gl/WXUW7tLh4QSbKxSE8) in August 2022.

Pic 1: spicy fish soup, boiled yam and plantain, palm oil.
[image: spicy fish soup, boiled yam and plantain, palm oil]

Pic 2: goat meat soup, boiled yam and plantain, palm oil.
[image: goat meat soup, boiled yam and plantain, palm oil]

I can't keep from thanking Christy for cooking these and more fabulous dishes.

Pic 3: it only got hardcore when I was offered a shot of *roots drink* or *roots wine*, featuring several roots, herbs and fruits infused in a base of gin.
[image]

Now seriously, I am a coffee-and-pastry like guy but I'm so grateful I could experience all of this!

Answer (score 6):

A cute fruit-lady made with banana, kiwi, grapes, starfruit and strawberries.

Yeah, we had this many fruits in that breakfast.

São Paulo, Brazil, May 2013.

[image: Fruit lady]

Answer (score 5):

The (vegan) brunch buffet at [Soya Cantine Bio](https://www.soya-cantine-bio.fr/en/) in Paris. Sunday, January 20, 2019.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**English breakfast**

Not *full* English breakfast because it lacks tomato, mushroom, fried bread and black pudding. Not really *traditional* because hash browns are an imported idea. This is what the fast food chain *thinks* a traditional Full English Breakfast is.

Eaten by me today, it could be ordered anywhere in UK and be identical.

[image]

Comment: The restaurant owner guaranteed me it was full and traditional, it seems I was fooled. I edited [my answer](/a/8667/142000) and apologize for my mistake

Answer (score 4):

*"Ciao, un orzo piccolo e una brioche salata per favore!"*

This is my take on one of many variations of the average Italian breakfast at the bar: I go for barley coffee instead of the most classic *espresso*, and the croissant (that we call *pasta* or *cornetto* or *brioche*) is savoury.

Savoury croissant is apparently very typical of my city, Bologna: now I'm working in Modena (30km from here) and, there, they have no idea that it exists. Still, when I talk to people from other Italian cities and I say I prefer the savoury corissant, they are like *"the savoury what?"* and this is funny to me ;)

Picture taken by me just now, obviously at [Bar Tito](https://maps.app.goo.gl/hbgGNocVkQFf2YbC8).

[image: orzo e brioche]

Answer (score 3):

English Breakfast.

Some english friends told me it's a good meal [if you had drunk too much the night before](https://www.thesun.co.uk/living/2223831/now-you-have-an-excuse-because-a-full-english-breakfast-really-is-the-best-hangover-cure/). I can confirm this is true.

Newcastle upon Tyne, England, March 2010.

[image: Traditional Full English Breakfast]

Comment: That's a load!! And yes, it will help fixing your day after :)))

Comment: If you can face it. I have seen quite a few hang-over people decline breakfast the next day, still sick I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Traditional German breakfast, aka "Frühstück".  From the heart of Bavaria last month.

[image: yummy morning bretzels]

Comment: But where is the Weißwurst?

Answer (score 2):

[image: slice of bread, cup of drink and some jars]
I have taken a picture of my work day breakfast.
As many Dutch my breakfast is a slice of bread with something out of a jar and a drink, so this will look pretty standard.
My spread is Sandwich spread and my drink a savoury, stock made out of powder, so a little less average. Most Dutch will use jam or peanut butter, or sliced cold meat or cheese and drink coffee or tea.

Photo taken 5 March 2024, Heemskerk, the Netherlands.